# Is there any pre-built way to parse JSON from VB6?

Tags: json, vb6, parsing

Is there any existing JSON parser which can be used from VB6?

I could obviously write my own parser, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if I don't have to.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is There a JSON Parser for VB6 / VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782076/is-there-a-json-parser-for-vb6-vba)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would look at [VB-JSON](http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html):

> VB-JSON is a Visual Basic 6 class library for parsing and emitting JSON (Javascript Object Notation) and can handle nested arrays and objects in the data. It does not rely on the JScript engine for parsing.