# Is There a JSON Parser for VB6 / VBA?

Tags: web-services, json, vba, serialization, vb6

I am trying to consume a web service in VB6.  The service - which I control - currently can return a SOAP/XML message or JSON.  I am having a really difficult time figuring out if VB6's SOAP type (version 1) can handle a returned `object` - as opposed to simple types like `string`, `int`, etc.  So far I cannot figure out what I need to do to get VB6 to play with returned objects.

So I thought I might serialize the response in the web service as a JSON string. Does a JSON parser exist for VB6?

Comment: I have an answer below but I have now found a better method http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/01/vba-parse-json-safer-with-jsonparse-and.html

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Check out [JSON.org](http://JSON.org) for an up-to-date list (see bottom of main page) of JSON parsers in many different languages.  As of the time of this writing, you'll see a link to several different JSON parsers there, but only one is for VB6/VBA (the others are .NET):

- [VB-JSON](http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html)

  - When I tried to download the zip file, Windows said the data was corrupt.  However, I was able to use [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org) to pull the files out.  It turns out that the main "folder" in the zip file isn't recognized as a folder by Windows, by 7-zip can see the contents of that main "folder," so you can open that up and then extract the files accordingly.
  - The actual syntax for this VB JSON library is really simple:

    ```
    Dim p As Object
    Set p = JSON.parse(strFormattedJSON)

    'Print the text of a nested property '
    Debug.Print p.Item("AddressClassification").Item("Description")

    'Print the text of a property within an array '
    Debug.Print p.Item("Candidates")(4).Item("ZipCode")
    ```
  - Note: I had to add the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" and "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8" library as references via Tools > References in the VBA editor.
  - Note: VBJSON code is actually based on a google code project [vba-json](http://code.google.com/p/vba-json/).  However, VBJSON promises several bug fixes from the original version.

Comment: is there a way with VB-JSON to pass it a Class object and return the corresponding JSON string?  Thanks!

Comment: How do you loop trough objects? Say p.Item("AddressClassification") contains 3 items. How can I loop over the items?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay You should be able to loop through the item just like you would loop through any array in VB6/VBA

Comment: @BenMcCormack Can you take a look at this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229563/vba-getting-values-from-a-collection ?

Answer (score 15):

Building on ozmike solution, which did not work for me (Excel 2013 and IE10).
The reason is that I could not call the methods on the exposed JSON object.
So its methods are now exposed through functions attached to a DOMElement.
Didn't know this is possible (must be that IDispatch-thing), thank you ozmike.

As ozmike stated, no 3rd-party libs, just 30 lines of code.

```
Option Explicit

Public JSON As Object
Private ie As Object

Public Sub initJson()
    Dim html As String

    html = "<!DOCTYPE html><head><script>" & _
    "Object.prototype.getItem=function( key ) { return this[key] }; " & _
    "Object.prototype.setItem=function( key, value ) { this[key]=value }; " & _
    "Object.prototype.getKeys=function( dummy ) { keys=[]; for (var key in this) if (typeof(this[key]) !== 'function') keys.push(key); return keys; }; " & _
    "window.onload = function() { " & _
    "document.body.parse = function(json) { return JSON.parse(json); }; " & _
    "document.body.stringify = function(obj, space) { return JSON.stringify(obj, null, space); }" & _
    "}" & _
    "</script></head><html><body id='JSONElem'></body></html>"

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .navigate "about:blank"
        Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Do While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        .Visible = False
        .document.Write html
        .document.Close
    End With

    ' This is the body element, we call it JSON:)
    Set JSON = ie.document.getElementById("JSONElem")

End Sub

Public Function closeJSON()
    ie.Quit
End Function
```

The following test constructs a JavaScript Object from scratch, then stringifies it.
Then it parses the object back and iterates over its keys.

```
Sub testJson()
    Call initJson

    Dim jsObj As Object
    Dim jsArray As Object

    Debug.Print "Construction JS object ..."
    Set jsObj = JSON.Parse("{}")
    Call jsObj.setItem("a", 1)
    Set jsArray = JSON.Parse("[]")
    Call jsArray.setItem(0, 13)
    Call jsArray.setItem(1, Math.Sqr(2))
    Call jsArray.setItem(2, 15)
    Call jsObj.setItem("b", jsArray)

    Debug.Print "Object: " & JSON.stringify(jsObj, 4)

    Debug.Print "Parsing JS object ..."
    Set jsObj = JSON.Parse("{""a"":1,""b"":[13,1.4142135623730951,15]}")

    Debug.Print "a: " & jsObj.getItem("a")
    Set jsArray = jsObj.getItem("b")
    Debug.Print "Length of b: " & jsArray.getItem("length")
    Debug.Print "Second element of b: "; jsArray.getItem(1)

    Debug.Print "Iterate over all keys ..."
    Dim keys As Object
    Set keys = jsObj.getKeys("all")

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To keys.getItem("length") - 1
        Debug.Print keys.getItem(i) & ": " & jsObj.getItem(keys.getItem(i))
    Next i

    Call closeJSON
End Sub
```

outputs

```
Construction JS object ...
Object: {
    "a": 1,
    "b": [
        13,
        1.4142135623730951,
        15
    ]
}
Parsing JS object ...
a: 1
Length of b: 3
Second element of b:  1,4142135623731 
Iterate over all keys ...
a: 1
b: 13,1.4142135623730951,15
```

Answer (score 7):

Hopefully this will be a big help to others who keep on coming to this page after searching for "vba json".

I found this [page](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/json/excel-json-conversion) to be very helpful. It provides several Excel-compatible VBA classes that deal with processing data in JSON format.

Comment: Which one would you recommend?

Answer (score 7):

As Json is nothing but strings so it can easily be handled if we can manipulate it the right way, no matter how complex the structure is. I don't think it is necessary to use any external library or converter to do the trick. Here is an example where I've parsed json data using string manipulation.

```
Sub GetJsonContent()
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, itm As Variant

    With http
        .Open "GET", "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", False
        .send
        itm = Split(.responseText, "id"":")
    End With

    x = UBound(itm)

    For y = 1 To x
        Cells(y, 1) = Split(Split(itm(y), "name"": """)(1), """")(0)
        Cells(y, 2) = Split(Split(itm(y), "username"": """)(1), """")(0)
        Cells(y, 3) = Split(Split(itm(y), "email"": """)(1), """")(0)
        Cells(y, 4) = Split(Split(itm(y), "street"": """)(1), """")(0)
    Next y
End Sub
```

Comment: That will work for simple JSON objects. It is not generic enough for objects with nested collections and nested objects.

Answer (score 6):

**[VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)** by Tim Hall, **MIT licensed** and on **GitHub**. It's another fork of [vba-json](https://code.google.com/p/vba-json/) that emerged end of 2014. Claims to work on Mac Office and Windows 32bit and 64bit.

Comment: Included in [VBA-Web](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web)  perfect for web request. Works on Mac too.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE: Found a safer way of parsing JSON than using Eval, this blog post shows the dangers of Eval ...  http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/01/vba-parse-json-safer-with-jsonparse-and.html**

Late to this party but sorry guys but by far the easiest way is to use Microsoft Script Control.  Some sample code which uses VBA.CallByName to drill in

```
'Tools->References->
'Microsoft Script Control 1.0;  {0E59F1D2-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}; C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msscript.ocx

Private Sub TestJSONParsingWithCallByName()

    Dim oScriptEngine As ScriptControl
    Set oScriptEngine = New ScriptControl
    oScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"

    Dim sJsonString As String
    sJsonString = "{'key1': 'value1'  ,'key2': { 'key3': 'value3' } }"


    Dim objJSON As Object
    Set objJSON = oScriptEngine.Eval("(" + sJsonString + ")")
    Debug.Assert VBA.CallByName(objJSON, "key1", VbGet) = "value1"
    Debug.Assert VBA.CallByName(VBA.CallByName(objJSON, "key2", VbGet), "key3", VbGet) = "value3"

End Sub
```

I have actually done a series of Q&As which explore JSON/VBA related topics.

Q1 [In Excel VBA on Windows, how to mitigate issue of dot syntax traversal of parsed JSON broken by IDE's capitalisation behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710995/in-excel-vba-on-windows-how-to-mitigate-issue-of-dot-syntax-traversal-of-parsed)

Q2 [In Excel VBA on Windows, how to loop through a JSON array parsed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711034/in-excel-vba-on-windows-how-to-loop-through-a-json-array-parsed)

Q3 [In Excel VBA on Windows, how to get stringified JSON respresentation instead of “[object Object]” for parsed JSON variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711073/in-excel-vba-on-windows-how-to-get-stringified-json-respresentation-instead-of)

Q4 [In Windows Excel VBA,how to get JSON keys to pre-empt “Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711100/in-windows-excel-vba-how-to-get-json-keys-to-pre-empt-run-time-error-438-obj)

Q5 [In Excel VBA on Windows, for parsed JSON variables what is this JScriptTypeInfo anyway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711112/in-excel-vba-on-windows-for-parsed-json-variables-what-is-this-jscripttypeinfo)

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: JSON keys are case sensitive (keys in VBA object returned by oScriptEngine.Eval are not)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on 64 Bit since Microsoft did not port this to 64 Bit!

Answer (score 4):

[VB6 - JsonBag, Another JSON Parser/Generator](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?738845-VB6-JsonBag-Another-JSON-Parser-Generator) should also be importable into VBA with little trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a "Native" VB JSON library.

It is possible to use JSON that is already in IE8+. This way your not  dependent on a third party library that gets out of date and is untested.

see amedeus' alternative version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21664962/334106)

```
Sub myJSONtest()


Dim oJson As Object
Set oJson = oIE_JSON() ' See below gets IE.JSON object

' using json objects
Debug.Print oJson.parse("{ ""hello"": ""world"" }").hello ' world
Debug.Print oJson.stringify(oJson.parse("{ ""hello"": ""world"" }")) ' {"hello":"world"}

' getting items
Debug.Print oJson.parse("{ ""key1"": ""value1"" }").key1 ' value1
Debug.Print oJson.parse("{ ""key1"": ""value1"" }").itemGet("key1") ' value1
Debug.Print oJson.parse("[ 1234, 4567]").itemGet(1) '  4567

' change  properties
Dim o As Object
Set o = oJson.parse("{ ""key1"": ""value1"" }")
o.propSetStr "key1", "value\""2"
Debug.Print o.itemGet("key1") ' value\"2
Debug.Print oJson.stringify(o) ' {"key1":"value\\\"2"}
o.propSetNum "key1", 123
Debug.Print o.itemGet("key1") ' 123
Debug.Print oJson.stringify(o) ' {"key1":123}

' add properties
o.propSetNum "newkey", 123 ' addkey! JS MAGIC
Debug.Print o.itemGet("newkey") ' 123
Debug.Print oJson.stringify(o) ' {"key1":123,"newkey":123}

' assign JSON 'objects' to properties
Dim o2 As Object
Set o2 = oJson.parse("{ ""object2"": ""object2value"" }")
o.propSetJSON "newkey", oJson.stringify(o2) ' set object
Debug.Print oJson.stringify(o) ' {"key1":123,"newkey":{"object2":"object2value"}}
Debug.Print o.itemGet("newkey").itemGet("object2") ' object2value

' change array items
Set o = oJson.parse("[ 1234, 4567]") '
Debug.Print oJson.stringify(o) ' [1234,4567]
Debug.Print o.itemGet(1)
o.itemSetStr 1, "234"
Debug.Print o.itemGet(1)
Debug.Print oJson.stringify(o) ' [1234,"234"]
o.itemSetNum 1, 234
Debug.Print o.itemGet(1)
Debug.Print oJson.stringify(o) ' [1234,234]

' add array items
o.itemSetNum 5, 234 ' add items! JS Magic
Debug.Print o.itemGet(5) ' 234
Debug.Print oJson.stringify(o) ' [1234,234,null,null,null,234]

' assign JSON object to array item
o.itemSetJSON 3, oJson.stringify(o2)  ' assign object
Debug.Print o.itemGet(3) '[object Object]
Debug.Print oJson.stringify(o.itemGet(3)) ' {"object2":"object2value"}
Debug.Print oJson.stringify(o) ' [1234,234,null,{"object2":"object2value"},null,234]


oIE_JSON_Quit ' quit IE, must shut down or the IE sessions remain.
Debug.Print oJson.stringify(o) ' can use after but but IE server will shutdown... soon
End Sub
```

You can bridge to IE.JSON from VB.
Create a function oIE_JSON

```
Public g_IE As Object ' global


Public Function oIE_JSON() As Object


    ' for array access o.itemGet(0) o.itemGet("key1")
    JSON_COM_extentions = "" & _
            " Object.prototype.itemGet        =function( i ) { return this[i] }   ;            " & _
            " Object.prototype.propSetStr     =function( prop , val ) { eval('this.' + prop + '  = ""' + protectDoubleQuotes (val) + '""' )   }    ;            " & _
            " Object.prototype.propSetNum     =function( prop , val ) { eval('this.' + prop + '  = ' + val + '')   }    ;            " & _
            " Object.prototype.propSetJSON    =function( prop , val ) { eval('this.' + prop + '  = ' + val + '')   }    ;            " & _
            " Object.prototype.itemSetStr     =function( prop , val ) { eval('this[' + prop + '] = ""' + protectDoubleQuotes (val) + '""' )   }    ;            " & _
            " Object.prototype.itemSetNum     =function( prop , val ) { eval('this[' + prop + '] = ' + val )   }    ;            " & _
            " Object.prototype.itemSetJSON    =function( prop , val ) { eval('this[' + prop + '] = ' + val )   }    ;            " & _
            " function protectDoubleQuotes (str)   { return str.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\').replace(/""/g,'\\""');   }"

    ' document.parentwindow.eval dosen't work some versions of ie eg ie10?
     IEEvalworkaroundjs = "" & _
         " function IEEvalWorkAroundInit ()   { " & _
         " var x=document.getElementById(""myIEEvalWorkAround"");" & _
         " x.IEEval= function( s ) { return eval(s) } ; } ;"

    g_JS_framework = "" & _
      JSON_COM_extentions & _
      IEEvalworkaroundjs

    ' need IE8 and DOC type
    g_JS_HTML = "<!DOCTYPE html>  " & _
         " <script>" & g_JS_framework & _
                  "</script>" & _
         " <body>" & _
         "<script  id=""myIEEvalWorkAround""  onclick=""IEEvalWorkAroundInit()""  ></script> " & _
                 " HEllo</body>"

On Error GoTo error_handler

' Create InternetExplorer Object
Set g_IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With g_IE
    .navigate "about:blank"
    Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do While .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    .Visible = False ' control IE interface window
    .Document.Write g_JS_HTML
End With

Set objID = g_IE.Document.getElementById("myIEEvalWorkAround")
objID.Click ' create  eval
Dim oJson As Object

'Set oJson = g_IE.Document.parentWindow.Eval("JSON") ' dosen't work some versions of IE
Set oJson = objID.IEEval("JSON")

Set objID = Nothing
Set oIE_JSON = oJson

Exit Function
error_handler:
MsgBox ("Unexpected Error, I'm quitting. " & Err.Description & ".  " & Err.Number)
g_IE.Quit
Set g_IE = Nothing

End Function

Public Function oIE_JSON_Quit()
         g_IE.Quit
         Exit Function
End Function
```

Up vote if you find useful

Comment: Does not work with Excel 2013 and IE10: Cannot invoke methods on the returned JSON object. All I can do is `cstr(oJson)`, which indeed gives _[object JSON]_

Comment: thx I don't have 2013 to test but once I do I will look into it. If you can find a work around tell us.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a .Net component. You can use .Net components from VB6 via [Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439(v=VS.71).aspx) - here's a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719105(VS.71).aspx). My guess is that .Net components will be more reliable and better supported than anything produced for VB6.

There are components in the Microsoft .Net framework like [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) or [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx). You could also use third party libraries like [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  You bring up a good point that .NET components will be better supported than anything in VB6.  That is certainly the case.  However (and I could be wrong here), JSON is simple enough that even VB6 shouldn't have a problem with it.  The VB-JSON code that I mentioned has so far worked really well.

Comment: @Ben JSON is simple, but you say the google code project used as a starting point still managed to have several bugs, so it's still possible to get it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You could write an Excel-DNA Add-in in VB.NET. Excel-DNA is a thin library that lets you write XLLs in .NET. This way you get access to the entire .NET universe and can use stuff like http://james.newtonking.com/json - a JSON framework that deserializes JSON in any custom class.

If you are interested, here's a write up of how to build a generic Excel JSON client for Excel using VB.NET:

http://optionexplicitvba.com/2014/05/09/developing-a-json-excel-add-in-with-vb-net/

And here's the link to the code: https://github.com/spreadgit/excel-json-client/blob/master/excel-json-client.dna

Answer (score 2):

Understand this is an old post, but I recently stumbled upon it while adding web service consumption to an old VB6 app.  The accepted answer (VB-JSON) is still valid and appears to work.  However, I discovered that Chilkat has been updated to include REST and JSON functionality, making it a one-stop (though paid) tool for me.  They even have an online code generator that generates the code to parse pasted JSON data.

[JsonObject link](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/xChilkatJsonObjectRef.html)

[Code Generator link](https://tools.chilkat.io/jsonParse.cshtml)

Answer (score 1):

Whether you need it for VB6, VBA, VB.NET, C#, Delphi or pretty much any other programming language on the Windows platform, check [JSON Essentials](https://pinery.systems/json-essentials-com/index.html#features). Its capabilities go well beyond just parsing and querying JSON. Using JSON Essentials you can serialize objects into JSON, make JSON HTTP calls and get parsed JSON DOM in response if you need it, re-formatting JSON, using files, registry, memory streams, or HTTP/HTTPS for writing and loading JSON data in UTF-8/16/32 and ASCII/EASCII encodings, and it comes with JSON Schema support. On top of that it's exceptionally fast, stable, standard compliant, being actively developed and supported. And it has a **free** license too.

Here are some quick samples, the first one shows how to parse and query JSON:

```
' Create JSON document object.
Dim document As JsonDocument
Set document = New JsonDocument

' Parse JSON.
document.parse "{""a"":true,""b"":123,""c"":{},""d"":[""abc""]}"

' Select the first node of the 'd' node using JSON Pointer
' starting from the root document node.
Dim node_abc As IJsonNode
Set node_abc = document.root.select("/d/0")

' Select node 'a' starting from the previously selected
' first child node of node 'd' and traversing first up to
' the root node and then down to node 'a' using Relative
' JSON Pointer.
Dim node_a As IJsonNode
Set node_a = node_abc.select("rel:2/a")
```

The next one is about saving/loading a file:

```
' Load JSON from a UTF-16 file in the current directory
document.load "file://test.json", "utf-16"

' Save document to the current directory using UTF-8 encoding.
document.save "file://test.json", "utf-8"
```

That's how simple to make an HTTP JSON request using JSON Essentials:

```
' Load document from HTTP response.
Dim status As IJsonStatus
Set status = document.load("http://postman-echo.com/get")
```

And that's how to make complex HTTP JSON requests and and parse JSON responses:

```
' Create and fill a new document model object.
Dim model As SomeDocumentModel
Set model = New SomeDocumentModel
model.a = True
model.b = 123
Set model.c = New EmptyDocumentModel
model.d = Array("abc")

' Load JSON data from a document model object.
document.load model

Dim request As String

' Specify HTTP method explicitly.
request = "json://{" + _
    """method"" : ""PUT"","
    
' Add custom HTTP query parameters.
request = request + _
    """query"" : {" + _
        """a"" : ""#a""," + _
        """b"" : ""#b""," + _
        """c"" : ""#c""" + _
    "},"
    
' Add custom HTTP form data parameters.
request = request + _
    """form"" : {" + _
        """d"" : ""#d""," + _
        """e"" : ""#e""," + _
        """f"" : ""#f""" + _
    "},"
    
' Add custom HTTP headers.
request = request + _
    """form"" : {" + _
        """a"" : ""#1""," + _
        """b"" : ""#2""," + _
        """c"" : ""#3""" + _
    "},"
    
' Override default TCP timeouts.
request = request + _
    """timeouts"" : {" + _
        """connect"" : 5000," + _
        """resolve"" : 5000," + _
        """send"" : 5000," + _
        """receive"" : 5000" + _
    "},"

' Require response JSON document to contains HTTP response status code,
' HTTP response headers and HTTP response body nested as JSON.
request = request + _
    """response"" : {" + _
        """status"" : true," + _
        """headers"" : true," + _
        """body"" : ""json""" + _
    "}" + _
"}"

' Save JSON document to the specified endpoint as HTTP PUT request
' that is encoded in UTF-8.
Dim status As IJsonStatus
Set status = document.save("http://postman-echo.com/put", "utf-8", request)

' Print JSON data of the parsed JSON response
Debug.Print status.response.json
```

And finally here's how to create a JSON Schema and perform JSON document validation:

```
' Create schema JSON document object.
Dim schemaDoc As JsonDocument
Set schemaDoc = New JsonDocument

' Load JSON schema that requires a node to be an array of numeric values.
schemaDoc.parse _
"{" + _
    """$id"": ""json:numeric_array""," + _
    """type"": ""array""," + _
    """items"": {" + _
        """type"": ""number""" + _
    "}" + _
"}"

' Create schema collection and add the schema document to it.
Dim schemas As JsonSchemas
Set schemas = New JsonSchemas
Dim schema As IJsonSchema
Set schema = schemas.Add(schemaDoc, "json:numeric_array")

' Create JSON document object.
Dim instanceDoc As JsonDocument
Set instanceDoc = New JsonDocument

' Load JSON, an array of numeric values that is expected to
' satisfy schema requirements.
instanceDoc.load Array(0, 1, 2)

' Validate JSON instance document against the added schema.
Dim status As IJsonStatus
Set status = schema.validate(instanceDoc)

' Ensure the validation passed successfully.
Debug.Print IIf(status.success, "Validated", "Not-validated")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript features of parsing JSON, on top of ScriptControl, we can create a parser in VBA which will list each and every data point inside the JSON. No matter how nested or complex the data structure is, as long as we provide a valid JSON, this parser will return a complete tree structure.

JavaScript’s Eval, getKeys and getProperty methods provide building blocks for validating and reading JSON.

Coupled with a recursive function in VBA we can iterate through all the keys (up to nth level) in a JSON string. Then using a Tree control (used in this article) or a dictionary or even on a simple worksheet, we can arrange the JSON data as required.

Full VBA Code here.Using JavaScript features of parsing JSON, on top of ScriptControl, we can create a parser in VBA which will list each and every data point inside the JSON. No matter how nested or complex the data structure is, as long as we provide a valid JSON, this parser will return a complete tree structure.

JavaScript’s Eval, getKeys and getProperty methods provide building blocks for validating and reading JSON.

Coupled with a recursive function in VBA we can iterate through all the keys (up to nth level) in a JSON string. Then using a Tree control (used in this article) or a dictionary or even on a simple worksheet, we can arrange the JSON data as required.

[Full VBA Code here.](http://ashuvba.blogspot.com/2014/09/json-parser-in-vba-browsing-through-net.html)

Answer (score 0):

Formula in an EXCEL CELL

```
=JSON2("{mykey:1111, mykey2:{keyinternal1:22.1,keyinternal2:22.2}, mykey3:3333}", "mykey2", "keyinternal2")
```

DISPLAYS: 22.2

```
=JSON("{mykey:1111,mykey2:2222,mykey3:3333}", "mykey2")
```

DISPLAYS: 2222

- INSTRUCTIONS:
- Step1. press ALT+F11
- Step2. Insert -> Module
- Step3. tools -> references -> tick  Microsoft Script Control 1.0
- Step4. paste this below.
- Step5. ALT+Q   close VBA window.

Tools -> References -> Microsoft Script Control 1.0;  {0E59F1D2-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}; C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msscript.ocx

```
Public Function JSON(sJsonString As String, Key As String) As String
On Error GoTo err_handler

    Dim oScriptEngine As ScriptControl
    Set oScriptEngine = New ScriptControl
    oScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"

    Dim objJSON As Object
    Set objJSON = oScriptEngine.Eval("(" + sJsonString + ")")

    JSON = VBA.CallByName(objJSON, Key, VbGet)

Err_Exit:
    Exit Function

err_handler:
    JSON = "Error: " & Err.Description
    Resume Err_Exit

End Function


Public Function JSON2(sJsonString As String, Key1 As String, Key2 As String) As String
On Error GoTo err_handler

    Dim oScriptEngine As ScriptControl
    Set oScriptEngine = New ScriptControl
    oScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"

    Dim objJSON As Object
    Set objJSON = oScriptEngine.Eval("(" + sJsonString + ")")

    JSON2 = VBA.CallByName(VBA.CallByName(objJSON, Key1, VbGet), Key2, VbGet)

Err_Exit:
    Exit Function

err_handler:
    JSON2 = "Error: " & Err.Description
    Resume Err_Exit

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

this is vb6 example code, tested ok,works done

from the above good examples, i made changes and got this good result

it can read keys {} and arrays []

```
Option Explicit
'in vb6 click "Tools"->"References" then
'check the box "Microsoft Script Control 1.0";
Dim oScriptEngine As New ScriptControl
Dim objJSON As Object


''to use it
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim json$

  json="{'key1': 'value1'  ,'key2': { 'key3': 'value3' } }"
  MsgBox JsonGet("key1", json)   'result = value1
  
  json="{'key1': 'value1'  ,'key2': { 'key3': 'value3' } }"
  MsgBox JsonGet("key2.key3",json )   'result = value3

  json="{'result':[{'Bid':0.00004718,'Ask':0.00004799}]}"
  MsgBox JsonGet("result.0.Ask", json)   'result = 0.00004799

  json="{key1:1111, key2:{k1: 2222 , k2: 3333}, key3:4444}"
  MsgBox JsonGet("key2.k1", json)   'result = 2222

  json="{'usd_rur':{'bids':[[1111,2222],[3333,4444]]}}"
  MsgBox JsonGet("usd_rur.bids.0.0", json)   'result = 1111
  MsgBox JsonGet("usd_rur.bids.0.1", json)   'result = 2222
  MsgBox JsonGet("usd_rur.bids.1.0", json)   'result = 3333
  MsgBox JsonGet("usd_rur.bids.1.1", json)   'result = 4444

End Sub


Public Function JsonGet(eKey$, eJsonString$, Optional eDlim$ = ".") As String
  Dim tmp$()
  Static sJsonString$
  On Error GoTo err

  If Trim(eKey$) = "" Or Trim(eJsonString$) = "" Then Exit Function
  If sJsonString <> eJsonString Then
    sJsonString = eJsonString
    oScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"
    Set objJSON = oScriptEngine.Eval("(" + eJsonString + ")")
  End If
  tmp = Split(eKey, eDlim)
  If UBound(tmp) = 0 Then JsonGet = VBA.CallByName(objJSON, eKey, VbGet): Exit Function
  
  Dim i&, o As Object
  Set o = objJSON
  For i = 0 To UBound(tmp) - 1
    Set o = VBA.CallByName(o, tmp(i), VbGet)
  Next i
  JsonGet = VBA.CallByName(o, tmp(i), VbGet)
  Set o = Nothing

  err:  'if key not found, result = "" empty string
End Function


Private Sub Form_QueryUnload(Cancel As Integer, UnloadMode As Integer)
  Set objJSON = Nothing
  Set oScriptEngine = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new one: [[VB6/VBA] JSON parsing to built-in VBA.Collections with JSON Path support](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?871695-VB6-VBA-JSON-parsing-to-built-in-VBA-Collections-with-JSON-Path-support)

It's a single self-contained module (no classes), parses JSON to nested built-in Collections (fast and lean) and supports practical subset of JSON Path (aka XPath for JSON) to retrieve values.

This means that there is no need to madly nest `Item` calls like

```
oJson.Item("first").Item("second").Item("array").Item(0)`
```

. . . but to access nested values can just use a single call to

```
JsonValue(oJson, "$.first.second.array[0]")
```

. . . and retrieve data from as deep in the hierarchy as needed.