# Parsing JSON in Excel VBA

Tags: json, excel, parsing, vba, object

I have the same issue as in [Excel VBA: Parsed JSON Object Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773683/excel-vba-parsed-json-object-loop) but cannot find any solution. My JSON has nested objects so suggested solution like VBJSON and vba-json do not work for me. I also fixed one of them to work properly but the result was a call stack overflow because of to many recursion of the doProcess function.

The best solution appears to be the jsonDecode function seen in the original post. It is very fast and highly effective; my object structure is all there in a generic VBA Object of type JScriptTypeInfo.

The issue at this point is that I cannot determine what will be the structure of the objects, therefore, I do not know beforehand the keys that will reside in each generic objects. I need to loop through the generic VBA Object to acquire the keys/properties.

If my parsing javascript function could trigger a VBA function or sub, that would be excellent.

Comment: I remember your previous question, so it's interesting to see it back again.  One question I would have is: let's say you succeed in parsing your JSON in VBA - how would you then use that "object" in VBA?  You note that the JSON structure can be of any type, so how would you navigate the end result in VBA?  My first thought might be to create a JScript which would parse the JSON (using eval or even one of the "better" existing libraries) and then iterate over the structure to produce a nested scripting dictionary-based object to pass back to VBA.  What are you doing with your parsed JSON ?

Comment: https://github.com/akaZorg/asp-xtreme-evolution/blob/master/app/core/lib/Parsers/json.class.asp Might be useful

Comment: I will create a sheet for each object and add the records on each row, creating the column if not already existing (appending in row1). Your suggested asp-xtreme-evoluton seems interesting. Was in the process of creating something very similar. I have been provided a fixed and almost working (I fixed the little "issue") of the vba-json class. We'll be using that for the moment. The working vba-json was provided by Randyr, the author of the related question.

Comment: @tim, my previous comment might not answer your question properly. I know that the structure is basically a list of tables with records. So I have an Object (key:value) representing the tables. The "key" is the table name and the value is an Array [] of the records which are Object (key:value). I don't know for a fact which table have been provided and which columns(fields) are available. For people that can't do without a strict structure, it is wild generic programing :-) no offense to anybody of course.

Comment: More easy to follow if the structures are similar but the "keys" are different.  Out of interest where is the data coming from?

Comment: I generate the json based on user request.

Comment: Do you have access to .NET's namespace `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json`?

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782076/is-there-a-json-parser-for-vb6-vba

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you want to build on top of `ScriptControl`, you can add a few helper method to get at the required information. The `JScriptTypeInfo` object is a bit unfortunate: it contains all the relevant information (as you can see in the *Watch* window) but it seems impossible to get at it with VBA. However, the Javascript engine can help us:

```
Option Explicit

Private ScriptEngine As ScriptControl

Public Sub InitScriptEngine()
    Set ScriptEngine = New ScriptControl
    ScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"
    ScriptEngine.AddCode "function getProperty(jsonObj, propertyName) { return jsonObj[propertyName]; } "
    ScriptEngine.AddCode "function getKeys(jsonObj) { var keys = new Array(); for (var i in jsonObj) { keys.push(i); } return keys; } "
End Sub

Public Function DecodeJsonString(ByVal JsonString As String)
    Set DecodeJsonString = ScriptEngine.Eval("(" + JsonString + ")")
End Function

Public Function GetProperty(ByVal JsonObject As Object, ByVal propertyName As String) As Variant
    GetProperty = ScriptEngine.Run("getProperty", JsonObject, propertyName)
End Function

Public Function GetObjectProperty(ByVal JsonObject As Object, ByVal propertyName As String) As Object
    Set GetObjectProperty = ScriptEngine.Run("getProperty", JsonObject, propertyName)
End Function

Public Function GetKeys(ByVal JsonObject As Object) As String()
    Dim Length As Integer
    Dim KeysArray() As String
    Dim KeysObject As Object
    Dim Index As Integer
    Dim Key As Variant

    Set KeysObject = ScriptEngine.Run("getKeys", JsonObject)
    Length = GetProperty(KeysObject, "length")
    ReDim KeysArray(Length - 1)
    Index = 0
    For Each Key In KeysObject
        KeysArray(Index) = Key
        Index = Index + 1
    Next
    GetKeys = KeysArray
End Function


Public Sub TestJsonAccess()
    Dim JsonString As String
    Dim JsonObject As Object
    Dim Keys() As String
    Dim Value As Variant
    Dim j As Variant

    InitScriptEngine

    JsonString = "{""key1"": ""val1"", ""key2"": { ""key3"": ""val3"" } }"
    Set JsonObject = DecodeJsonString(CStr(JsonString))
    Keys = GetKeys(JsonObject)

    Value = GetProperty(JsonObject, "key1")
    Set Value = GetObjectProperty(JsonObject, "key2")
End Sub
```

A few notes:

- If the `JScriptTypeInfo` instance refers to a Javascript object, `For Each ... Next` won't work. However, it does work if it refers to a Javascript array (see `GetKeys` function).
- The access properties whose name is only known at run-time, use the functions `GetProperty` and `GetObjectProperty`.
- The Javascript array provides the properties `length`, `0`, `Item 0`, `1`, `Item 1` etc. With the VBA dot notation (`jsonObject.property`), only the length property is accessible and only if you declare a variable called `length` with all lowercase letters. Otherwise the case doesn't match and it won't find it. The other properties are not valid in VBA. So better use the `GetProperty` function.
- The code uses early binding. So you have to add a reference to "Microsoft Script Control 1.0".
- You have to call `InitScriptEngine` once before using the other functions to do some basic initialization.

Comment: This answer seems what I want but I'm getting a `object variable not set` when trying the `DecodeJsonString` function. Are there any other references I need apart from Microsoft Script Control?

Comment: If there was a missing reference, you'd get a different error message. On what line does the error occur? On what is the value of the variables used in that line?

Comment: It occurs just after the line `Set DecodeJsonString = ScriptEngine.Eval("(" + JsonString + ")")`. The `JsonString` is just a plain json object. I've tried with a variety of Json objects and get the same error.

Comment: The best ever answer . I have just completed a POC on how to call an JSON Restful service , parse the recieved json based on your answer and then displayed it in Excel . This was very well recieved by our clients. Thank you very much . +1 for this ..

Comment: I'm using your code but having problems returns part of a JSON string where there is no subkeys. I am getting an unescaped command deliminated value for the entire "table". Any ideas?

JSON returns:

{"id":"primary_site","algorithm":"cs","version":"02.05.50","name":"Primary Site","title":"Primary Site","last_modified":"2015-05-27T16:19:40.613Z","definition":[{"key":"site","name":"Primary Site","type":"INPUT"},{"key":"desc","name":"Description","type":"DESCRIPTION"}],"rows":[["C000","External upper lip"],["C001","External lower lip"],["C002","External lip, NOS"], etc..the "rows" is the issue

Comment: These days I'd recommend [JsonBag](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?738845-VB6-JsonBag-Another-JSON-Parser-Generator). Only one class, comes with documentation, and it's very easy to use.

Comment: Note that the above approach makes the system vulnerable in some cases, since it allows the direct access to the drives (and other stuff) for the malicious JS code via ActiveX's. Let's suppose you are parsing web server response JSON, like `JsonString = "{a:(function(){(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')).CreateTextFile('C:\\Test.txt')})()}"`. After evaluating it you'll find new created file `C:\Test.txt`. So JSON parsing with `ScriptControl` ActiveX is not a good idea. Check the [update of my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30494373/2165759) for the RegEx-based JSON parser.

Comment: I got your solution to work for **VBScript** by stripping out the types and initializing by using the following: `Set se = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")`.  +1 Thanks!

Comment: `eval` is evil. An example would be `"{}), Evil(), ({""foo"":""bar""}"`. One solution is to add the code from Douglas Crockford's JSON library. It'll add `JSON.parse` function to the JScript environment. Then use `ScriptEngine.Run("JSON.parse", "{}, Evil(), {}")` and it'll throw a parse error.

Answer (score 26):

**UPDATE 3** (Sep 24 '17)

Check [VBA-JSON-parser on GitHub](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) for the latest version and examples. **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) module into the VBA project for JSON processing**.

**UPDATE 2** (Oct 1 '16)

However if you do want to parse JSON on 64-bit Office with `ScriptControl`, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38134477/2165759) may help you to get `ScriptControl` to work on 64-bit.

**UPDATE** (Oct 26 '15)

Note that a `ScriptControl`-based approachs makes the system vulnerable in some cases, since they allows a direct access to the drives (and other stuff) for the malicious JS code via ActiveX's. Let's suppose you are parsing web server response JSON, like `JsonString = "{a:(function(){(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')).CreateTextFile('C:\\Test.txt')})()}"`. After evaluating it you'll find new created file `C:\Test.txt`. So JSON parsing with `ScriptControl` ActiveX is not a good idea.

Trying to avoid that, I've created JSON parser based on RegEx's. Objects `{}` are represented by dictionaries, that makes possible to use dictionary's properties and methods: `.Count`, `.Exists()`, `.Item()`, `.Items`, `.Keys`. Arrays `[]` are the conventional zero-based VB arrays, so `UBound()` shows the number of elements. Here is the code with some usage examples:

```
Option Explicit

Sub JsonTest()
    Dim strJsonString As String
    Dim varJson As Variant
    Dim strState As String
    Dim varItem As Variant

    ' parse JSON string to object
    ' root element can be the object {} or the array []
    strJsonString = "{""a"":[{}, 0, ""value"", [{""stuff"":""content""}]], b:null}"
    ParseJson strJsonString, varJson, strState

    ' checking the structure step by step
    Select Case False ' if any of the checks is False, the sequence is interrupted
        Case IsObject(varJson) ' if root JSON element is object {},
        Case varJson.Exists("a") ' having property a,
        Case IsArray(varJson("a")) ' which is array,
        Case UBound(varJson("a")) >= 3 ' having not less than 4 elements,
        Case IsArray(varJson("a")(3)) ' where forth element is array,
        Case UBound(varJson("a")(3)) = 0 ' having the only element,
        Case IsObject(varJson("a")(3)(0)) ' which is object,
        Case varJson("a")(3)(0).Exists("stuff") ' having property stuff,
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Check the structure step by step" & vbCrLf & varJson("a")(3)(0)("stuff") ' then show the value of the last one property.
    End Select

    ' direct access to the property if sure of structure
    MsgBox "Direct access to the property" & vbCrLf & varJson.Item("a")(3)(0).Item("stuff") ' content

    ' traversing each element in array
    For Each varItem In varJson("a")
        ' show the structure of the element
        MsgBox "The structure of the element:" & vbCrLf & BeautifyJson(varItem)
    Next

    ' show the full structure starting from root element
    MsgBox "The full structure starting from root element:" & vbCrLf & BeautifyJson(varJson)

End Sub

Sub BeautifyTest()
    ' put sourse JSON string to "desktop\source.json" file
    ' processed JSON will be saved to "desktop\result.json" file
    Dim strDesktop As String
    Dim strJsonString As String
    Dim varJson As Variant
    Dim strState As String
    Dim strResult As String
    Dim lngIndent As Long

    strDesktop = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders.Item("Desktop")
    strJsonString = ReadTextFile(strDesktop & "\source.json", -2)
    ParseJson strJsonString, varJson, strState
    If strState <> "Error" Then
        strResult = BeautifyJson(varJson)
        WriteTextFile strResult, strDesktop & "\result.json", -1
    End If
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").PopUp strState, 1, , 64
End Sub

Sub ParseJson(ByVal strContent As String, varJson As Variant, strState As String)
    ' strContent - source JSON string
    ' varJson - created object or array to be returned as result
    ' strState - Object|Array|Error depending on processing to be returned as state
    Dim objTokens As Object
    Dim objRegEx As Object
    Dim bMatched As Boolean

    Set objTokens = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With objRegEx
        ' specification http://www.json.org/
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = """(?:\\""|[^""])*""(?=\s*(?:,|\:|\]|\}))"
        Tokenize objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, bMatched, "str"
        .Pattern = "(?:[+-])?(?:\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+)e(?:[+-])?\d+(?=\s*(?:,|\]|\}))"
        Tokenize objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, bMatched, "num"
        .Pattern = "(?:[+-])?(?:\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+)(?=\s*(?:,|\]|\}))"
        Tokenize objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, bMatched, "num"
        .Pattern = "\b(?:true|false|null)(?=\s*(?:,|\]|\}))"
        Tokenize objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, bMatched, "cst"
        .Pattern = "\b[A-Za-z_]\w*(?=\s*\:)" ' unspecified name without quotes
        Tokenize objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, bMatched, "nam"
        .Pattern = "\s"
        strContent = .Replace(strContent, "")
        .MultiLine = False
        Do
            bMatched = False
            .Pattern = "<\d+(?:str|nam)>\:<\d+(?:str|num|obj|arr|cst)>"
            Tokenize objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, bMatched, "prp"
            .Pattern = "\{(?:<\d+prp>(?:,<\d+prp>)*)?\}"
            Tokenize objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, bMatched, "obj"
            .Pattern = "\[(?:<\d+(?:str|num|obj|arr|cst)>(?:,<\d+(?:str|num|obj|arr|cst)>)*)?\]"
            Tokenize objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, bMatched, "arr"
        Loop While bMatched
        .Pattern = "^<\d+(?:obj|arr)>$" ' unspecified top level array
        If Not (.Test(strContent) And objTokens.Exists(strContent)) Then
            varJson = Null
            strState = "Error"
        Else
            Retrieve objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, varJson
            strState = IIf(IsObject(varJson), "Object", "Array")
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub Tokenize(objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, bMatched, strType)
    Dim strKey As String
    Dim strRes As String
    Dim lngCopyIndex As Long
    Dim objMatch As Object

    strRes = ""
    lngCopyIndex = 1
    With objRegEx
        For Each objMatch In .Execute(strContent)
            strKey = "<" & objTokens.Count & strType & ">"
            bMatched = True
            With objMatch
                objTokens(strKey) = .Value
                strRes = strRes & Mid(strContent, lngCopyIndex, .FirstIndex - lngCopyIndex + 1) & strKey
                lngCopyIndex = .FirstIndex + .Length + 1
            End With
        Next
        strContent = strRes & Mid(strContent, lngCopyIndex, Len(strContent) - lngCopyIndex + 1)
    End With
End Sub

Sub Retrieve(objTokens, objRegEx, strTokenKey, varTransfer)
    Dim strContent As String
    Dim strType As String
    Dim objMatches As Object
    Dim objMatch As Object
    Dim strName As String
    Dim varValue As Variant
    Dim objArrayElts As Object

    strType = Left(Right(strTokenKey, 4), 3)
    strContent = objTokens(strTokenKey)
    With objRegEx
        .Global = True
        Select Case strType
            Case "obj"
                .Pattern = "<\d+\w{3}>"
                Set objMatches = .Execute(strContent)
                Set varTransfer = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                For Each objMatch In objMatches
                    Retrieve objTokens, objRegEx, objMatch.Value, varTransfer
                Next
            Case "prp"
                .Pattern = "<\d+\w{3}>"
                Set objMatches = .Execute(strContent)

                Retrieve objTokens, objRegEx, objMatches(0).Value, strName
                Retrieve objTokens, objRegEx, objMatches(1).Value, varValue
                If IsObject(varValue) Then
                    Set varTransfer(strName) = varValue
                Else
                    varTransfer(strName) = varValue
                End If
            Case "arr"
                .Pattern = "<\d+\w{3}>"
                Set objMatches = .Execute(strContent)
                Set objArrayElts = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                For Each objMatch In objMatches
                    Retrieve objTokens, objRegEx, objMatch.Value, varValue
                    If IsObject(varValue) Then
                        Set objArrayElts(objArrayElts.Count) = varValue
                    Else
                        objArrayElts(objArrayElts.Count) = varValue
                    End If
                    varTransfer = objArrayElts.Items
                Next
            Case "nam"
                varTransfer = strContent
            Case "str"
                varTransfer = Mid(strContent, 2, Len(strContent) - 2)
                varTransfer = Replace(varTransfer, "\""", """")
                varTransfer = Replace(varTransfer, "\\", "\")
                varTransfer = Replace(varTransfer, "\/", "/")
                varTransfer = Replace(varTransfer, "\b", Chr(8))
                varTransfer = Replace(varTransfer, "\f", Chr(12))
                varTransfer = Replace(varTransfer, "\n", vbLf)
                varTransfer = Replace(varTransfer, "\r", vbCr)
                varTransfer = Replace(varTransfer, "\t", vbTab)
                .Global = False
                .Pattern = "\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}"
                Do While .Test(varTransfer)
                    varTransfer = .Replace(varTransfer, ChrW(("&H" & Right(.Execute(varTransfer)(0).Value, 4)) * 1))
                Loop
            Case "num"
                varTransfer = Evaluate(strContent)
            Case "cst"
                Select Case LCase(strContent)
                    Case "true"
                        varTransfer = True
                    Case "false"
                        varTransfer = False
                    Case "null"
                        varTransfer = Null
                End Select
        End Select
    End With
End Sub

Function BeautifyJson(varJson As Variant) As String
    Dim strResult As String
    Dim lngIndent As Long
    BeautifyJson = ""
    lngIndent = 0
    BeautyTraverse BeautifyJson, lngIndent, varJson, vbTab, 1
End Function

Sub BeautyTraverse(strResult As String, lngIndent As Long, varElement As Variant, strIndent As String, lngStep As Long)
    Dim arrKeys() As Variant
    Dim lngIndex As Long
    Dim strTemp As String

    Select Case VarType(varElement)
        Case vbObject
            If varElement.Count = 0 Then
                strResult = strResult & "{}"
            Else
                strResult = strResult & "{" & vbCrLf
                lngIndent = lngIndent + lngStep
                arrKeys = varElement.Keys
                For lngIndex = 0 To UBound(arrKeys)
                    strResult = strResult & String(lngIndent, strIndent) & """" & arrKeys(lngIndex) & """" & ": "
                    BeautyTraverse strResult, lngIndent, varElement(arrKeys(lngIndex)), strIndent, lngStep
                    If Not (lngIndex = UBound(arrKeys)) Then strResult = strResult & ","
                    strResult = strResult & vbCrLf
                Next
                lngIndent = lngIndent - lngStep
                strResult = strResult & String(lngIndent, strIndent) & "}"
            End If
        Case Is >= vbArray
            If UBound(varElement) = -1 Then
                strResult = strResult & "[]"
            Else
                strResult = strResult & "[" & vbCrLf
                lngIndent = lngIndent + lngStep
                For lngIndex = 0 To UBound(varElement)
                    strResult = strResult & String(lngIndent, strIndent)
                    BeautyTraverse strResult, lngIndent, varElement(lngIndex), strIndent, lngStep
                    If Not (lngIndex = UBound(varElement)) Then strResult = strResult & ","
                    strResult = strResult & vbCrLf
                Next
                lngIndent = lngIndent - lngStep
                strResult = strResult & String(lngIndent, strIndent) & "]"
            End If
        Case vbInteger, vbLong, vbSingle, vbDouble
            strResult = strResult & varElement
        Case vbNull
            strResult = strResult & "Null"
        Case vbBoolean
            strResult = strResult & IIf(varElement, "True", "False")
        Case Else
            strTemp = Replace(varElement, "\""", """")
            strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "\", "\\")
            strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "/", "\/")
            strTemp = Replace(strTemp, Chr(8), "\b")
            strTemp = Replace(strTemp, Chr(12), "\f")
            strTemp = Replace(strTemp, vbLf, "\n")
            strTemp = Replace(strTemp, vbCr, "\r")
            strTemp = Replace(strTemp, vbTab, "\t")
            strResult = strResult & """" & strTemp & """"
    End Select

End Sub

Function ReadTextFile(strPath As String, lngFormat As Long) As String
    ' lngFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strPath, 1, False, lngFormat)
        ReadTextFile = ""
        If Not .AtEndOfStream Then ReadTextFile = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With
End Function

Sub WriteTextFile(strContent As String, strPath As String, lngFormat As Long)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strPath, 2, True, lngFormat)
        .Write (strContent)
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

One more opportunity of this JSON RegEx parser is that it works on 64-bit Office, where ScriptControl isn't available.

**INITIAL** (May 27 '15)

Here is one more method to parse JSON in VBA, based on `ScriptControl` ActiveX, without external libraries:

```
Sub JsonTest()

    Dim Dict, Temp, Text, Keys, Items

    ' Converting JSON string to appropriate nested dictionaries structure
    ' Dictionaries have numeric keys for JSON Arrays, and string keys for JSON Objects
    ' Returns Nothing in case of any JSON syntax issues
    Set Dict = GetJsonDict("{a:[[{stuff:'result'}]], b:''}")
    ' You can use For Each ... Next and For ... Next loops through keys and items
    Keys = Dict.Keys
    Items = Dict.Items

    ' Referring directly to the necessary property if sure, without any checks
    MsgBox Dict("a")(0)(0)("stuff")

    ' Auxiliary DrillDown() function
    ' Drilling down the structure, sequentially checking if each level exists
    Select Case False
    Case DrillDown(Dict, "a", Temp, "")
    Case DrillDown(Temp, 0, Temp, "")
    Case DrillDown(Temp, 0, Temp, "")
    Case DrillDown(Temp, "stuff", "", Text)
    Case Else
        ' Structure is consistent, requested value found
        MsgBox Text
    End Select

End Sub

Function GetJsonDict(JsonString As String)
    With CreateObject("ScriptControl")
        .Language = "JScript"
        .ExecuteStatement "function gettype(sample) {return {}.toString.call(sample).slice(8, -1)}"
        .ExecuteStatement "function evaljson(json, er) {try {var sample = eval('(' + json + ')'); var type = gettype(sample); if(type != 'Array' && type != 'Object') {return er;} else {return getdict(sample);}} catch(e) {return er;}}"
        .ExecuteStatement "function getdict(sample) {var type = gettype(sample); if(type != 'Array' && type != 'Object') return sample; var dict = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.Dictionary'); if(type == 'Array') {for(var key = 0; key < sample.length; key++) {dict.add(key, getdict(sample[key]));}} else {for(var key in sample) {dict.add(key, getdict(sample[key]));}} return dict;}"
        Set GetJsonDict = .Run("evaljson", JsonString, Nothing)
    End With
End Function

Function DrillDown(Source, Prop, Target, Value)
    Select Case False
    Case TypeName(Source) = "Dictionary"
    Case Source.exists(Prop)
    Case Else
        Select Case True
        Case TypeName(Source(Prop)) = "Dictionary"
            Set Target = Source(Prop)
            Value = Empty
        Case IsObject(Source(Prop))
            Set Value = Source(Prop)
            Set Target = Nothing
        Case Else
            Value = Source(Prop)
            Set Target = Nothing
        End Select
        DrillDown = True
        Exit Function
    End Select
    DrillDown = False
End Function
```

Comment: The second regex version is the craziest implementation I've seen so far. What's going on in that code? I have my own regex based parser (decode only), which I posted down below

Comment: Apologies for being dense but in the update version where are varJson, strState coming from? I seem them used but not where anything other than default value is assigned. Or is that the point? You are only interested in processing based on type?

Comment: @QHarr `varJson` and `strState` are passed `ByRef`, values are assigned to them within `Sub ParseJson()`, and returned as the result of parsing.

Comment: @omegastripes Silly me. I should have scrolled down. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: The VBA-JSON author has a drop-in Scripting.Dictionary replacement github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary. You don't need Scripting runtime in that case. Thanks to @TimWilliams for this info.

Comment: @rleir sure you can use [VBA-Dictionary](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary), this parser supports it since [v1.703 commit](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser/commit/6e00390209cb015ab7df6ea03ac82b246f7081c0)

Comment: First of all, thank you, omegastripes, for writing this awesome JSON parse. 
@rleir is there a function in VBA-Dictionary that accepts string representation of JSON and returns the parsed Dictionary object? I need VBA-Dictionary since it is compatible with mac and windows. First, I tried using VBA-JSON but later found out that it does not work on mac.

Comment: Amazing function! But I had to change this line `varTransfer = Evaluate(strContent)` to this `varTransfer = CDbl(strContent)` because it was giving me an error `Object doesnt support this property or method`

Comment: @JuanPerez actually the latest version uses [this syntax](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser/blob/master/JSON.bas#L174), you should get the entire module from the repo by the link at the top of the answer.

Answer (score 13):

As Json is nothing but strings so it can easily be handled if we can manipulate it the right way, no matter how complex the structure is. I don't think it is necessary to use any external library or converter to do the trick. Here is an example where I've parsed json data using string manipulation.

```
Sub FetchData()
    Dim str As Variant, N&, R&

    With New XMLHTTP60
        .Open "GET", "https://oresapp.asicanada.net/ores.imis.services/api/member/?address=&callback=angular.callbacks._0&city=&companyName=&personName=", False
        .send
        str = Split(.responseText, ":[{""Id"":")
    End With

    N = UBound(str)

    For R = 1 To N
        Cells(R, 1) = Split(Split(str(R), "FullName"":""")(1), """")(0)
        Cells(R, 2) = Split(Split(str(R), "Phone"":""")(1), """")(0)
        Cells(R, 3) = Split(Split(str(R), "Email"":""")(1), """")(0)
    Next R
End Sub
```

Comment: Adding third parameter `Split(<string>, <delimiter>, 2)` within loop, where a single result is necessary, may improve performance.

Comment: This should be best answer. After trying for hours with other attempts I made this work within 10mins. Simple and effective. I want to note that this requires to add "Microsoft XML, V6" reference to work.

Comment: @MrXsquared It's a naive approach, but it can work with some forms of very simple JSON. If it works in your scenario and you like it, have at it. Just be prepared to deal frequently with recursive JSON.

Answer (score 9):

To parse JSON in VBA without adding a huge library to your workbook project, I created the following solution. It's extremely fast and stores all of the keys and values in a dictionary for easy access:

```
Function ParseJSON(json$, Optional key$ = "obj") As Object
    p = 1
    token = Tokenize(json)
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    If token(p) = "{" Then ParseObj key Else ParseArr key
    Set ParseJSON = dic
End Function

Function ParseObj(key$)
    Do: p = p + 1
        Select Case token(p)
            Case "]"
            Case "[":  ParseArr key
            Case "{"
                       If token(p + 1) = "}" Then
                           p = p + 1
                           dic.Add key, "null"
                       Else
                           ParseObj key
                       End If
            
            Case "}":  key = ReducePath(key): Exit Do
            Case ":":  key = key & "." & token(p - 1)
            Case ",":  key = ReducePath(key)
            Case Else: If token(p + 1) <> ":" Then dic.Add key, token(p)
        End Select
    Loop
End Function

Function ParseArr(key$)
    Dim e&
    Do: p = p + 1
        Select Case token(p)
            Case "}"
            Case "{":  ParseObj key & ArrayID(e)
            Case "[":  ParseArr key
            Case "]":  Exit Do
            Case ":":  key = key & ArrayID(e)
            Case ",":  e = e + 1
            Case Else: dic.Add key & ArrayID(e), token(p)
        End Select
    Loop
End Function
```

The code above does use a few helper functions, but the above is the meat of it.

The strategy used here is to employ a recursive tokenizer. I found it interesting enough to write an [article about this solution](https://medium.com/swlh/excel-vba-parse-json-easily-c2213f4d8e7a) on Medium. It explains the details.

Here is the full (yet surprisingly short) code listing, including all of the helper functions:

```
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
' VBA JSON Parser
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
Option Explicit
Private p&, token, dic
Function ParseJSON(json$, Optional key$ = "obj") As Object
    p = 1
    token = Tokenize(json)
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    If token(p) = "{" Then ParseObj key Else ParseArr key
    Set ParseJSON = dic
End Function
Function ParseObj(key$)
    Do: p = p + 1
        Select Case token(p)
            Case "]"
            Case "[":  ParseArr key
            Case "{"
                       If token(p + 1) = "}" Then
                           p = p + 1
                           dic.Add key, "null"
                       Else
                           ParseObj key
                       End If
            
            Case "}":  key = ReducePath(key): Exit Do
            Case ":":  key = key & "." & token(p - 1)
            Case ",":  key = ReducePath(key)
            Case Else: If token(p + 1) <> ":" Then dic.Add key, token(p)
        End Select
    Loop
End Function
Function ParseArr(key$)
    Dim e&
    Do: p = p + 1
        Select Case token(p)
            Case "}"
            Case "{":  ParseObj key & ArrayID(e)
            Case "[":  ParseArr key
            Case "]":  Exit Do
            Case ":":  key = key & ArrayID(e)
            Case ",":  e = e + 1
            Case Else: dic.Add key & ArrayID(e), token(p)
        End Select
    Loop
End Function
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
' Support Functions
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Tokenize(s$)
    Const Pattern = """(([^""\\]|\\.)*)""|[+\-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?|\w+|[^\s""']+?"
    Tokenize = RExtract(s, Pattern, True)
End Function
Function RExtract(s$, Pattern, Optional bGroup1Bias As Boolean, Optional bGlobal As Boolean = True)
  Dim c&, m, n, v
  With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = bGlobal
    .MultiLine = False
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = Pattern
    If .TEST(s) Then
      Set m = .Execute(s)
      ReDim v(1 To m.Count)
      For Each n In m
        c = c + 1
        v(c) = n.value
        If bGroup1Bias Then If Len(n.submatches(0)) Or n.value = """""" Then v(c) = n.submatches(0)
      Next
    End If
  End With
  RExtract = v
End Function
Function ArrayID$(e)
    ArrayID = "(" & e & ")"
End Function
Function ReducePath$(key$)
    If InStr(key, ".") Then ReducePath = Left(key, InStrRev(key, ".") - 1)
End Function
Function ListPaths(dic)
    Dim s$, v
    For Each v In dic
        s = s & v & " --> " & dic(v) & vbLf
    Next
    Debug.Print s
End Function
Function GetFilteredValues(dic, match)
    Dim c&, i&, v, w
    v = dic.keys
    ReDim w(1 To dic.Count)
    For i = 0 To UBound(v)
        If v(i) Like match Then
            c = c + 1
            w(c) = dic(v(i))
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve w(1 To c)
    GetFilteredValues = w
End Function
Function GetFilteredTable(dic, cols)
    Dim c&, i&, j&, v, w, z
    v = dic.keys
    z = GetFilteredValues(dic, cols(0))
    ReDim w(1 To UBound(z), 1 To UBound(cols) + 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(cols) + 1
         z = GetFilteredValues(dic, cols(j - 1))
         For i = 1 To UBound(z)
            w(i, j) = z(i)
         Next
    Next
    GetFilteredTable = w
End Function
Function OpenTextFile$(f)
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile f
        OpenTextFile = .ReadText
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 6):

Simpler way you can go array.myitem(0) in VB code

**[my full answer here parse and stringify (serialize)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21664962/334106)**

Use the 'this' object in js

```
ScriptEngine.AddCode "Object.prototype.myitem=function( i ) { return this[i] } ; "
```

Then you can go array.myitem(0)

```
Private ScriptEngine As ScriptControl

Public Sub InitScriptEngine()
    Set ScriptEngine = New ScriptControl
    ScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"
    ScriptEngine.AddCode "Object.prototype.myitem=function( i ) { return this[i] } ; "
    Set foo = ScriptEngine.Eval("(" + "[ 1234, 2345 ]" + ")") ' JSON array
    Debug.Print foo.myitem(1) ' method case sensitive!
    Set foo = ScriptEngine.Eval("(" + "{ ""key1"":23 , ""key2"":2345 }" + ")") ' JSON key value
    Debug.Print foo.myitem("key1") ' WTF

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me under Excel and a big JSON files using JSON query translated in to native form. 
https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON
I am able parse node like "item.something" and get value using simple command:

```
MsgBox Json("item")("something")
```

What's nice.

Answer (score 1):

> **Microsoft**: Because **VBScript** is a subset of Visual Basic for
>   Applications,...

The code below is derived from Codo's post should it also be helpful to have in class form, and usable as **VBScript**:

```
class JsonParser
    ' adapted from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627652/parsing-json-in-excel-vba
    private se
    private sub Class_Initialize
        set se = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl") 
        se.Language = "JScript"
        se.AddCode "function getValue(jsonObj, valueName) { return jsonObj[valueName]; } "
        se.AddCode "function enumKeys(jsonObj) { var keys = new Array(); for (var i in jsonObj) { keys.push(i); } return keys; } "
    end sub
    public function Decode(ByVal json)
        set Decode = se.Eval("(" + cstr(json) + ")")
    end function

    public function GetValue(ByVal jsonObj, ByVal valueName)
        GetValue = se.Run("getValue", jsonObj, valueName)
    end function

    public function GetObject(ByVal jsonObject, ByVal valueName)
        set GetObjet = se.Run("getValue", jsonObject, valueName)
    end function

    public function EnumKeys(ByVal jsonObject)
        dim length, keys, obj, idx, key
        set obj = se.Run("enumKeys", jsonObject)
        length = GetValue(obj, "length")
        redim keys(length - 1)
        idx = 0
        for each key in obj
            keys(idx) = key
            idx = idx + 1
        next
        EnumKeys = keys
    end function
end class
```

Usage:

```
set jp = new JsonParser
set jo = jp.Decode("{value: true}")
keys = jp.EnumKeys(jo)
value = jp.GetValue(jo, "value")
```

Comment: How does this work in a nested JSON structure with, for example, collections of dictionaries containing different datatypes?

Comment: Good question, @QHarr   Perhaps a value class could be introduced that could be used to build out an object tree of the data. For example, if an opening brace is detected, then perform a subsequent parse.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Codo.

I've just updated and completed what you have done to :

- serialize the json (I need it to inject the json in a text-like document)
- add, remove and update node (who knows)

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Private ScriptEngine As ScriptControl

  Public Sub InitScriptEngine()
      Set ScriptEngine = New ScriptControl
      ScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"
      ScriptEngine.AddCode "function getProperty(jsonObj, propertyName) { return jsonObj[propertyName]; } "
      ScriptEngine.AddCode "function getType(jsonObj, propertyName) {return typeof(jsonObj[propertyName]);}"
      ScriptEngine.AddCode "function getKeys(jsonObj) { var keys = new Array(); for (var i in jsonObj) { keys.push(i); } return keys; } "
      ScriptEngine.AddCode "function addKey(jsonObj, propertyName, value) { jsonObj[propertyName] = value; return jsonObj;}"
      ScriptEngine.AddCode "function removeKey(jsonObj, propertyName) { var json = jsonObj; delete json[propertyName]; return json }"
  End Sub
  Public Function removeJSONProperty(ByVal JsonObject As Object, propertyName As String)
      Set removeJSONProperty = ScriptEngine.Run("removeKey", JsonObject, propertyName)
  End Function

  Public Function updateJSONPropertyValue(ByVal JsonObject As Object, propertyName As String, value As String) As Object
      Set updateJSONPropertyValue = ScriptEngine.Run("removeKey", JsonObject, propertyName)
      Set updateJSONPropertyValue = ScriptEngine.Run("addKey", JsonObject, propertyName, value)
  End Function



  Public Function addJSONPropertyValue(ByVal JsonObject As Object, propertyName As String, value As String) As Object
      Set addJSONPropertyValue = ScriptEngine.Run("addKey", JsonObject, propertyName, value)
  End Function
  Public Function DecodeJsonString(ByVal JsonString As String)
  InitScriptEngine
      Set DecodeJsonString = ScriptEngine.Eval("(" + JsonString + ")")
  End Function

  Public Function GetProperty(ByVal JsonObject As Object, ByVal propertyName As String) As Variant
      GetProperty = ScriptEngine.Run("getProperty", JsonObject, propertyName)
  End Function

  Public Function GetObjectProperty(ByVal JsonObject As Object, ByVal propertyName As String) As Object
      Set GetObjectProperty = ScriptEngine.Run("getProperty", JsonObject, propertyName)
  End Function

  Public Function SerializeJSONObject(ByVal JsonObject As Object) As String()
      Dim Length As Integer
      Dim KeysArray() As String
      Dim KeysObject As Object
      Dim Index As Integer
      Dim Key As Variant
      Dim tmpString As String
      Dim tmpJSON As Object
      Dim tmpJSONArray() As Variant
      Dim tmpJSONObject() As Variant
      Dim strJsonObject As String
      Dim tmpNbElement As Long, i As Long
      InitScriptEngine
      Set KeysObject = ScriptEngine.Run("getKeys", JsonObject)

      Length = GetProperty(KeysObject, "length")
      ReDim KeysArray(Length - 1)
      Index = 0
      For Each Key In KeysObject
      tmpString = ""
          If ScriptEngine.Run("getType", JsonObject, Key) = "object" Then
      'MsgBox "object " & SerializeJSONObject(GetObjectProperty(JsonObject, Key))(0)
              Set tmpJSON = GetObjectProperty(JsonObject, Key)
              strJsonObject = VBA.Replace(ScriptEngine.Run("getKeys", tmpJSON), " ", "")
              tmpNbElement = Len(strJsonObject) - Len(VBA.Replace(strJsonObject, ",", ""))

              If VBA.IsNumeric(Left(ScriptEngine.Run("getKeys", tmpJSON), 1)) = True Then

                  ReDim tmpJSONArray(tmpNbElement)
                  For i = 0 To tmpNbElement
                      tmpJSONArray(i) = GetProperty(tmpJSON, i)
                  Next
                      tmpString = "[" & Join(tmpJSONArray, ",") & "]"
              Else
                  tmpString = "{" & Join(SerializeJSONObject(tmpJSON), ", ") & "}"
              End If

          Else
                  tmpString = GetProperty(JsonObject, Key)

          End If

          KeysArray(Index) = Key & ": " & tmpString
          Index = Index + 1
      Next

      SerializeJSONObject = KeysArray

  End Function

  Public Function GetKeys(ByVal JsonObject As Object) As String()
      Dim Length As Integer
      Dim KeysArray() As String
      Dim KeysObject As Object
      Dim Index As Integer
      Dim Key As Variant
  InitScriptEngine
      Set KeysObject = ScriptEngine.Run("getKeys", JsonObject)
      Length = GetProperty(KeysObject, "length")
      ReDim KeysArray(Length - 1)
      Index = 0
      For Each Key In KeysObject
          KeysArray(Index) = Key
          Index = Index + 1
      Next
      GetKeys = KeysArray
  End Function
  ```

Comment: Thank you for posting this code. I have a multiple record JSON string, something like: {""key1"": ""val1"", ""key2"": { ""key3"": ""val3"" },"{""key1"": ""val11"", ""key2"": { ""key3"": ""val33"" } } Can you please advise how can I loop through all the records? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Another Regex based JSON parser (decode only)

```
Option Explicit

Private Enum JsonStep
    jstUnexpected
    jstString
    jstNumber
    jstTrue
    jstFalse
    jstNull
    jstOpeningBrace
    jstClosingBrace
    jstOpeningBracket
    jstClosingBracket
    jstComma
    jstColon
    jstWhitespace
End Enum

Private gobjRegExpJsonStep As Object
Private gobjRegExpUnicodeCharacters As Object
Private gobjTokens As Object
Private k As Long

Private Function JsonStepName(ByRef jstStep As JsonStep) As String
    Select Case jstStep
        Case jstString: JsonStepName = "'STRING'"
        Case jstNumber: JsonStepName = "'NUMBER'"
        Case jstTrue: JsonStepName = "true"
        Case jstFalse: JsonStepName = "false"
        Case jstNull: JsonStepName = "null"
        Case jstOpeningBrace: JsonStepName = "'{'"
        Case jstClosingBrace: JsonStepName = "'}'"
        Case jstOpeningBracket: JsonStepName = "'['"
        Case jstClosingBracket: JsonStepName = "']'"
        Case jstComma: JsonStepName = "','"
        Case jstColon: JsonStepName = "':'"
        Case jstWhitespace: JsonStepName = "'WHITESPACE'"
        Case Else: JsonStepName = "'UNEXPECTED'"
    End Select
End Function

Private Function Unescape(ByVal strText As String) As String
    Dim objMatches As Object
    Dim i As Long
    
    strText = Replace$(strText, "\""", """")
    strText = Replace$(strText, "\\", "\")
    strText = Replace$(strText, "\/", "/")
    strText = Replace$(strText, "\b", vbBack)
    strText = Replace$(strText, "\f", vbFormFeed)
    strText = Replace$(strText, "\n", vbCrLf)
    strText = Replace$(strText, "\r", vbCr)
    strText = Replace$(strText, "\t", vbTab)
    If gobjRegExpUnicodeCharacters Is Nothing Then
        Set gobjRegExpUnicodeCharacters = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        With gobjRegExpUnicodeCharacters
            .Global = True
            .Pattern = "\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})"
        End With
    End If
    Set objMatches = gobjRegExpUnicodeCharacters.Execute(strText)
    For i = 0 To objMatches.Count - 1
        With objMatches(i)
            strText = Replace$(strText, .Value, ChrW$(Val("&H" + .SubMatches(0))), , 1)
        End With
    Next i
    Unescape = strText
End Function

Private Sub Tokenize(ByRef strText As String)
    If gobjRegExpJsonStep Is Nothing Then
        Set gobjRegExpJsonStep = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        With gobjRegExpJsonStep
            .Pattern = "(""((?:[^\\""]+|\\[""\\/bfnrt]|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})*)""|" & _
                        "(-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?)|" & _
                        "(true)|" & _
                        "(false)|" & _
                        "(null)|" & _
                        "(\{)|" & _
                        "(\})|" & _
                        "(\[)|" & _
                        "(\])|" & _
                        "(\,)|" & _
                        "(:)|" & _
                        "(\s+)|" & _
                        "(.+?))"
            .Global = True
        End With
    End If
    Set gobjTokens = gobjRegExpJsonStep.Execute(strText)
End Sub

Private Function ErrorMessage(ByRef vntExpecting As Variant) As String
    Dim lngLB As Long
    Dim lngUB As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim jstJsonStep As JsonStep
    Dim strResult As String
    
    If Rank(vntExpecting) = 1 Then
        lngLB = LBound(vntExpecting)
        lngUB = UBound(vntExpecting)
        If lngLB <= lngUB Then
            strResult = "Expecting "
            For i = lngLB To lngUB
                jstJsonStep = vntExpecting(i)
                If i > lngLB Then
                    If i < lngUB Then
                        strResult = strResult & ", "
                    Else
                        strResult = strResult & " or "
                    End If
                End If
                strResult = strResult & JsonStepName(jstJsonStep)
            Next i
        End If
    End If
    If strResult = "" Then
        strResult = "Unexpected error"
    End If
    If gobjTokens.Count > 0 Then
        If k < gobjTokens.Count Then
            strResult = strResult & " at position " & (gobjTokens(k).FirstIndex + 1) & "."
        Else
            strResult = strResult & " at EOF."
        End If
    Else
        strResult = strResult & " at position 1."
    End If
    ErrorMessage = strResult
End Function

Private Function ParseStep(ByRef vntValue As Variant) As JsonStep
    Dim i As Long
    
    k = k + 1
    If k >= gobjTokens.Count Then
        vntValue = Empty
        Exit Function
    End If
    With gobjTokens(k)
        For i = 1 To 12
            If Not IsEmpty(.SubMatches(i)) Then
                ParseStep = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        Select Case ParseStep
            Case jstString
                vntValue = Unescape(.SubMatches(1))
            Case jstNumber
                vntValue = Val(.SubMatches(2))
            Case jstTrue
                vntValue = True
            Case jstFalse
                vntValue = False
            Case jstNull
                vntValue = Null
            Case jstWhitespace
                ParseStep = ParseStep(vntValue)
            Case Else
                vntValue = Empty
        End Select
    End With
End Function

Private Function ParseObject(ByRef vntObject As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim strKey As String
    Dim vntValue As Variant
    Dim objResult As Object
    
    Set objResult = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Do
        Select Case ParseStep(strKey)
            Case jstString
                If Not ParseStep(Empty) = jstColon Then
                    LogError "ParseObject", ErrorMessage(Array(jstColon))
                    Exit Function
                End If
                Select Case ParseStep(vntValue)
                    Case jstString, jstNumber, jstTrue, jstFalse, jstNull
                        objResult.Item(strKey) = vntValue
                    Case jstOpeningBrace
                        If ParseObject(vntValue) Then
                            Set objResult.Item(strKey) = vntValue
                        End If
                    Case jstOpeningBracket
                        If ParseArray(vntValue) Then
                            Set objResult.Item(strKey) = vntValue
                        End If
                    Case Else
                        LogError "ParseObject", ErrorMessage(Array(jstString, jstNumber, jstTrue, jstFalse, jstNull, jstOpeningBrace, jstOpeningBracket))
                        Exit Function
                End Select
                Select Case ParseStep(Empty)
                    Case jstComma
                        'Do nothing
                    Case jstClosingBrace
                        Set vntObject = objResult
                        ParseObject = True
                        Exit Function
                    Case Else
                        LogError "ParseObject", ErrorMessage(Array(jstComma, jstClosingBrace))
                        Exit Function
                End Select
            Case jstClosingBrace
                Set vntObject = objResult
                ParseObject = True
                Exit Function
            Case Else
                LogError "ParseObject", ErrorMessage(Array(jstString, jstClosingBrace))
                Exit Function
        End Select
    Loop While True
End Function

Private Function ParseArray(ByRef vntArray As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim vntValue As Variant
    Dim colResult As Collection
    
    Set colResult = New Collection
    Do
        Select Case ParseStep(vntValue)
            Case jstString, jstNumber, jstTrue, jstFalse, jstNull
                colResult.Add vntValue
            Case jstOpeningBrace
                If ParseObject(vntArray) Then
                    colResult.Add vntArray
                End If
            Case jstOpeningBracket
                If ParseArray(vntArray) Then
                    colResult.Add vntArray
                End If
            Case jstClosingBracket
                Set vntArray = colResult
                ParseArray = True
                Exit Function
            Case Else
                LogError "ParseArray", ErrorMessage(Array(jstString, jstNumber, jstTrue, jstFalse, jstNull, jstOpeningBrace, jstOpeningBracket, jstClosingBracket))
                Exit Function
        End Select
        Select Case ParseStep(Empty)
            Case jstComma
                'Do nothing
            Case jstClosingBracket
                Set vntArray = colResult
                ParseArray = True
                Exit Function
            Case Else
                LogError "ParseArray", ErrorMessage(Array(jstComma, jstClosingBracket))
                Exit Function
        End Select
    Loop While True
End Function

Public Function ParseJson(ByRef strText As String, _
                          ByRef objJson As Object) As Boolean
    Tokenize strText
    k = -1
    Select Case ParseStep(Empty)
        Case jstOpeningBrace
            ParseJson = ParseObject(objJson)
        Case jstOpeningBracket
            ParseJson = ParseArray(objJson)
        Case Else
            LogError "ParseJson", ErrorMessage(Array(jstOpeningBrace, jstOpeningBracket))
    End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Two small contributions to [Codo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413337/codo)'s answer:

```
' "recursive" version of GetObjectProperty
Public Function GetObjectProperty(ByVal JsonObject As Object, ByVal propertyName As String) As Object
    Dim names() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    names = Split(propertyName, ".")

    For i = 0 To UBound(names)
        Set JsonObject = ScriptEngine.Run("getProperty", JsonObject, names(i))
    Next

    Set GetObjectProperty = JsonObject
End Function

' shortcut to object array
Public Function GetObjectArrayProperty(ByVal JsonObject As Object, ByVal propertyName As String) As Object()
    Dim a() As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim l As Integer

    Set JsonObject = GetObjectProperty(JsonObject, propertyName)

    l = GetProperty(JsonObject, "length") - 1

    ReDim a(l)

    For i = 0 To l
        Set a(i) = GetObjectProperty(JsonObject, CStr(i))
    Next

    GetObjectArrayProperty = a
End Function
```

So now I can do stuff like:

```
Dim JsonObject As Object
Dim Value() As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim Total As Double

Set JsonObject = DecodeJsonString(CStr(request.responseText))

Value = GetObjectArrayProperty(JsonObject, "d.Data")

For i = 0 To UBound(Value)
    Total = Total + Value(i).Amount
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good answers here - just chipping in my own.

I had a requirement to parse a very specific JSON string, representing the results of making a web-API call. The JSON described a list of objects, and looked something like this:

```
[
   {
     "property1": "foo",
     "property2": "bar",
     "timeOfDay": "2019-09-30T00:00:00",
     "numberOfHits": 98,
     "isSpecial": false,
     "comment": "just to be awkward, this contains a comma"
   },
   {
     "property1": "fool",
     "property2": "barrel",
     "timeOfDay": "2019-10-31T00:00:00",
     "numberOfHits": 11,
     "isSpecial": false,
     "comment": null
   },
   ...
]
```

There are a few things to note about this:

1. The JSON should always describe a list (even if empty), which should only contain objects.
2. The objects in the list should only contain properties with simple types (string / date / number / boolean or `null`).
3. The value of a property *may* contain a comma - which makes parsing the JSON somewhat harder - but may *not* contain any quotes (because I'm too lazy to deal with that).

The `ParseListOfObjects` function in the code below takes the JSON string as input, and returns a `Collection` representing the items in the list. Each item is represented as a `Dictionary`, where the keys of the dictionary correspond to the names of the object's properties. The values are automatically converted to the appropriate type (`String`, `Date`, `Double`, `Boolean` - or `Empty` if the value is `null`).

Your VBA project will need a reference to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library to use the `Dictionary` object - though it would not be difficult to remove this dependency if you use a different way of encoding the results.

Here's my `JSON.bas`:

```
Option Explicit

' NOTE: a fully-featured JSON parser in VBA would be a beast.
' This simple parser only supports VERY simple JSON (which is all we need).
' Specifically, it supports JSON comprising a list of objects, each of which has only simple properties.

Private Const strSTART_OF_LIST As String = "["
Private Const strEND_OF_LIST As String = "]"

Private Const strLIST_DELIMITER As String = ","

Private Const strSTART_OF_OBJECT As String = "{"
Private Const strEND_OF_OBJECT As String = "}"

Private Const strOBJECT_PROPERTY_NAME_VALUE_SEPARATOR As String = ":"

Private Const strQUOTE As String = """"

Private Const strNULL_VALUE As String = "null"
Private Const strTRUE_VALUE As String = "true"
Private Const strFALSE_VALUE As String = "false"


Public Function ParseListOfObjects(ByVal strJson As String) As Collection

    ' Takes a JSON string that represents a list of objects (where each object has only simple value properties), and
    ' returns a collection of dictionary objects, where the keys and values of each dictionary represent the names and
    ' values of the JSON object properties.

    Set ParseListOfObjects = New Collection

    Dim strList As String: strList = Trim(strJson)

    ' Check we have a list
    If Left(strList, Len(strSTART_OF_LIST)) <> strSTART_OF_LIST _
    Or Right(strList, Len(strEND_OF_LIST)) <> strEND_OF_LIST Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError, Description:="The provided JSON does not appear to be a list (it does not start with '" & strSTART_OF_LIST & "' and end with '" & strEND_OF_LIST & "')"
    End If

    ' Get the list item text (between the [ and ])
    Dim strBody As String: strBody = Trim(Mid(strList, 1 + Len(strSTART_OF_LIST), Len(strList) - Len(strSTART_OF_LIST) - Len(strEND_OF_LIST)))

    If strBody = "" Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Check we have a list of objects
    If Left(strBody, Len(strSTART_OF_OBJECT)) <> strSTART_OF_OBJECT Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError, Description:="The provided JSON does not appear to be a list of objects (the content of the list does not start with '" & strSTART_OF_OBJECT & "')"
    End If

    ' We now have something like:
    '    {"property":"value", "property":"value"}, {"property":"value", "property":"value"}, ...
    ' so we can't just split on a comma to get the various items (because the items themselves have commas in them).
    ' HOWEVER, since we know we're dealing with very simple JSON that has no nested objects, we can split on "}," because
    ' that should only appear between items. That'll mean that all but the last item will be missing it's closing brace.
    Dim astrItems() As String: astrItems = Split(strBody, strEND_OF_OBJECT & strLIST_DELIMITER)

    Dim ixItem As Long
    For ixItem = LBound(astrItems) To UBound(astrItems)

        Dim strItem As String: strItem = Trim(astrItems(ixItem))

        If Left(strItem, Len(strSTART_OF_OBJECT)) <> strSTART_OF_OBJECT Then
            Err.Raise vbObjectError, Description:="Mal-formed list item (does not start with '" & strSTART_OF_OBJECT & "')"
        End If

        ' Only the last item will have a closing brace (see comment above)
        Dim bIsLastItem As Boolean: bIsLastItem = ixItem = UBound(astrItems)

        If bIsLastItem Then
            If Right(strItem, Len(strEND_OF_OBJECT)) <> strEND_OF_OBJECT Then
                Err.Raise vbObjectError, Description:="Mal-formed list item (does not end with '" & strEND_OF_OBJECT & "')"
            End If
        End If

        Dim strContent: strContent = Mid(strItem, 1 + Len(strSTART_OF_OBJECT), Len(strItem) - Len(strSTART_OF_OBJECT) - IIf(bIsLastItem, Len(strEND_OF_OBJECT), 0))

        ParseListOfObjects.Add ParseObjectContent(strContent)

    Next ixItem

End Function

Private Function ParseObjectContent(ByVal strContent As String) As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set ParseObjectContent = New Scripting.Dictionary
    ParseObjectContent.CompareMode = TextCompare

    ' The object content will look something like:
    '    "property":"value", "property":"value", ...
    ' ... although the value may not be in quotes, since numbers are not quoted.
    ' We can't assume that the property value won't contain a comma, so we can't just split the
    ' string on the commas, but it's reasonably safe to assume that the value won't contain further quotes
    ' (and we're already assuming no sub-structure).
    ' We'll need to scan for commas while taking quoted strings into account.

    Dim ixPos As Long: ixPos = 1
    Do While ixPos <= Len(strContent)

        Dim strRemainder As String

        ' Find the opening quote for the name (names should always be quoted)
        Dim ixOpeningQuote As Long: ixOpeningQuote = InStr(ixPos, strContent, strQUOTE)

        If ixOpeningQuote <= 0 Then
            ' The only valid reason for not finding a quote is if we're at the end (though white space is permitted)
            strRemainder = Trim(Mid(strContent, ixPos))
            If Len(strRemainder) = 0 Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            Err.Raise vbObjectError, Description:="Mal-formed object (the object name does not start with a quote)"
        End If

        ' Now find the closing quote for the name, which we assume is the very next quote
        Dim ixClosingQuote As Long: ixClosingQuote = InStr(ixOpeningQuote + 1, strContent, strQUOTE)
        If ixClosingQuote <= 0 Then
            Err.Raise vbObjectError, Description:="Mal-formed object (the object name does not end with a quote)"
        End If

        If ixClosingQuote - ixOpeningQuote - Len(strQUOTE) = 0 Then
            Err.Raise vbObjectError, Description:="Mal-formed object (the object name is blank)"
        End If

        Dim strName: strName = Mid(strContent, ixOpeningQuote + Len(strQUOTE), ixClosingQuote - ixOpeningQuote - Len(strQUOTE))

        ' The next thing after the quote should be the colon

        Dim ixNameValueSeparator As Long: ixNameValueSeparator = InStr(ixClosingQuote + Len(strQUOTE), strContent, strOBJECT_PROPERTY_NAME_VALUE_SEPARATOR)

        If ixNameValueSeparator <= 0 Then
            Err.Raise vbObjectError, Description:="Mal-formed object (missing '" & strOBJECT_PROPERTY_NAME_VALUE_SEPARATOR & "')"
        End If

        ' Check that there was nothing between the closing quote and the colon

        strRemainder = Trim(Mid(strContent, ixClosingQuote + Len(strQUOTE), ixNameValueSeparator - ixClosingQuote - Len(strQUOTE)))
        If Len(strRemainder) > 0 Then
            Err.Raise vbObjectError, Description:="Mal-formed object (unexpected content between name and '" & strOBJECT_PROPERTY_NAME_VALUE_SEPARATOR & "')"
        End If

        ' What comes after the colon is the value, which may or may not be quoted (e.g. numbers are not quoted).
        ' If the very next thing we see is a quote, then it's a quoted value, and we need to find the matching
        ' closing quote while ignoring any commas inside the quoted value.
        ' If the next thing we see is NOT a quote, then it must be an unquoted value, and we can scan directly
        ' for the next comma.
        ' Either way, we're looking for a quote or a comma, whichever comes first (or neither, in which case we
        ' have the last - unquoted - value).

        ixOpeningQuote = InStr(ixNameValueSeparator + Len(strOBJECT_PROPERTY_NAME_VALUE_SEPARATOR), strContent, strQUOTE)
        Dim ixPropertySeparator As Long: ixPropertySeparator = InStr(ixNameValueSeparator + Len(strOBJECT_PROPERTY_NAME_VALUE_SEPARATOR), strContent, strLIST_DELIMITER)

        If ixOpeningQuote > 0 And ixPropertySeparator > 0 Then
            ' Only use whichever came first
            If ixOpeningQuote < ixPropertySeparator Then
                ixPropertySeparator = 0
            Else
                ixOpeningQuote = 0
            End If
        End If

        Dim strValue As String
        Dim vValue As Variant

        If ixOpeningQuote <= 0 Then ' it's not a quoted value

            If ixPropertySeparator <= 0 Then ' there's no next value; this is the last one
                strValue = Trim(Mid(strContent, ixNameValueSeparator + Len(strOBJECT_PROPERTY_NAME_VALUE_SEPARATOR)))
                ixPos = Len(strContent) + 1
            Else ' this is not the last value
                strValue = Trim(Mid(strContent, ixNameValueSeparator + Len(strOBJECT_PROPERTY_NAME_VALUE_SEPARATOR), ixPropertySeparator - ixNameValueSeparator - Len(strOBJECT_PROPERTY_NAME_VALUE_SEPARATOR)))
                ixPos = ixPropertySeparator + Len(strLIST_DELIMITER)
            End If

            vValue = ParseUnquotedValue(strValue)

        Else ' It is a quoted value

            ' Find the corresponding closing quote, which should be the very next one

            ixClosingQuote = InStr(ixOpeningQuote + Len(strQUOTE), strContent, strQUOTE)

            If ixClosingQuote <= 0 Then
                Err.Raise vbObjectError, Description:="Mal-formed object (the value does not end with a quote)"
            End If

            strValue = Mid(strContent, ixOpeningQuote + Len(strQUOTE), ixClosingQuote - ixOpeningQuote - Len(strQUOTE))
            vValue = ParseQuotedValue(strValue)

            ' Re-scan for the property separator, in case we hit one that was part of the quoted value
            ixPropertySeparator = InStr(ixClosingQuote + Len(strQUOTE), strContent, strLIST_DELIMITER)

            If ixPropertySeparator <= 0 Then ' this was the last value

                ' Check that there's nothing between the closing quote and the end of the text
                strRemainder = Trim(Mid(strContent, ixClosingQuote + Len(strQUOTE)))
                If Len(strRemainder) > 0 Then
                    Err.Raise vbObjectError, Description:="Mal-formed object (there is content after the last value)"
                End If

                ixPos = Len(strContent) + 1

            Else ' this is not the last value

                ' Check that there's nothing between the closing quote and the property separator
                strRemainder = Trim(Mid(strContent, ixClosingQuote + Len(strQUOTE), ixPropertySeparator - ixClosingQuote - Len(strQUOTE)))
                If Len(strRemainder) > 0 Then
                    Err.Raise vbObjectError, Description:="Mal-formed object (there is content after the last value)"
                End If

                ixPos = ixPropertySeparator + Len(strLIST_DELIMITER)

            End If

        End If

        ParseObjectContent.Add strName, vValue

    Loop

End Function

Private Function ParseUnquotedValue(ByVal strValue As String) As Variant

    If StrComp(strValue, strNULL_VALUE, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ParseUnquotedValue = Empty
    ElseIf StrComp(strValue, strTRUE_VALUE, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ParseUnquotedValue = True
    ElseIf StrComp(strValue, strFALSE_VALUE, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ParseUnquotedValue = False
    ElseIf IsNumeric(strValue) Then
        ParseUnquotedValue = CDbl(strValue)
    Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError, Description:="Mal-formed value (not null, true, false or a number)"
    End If

End Function

Private Function ParseQuotedValue(ByVal strValue As String) As Variant

    ' Both dates and strings are quoted; we'll treat it as a date if it has the expected date format.
    ' Dates are in the form:
    '    2019-09-30T00:00:00
    If strValue Like "####-##-##T##:00:00" Then
        ' NOTE: we just want the date part
        ParseQuotedValue = CDate(Left(strValue, Len("####-##-##")))
    Else
        ParseQuotedValue = strValue
    End If

End Function
```

A simple test:

```
Const strJSON As String = "[{""property1"":""foo""}]"
Dim oObjects As Collection: Set oObjects = Json.ParseListOfObjects(strJSON)

MsgBox oObjects(1)("property1") ' shows "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

[`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is more reliable than `eval` and should be safe to use as of 2023 (IE8+). These days I tend to use `htmlfile` instead of `ScriptControl` since it isn't available in 64-bit Excel.

```vb
Dim jsonString
jsonString = "{""SomeArray"":[{""SomeVal"": 42}]}"

Dim htmlfile
Set htmlfile = CreateObject("htmlfile")

' this ritual enables window.JSON
htmlfile.write "<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>"
htmlfile.parentWindow.execScript ";"

Dim json
Set json = htmlfile.parentWindow.json

' parse
Dim obj
Set obj = CallByName(json, "parse", VbMethod, jsonString)

' manipulation
' You still need to deal with getProperty stuff...
CallByName(obj.SomeArray, 0, VbGet).SomeVal = "foo"

' stringify
Dim str
str = CallByName(json, "stringify", VbMethod, obj)
Debug.Print str
```

Here is some thin wrapper for readability:

```vb
Private HtmlFile As Object
Private Json As Object

Private Sub Init()
    If Json Is Nothing Then
        Set HtmlFile = CreateObject("htmlfile")

        ' this ritual enables window.JSON
        Htmlfile.write "<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>"
        Htmlfile.parentWindow.execScript ";"

        Set Json = HtmlFile.parentWindow.Json
    End If
End Sub

Public Function JsonParse(ByVal jsonString As String) As Object
    Init
    Set JsonParse = CallByName(Json, "parse", VbMethod, jsonString)
End Function

Public Function JsonStringify(ByVal jsonObject As Object) As String
    Init
    JsonStringify = CallByName(Json, "stringify", VbMethod, jsonObject)
End Function

Public Function ValueAt(ByVal jsonList As Object, ByVal index As Variant) As Variant
    ValueAt = CallByName(jsonList, index, VbGet)
End Function

Public Function ObjectAt(ByVal jsonList As Object, ByVal index As Variant) As Object
    Set ObjectAt = CallByName(jsonList, index, VbGet)
End Function

Public Function JsonListLength(ByVal jsonList As Object) As Integer
    JsonLength = ValueAt(jsonList, "length")
End Function

Public Sub JsonListClear(ByVal jsonList As Object)
    CallByName jsonList, "length", VbSet, 0
End Sub

Public Sub JsonListPush(ByVal jsonList As Object, ByVal val As Object)
    CallByName jsonList, "push", VbMethod, val
End Sub
```