# Which 'reference' allows Json in VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba

Now, I am trying to use JSON in VBA. Which Reference should be used in VBA to allow Json objects, cJobjects?

I have tried to declare as follow:

```
Dim myObj As cJobject
```

But can't get compiler to recognize `cJobject`.

Comment: its EXCEL-VBA btw, and I have already tried "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `cJobject` is a custom class module. So, you need to all related class module for using this. Actually, It has other way to parse JSON in vba. I suggested to use that way like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627652/parsing-json-in-excel-vba).

Here is [reference](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/json/howcjobject) for using `cJobject`.

Download, **cDataSet.xls** and check it. This will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas, will try it and let you know

Comment: My worry is why I have to include so many classes? Cant it be added as a "eference"? Just a tick mark in reference and tada... we got JSON object.

Comment: I don't know, I am not familiar with this one. Just search on Internet for helping you, and parsing my search result.