# VBA: Access JSON

Tags: json, vba, parsing

I'm working on a VBA projection and am not sure how to access the "id" in this JSON. What should "players" be set to to get the id in the loop?

I've updated the question with more code.

JSON

```
{  
   "event_games":[  
       {  
       "players":[  
           {
               "id":182759
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Code

```
Private Function getPlayerID(sport As String)
    Dim JSONHttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP30
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim playerID As String
    Dim p As Object
    Dim players As Object
    Dim x As Integer

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    JSONHttp.Open "GET", url, False
    JSONHttp.send

    response = JSONHttp.responseText
    Set p = JSON.parse(response)
    Set players = p.Item("event_games")

    If openConnection(conn, gstrConnection) Then

        For x = 1 To players.Count

            playerID= players.Item("players").Item("id")
            LogWrite Now & " " & playerID

        Next
    Else
        LogWrite Now & " Could not load. Error. " & response
End If

Exit Function
errHandler:

    LogWrite Now & ":" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume Next

End Function
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the environment you are working - VBS or VBA, and post the full code, including `JSONHttp` and `JSON` variables assignment.

Comment: Okay. I updated the code. Does that give you more insight? (VBA)

Comment: Could you please post the full code, including `JSON` variable assignment. And remove extraneous `vbscript` tag, since you are using VBA.

Comment: I've pasted the whole code.

Comment: What's `JSON`? Have you added some reference to the project?

Comment: I didn't write the program. I'm assuming that JSON is referenced somewhere. It's not being set anywhere in the code.

Comment: Check if there is the reference in VBA Project - Menu - Tools - References, if not, it won't work that way since there is no native JSON support in VBA. Although what happens if you run the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the below example concerning implementation of JSON parsing in VBA:

```
Sub JsonTest()
    Dim response As String
    Dim p As Object
    Dim x As Long
    response = "{'event_games':[{'players':[{'id':182759},{'id':182760},{'id':182761}]}]}"
    Set p = GetJsonDict(response)
    Set players = p("event_games")(0)("players")
    For x = 1 To players.Count
        playerID = players(x - 1)("id")
        MsgBox "player " & x & ", playerID " & playerID
    Next
End Sub

Function GetJsonDict(JsonString As String)
    With CreateObject("ScriptControl")
        .Language = "JScript"
        .ExecuteStatement "function gettype(sample) {return {}.toString.call(sample).slice(8, -1)}"
        .ExecuteStatement "function evaljson(json, er) {try {var sample = eval('(' + json + ')'); var type = gettype(sample); if(type != 'Array' && type != 'Object') {return er;} else {return getdict(sample);}} catch(e) {return er;}}"
        .ExecuteStatement "function getdict(sample) {var type = gettype(sample); if(type != 'Array' && type != 'Object') return sample; var dict = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.Dictionary'); if(type == 'Array') {for(var key = 0; key < sample.length; key++) {dict.add(key, getdict(sample[key]));}} else {for(var key in sample) {dict.add(key, getdict(sample[key]));}} return dict;}"
        Set GetJsonDict = .Run("evaljson", JsonString, Nothing)
    End With
End Function
```

**UPDATE**

Note that the above approach makes the system vulnerable in some cases, since it allows the direct access to the drives (and other stuff) for the malicious JS code via ActiveX's. Let's suppose you are parsing web server response JSON, like `JsonString = "{a:(function(){(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')).CreateTextFile('C:\\Test.txt')})()}"`. After evaluating it you'll find new created file `C:\Test.txt`. So JSON parsing with `ScriptControl` ActiveX is not a good idea.

Trying to avoid that, I've created JSON parser based on RegEx's. Objects `{}` are represented by dictionaries, that makes possible to use dictionary's properties and methods: `.Count`, `.Exists()`, `.Item()`, `.Items`, `.Keys`. Arrays `[]` are the conventional zero-based VB arrays, so `UBound()` shows the number of elements. Here is the code with some usage examples:

```
Option Explicit

Sub JsonTest()
    Dim response As String
    Dim p As Variant
    Dim state As String
    Dim players() As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    Dim playerID As String
    response = "{""event_games"":[{""players"":[{""id"":182759},{""id"":182760},{""id"":182761}]}]}"
    ParseJson response, p, state
    players = p("event_games")(0)("players")
    For x = 0 To UBound(players)
        playerID = players(x)("id")
        MsgBox "player " & x & ", playerID " & playerID
    Next
End Sub

Sub ParseJson(ByVal strContent As String, varJson As Variant, strState As String)
    ' strContent - source JSON string
    ' varJson - created object or array to be returned as result
    ' strState - Object|Array|Error depending on processing to be returned as state
    Dim objTokens As Object
    Dim objRegEx As Object
    Dim bMatched As Boolean

    Set objTokens = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With objRegEx
        ' specification http://www.json.org/
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = """(?:\\""|[^""])*""(?=\s*(?:,|\:|\]|\}))"
        Tokenize objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, bMatched, "str"
        .Pattern = "(?:[+-])?(?:\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+)e(?:[+-])?\d+(?=\s*(?:,|\]|\}))"
        Tokenize objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, bMatched, "num"
        .Pattern = "(?:[+-])?(?:\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+)(?=\s*(?:,|\]|\}))"
        Tokenize objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, bMatched, "num"
        .Pattern = "\b(?:true|false|null)(?=\s*(?:,|\]|\}))"
        Tokenize objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, bMatched, "cst"
        .Pattern = "\b[A-Za-z_]\w*(?=\s*\:)" ' unspecified name without quotes
        Tokenize objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, bMatched, "nam"
        .Pattern = "\s"
        strContent = .Replace(strContent, "")
        .MultiLine = False
        Do
            bMatched = False
            .Pattern = "<\d+(?:str|nam)>\:<\d+(?:str|num|obj|arr|cst)>"
            Tokenize objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, bMatched, "prp"
            .Pattern = "\{(?:<\d+prp>(?:,<\d+prp>)*)?\}"
            Tokenize objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, bMatched, "obj"
            .Pattern = "\[(?:<\d+(?:str|num|obj|arr|cst)>(?:,<\d+(?:str|num|obj|arr|cst)>)*)?\]"
            Tokenize objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, bMatched, "arr"
        Loop While bMatched
        .Pattern = "^<\d+(?:obj|arr)>$" ' unspecified top level array
        If Not (.Test(strContent) And objTokens.Exists(strContent)) Then
            varJson = Null
            strState = "Error"
        Else
            Retrieve objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, varJson
            strState = IIf(IsObject(varJson), "Object", "Array")
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub Tokenize(objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, bMatched, strType)
    Dim strKey As String
    Dim strRes As String
    Dim lngCopyIndex As Long
    Dim objMatch As Object

    strRes = ""
    lngCopyIndex = 1
    With objRegEx
        For Each objMatch In .Execute(strContent)
            strKey = "<" & objTokens.Count & strType & ">"
            bMatched = True
            With objMatch
                objTokens(strKey) = .Value
                strRes = strRes & Mid(strContent, lngCopyIndex, .FirstIndex - lngCopyIndex + 1) & strKey
                lngCopyIndex = .FirstIndex + .Length + 1
            End With
        Next
        strContent = strRes & Mid(strContent, lngCopyIndex, Len(strContent) - lngCopyIndex + 1)
    End With
End Sub

Sub Retrieve(objTokens, objRegEx, strTokenKey, varTransfer)
    Dim strContent As String
    Dim strType As String
    Dim objMatches As Object
    Dim objMatch As Object
    Dim strName As String
    Dim varValue As Variant
    Dim objArrayElts As Object

    strType = Left(Right(strTokenKey, 4), 3)
    strContent = objTokens(strTokenKey)
    With objRegEx
        .Global = True
        Select Case strType
            Case "obj"
                .Pattern = "<\d+\w{3}>"
                Set objMatches = .Execute(strContent)
                Set varTransfer = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                For Each objMatch In objMatches
                    Retrieve objTokens, objRegEx, objMatch.Value, varTransfer
                Next
            Case "prp"
                .Pattern = "<\d+\w{3}>"
                Set objMatches = .Execute(strContent)

                Retrieve objTokens, objRegEx, objMatches(0).Value, strName
                Retrieve objTokens, objRegEx, objMatches(1).Value, varValue
                If IsObject(varValue) Then
                    Set varTransfer(strName) = varValue
                Else
                    varTransfer(strName) = varValue
                End If
            Case "arr"
                .Pattern = "<\d+\w{3}>"
                Set objMatches = .Execute(strContent)
                Set objArrayElts = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                For Each objMatch In objMatches
                    Retrieve objTokens, objRegEx, objMatch.Value, varValue
                    If IsObject(varValue) Then
                        Set objArrayElts(objArrayElts.Count) = varValue
                    Else
                        objArrayElts(objArrayElts.Count) = varValue
                    End If
                    varTransfer = objArrayElts.Items
                Next
            Case "nam"
                varTransfer = strContent
            Case "str"
                varTransfer = Mid(strContent, 2, Len(strContent) - 2)
                varTransfer = Replace(varTransfer, "\""", """")
                varTransfer = Replace(varTransfer, "\\", "\")
                varTransfer = Replace(varTransfer, "\/", "/")
                varTransfer = Replace(varTransfer, "\b", Chr(8))
                varTransfer = Replace(varTransfer, "\f", Chr(12))
                varTransfer = Replace(varTransfer, "\n", vbLf)
                varTransfer = Replace(varTransfer, "\r", vbCr)
                varTransfer = Replace(varTransfer, "\t", vbTab)
                .Global = False
                .Pattern = "\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}"
                Do While .Test(varTransfer)
                    varTransfer = .Replace(varTransfer, ChrW(("&H" & Right(.Execute(varTransfer)(0).Value, 4)) * 1))
                Loop
            Case "num"
                varTransfer = Evaluate(strContent)
            Case "cst"
                Select Case LCase(strContent)
                    Case "true"
                        varTransfer = True
                    Case "false"
                        varTransfer = False
                    Case "null"
                        varTransfer = Null
                End Select
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

You can find the [full version by the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30494373/2165759).