# Call Google Finance API in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, google-finance-api

I want to fetch stock price via Google Finance API in Excel.

Resource: `https://finance.google.com/finance/info`

Method: `GET`

Parameters:

- client = ig
- q = `<exchange code>:<stock code>`

example:

`https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=TPE:2330`

this request will get the stock price of Taiwan Semiconductor.

Is there a solution, no matter doing some setting of worksheet or writing some VBA code, to reach my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The methods are XMLHTTPRequest, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for getting the response. And parsing JSON with VBA for parsing the response since it is JSON. Simplest method for parsing JSON with VBA is described here [Parsing JSON in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627652/parsing-json-in-excel-vba) but there are much more comfortable libraries available with search keywords `Excel VBA parse JSON`.

Simple example for your use case:

```
Sub testGetJSON()

 sExchangeCode = "TPE"
 sStockCode = "2330"
 sURL = "https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=" & sExchangeCode & ":" & sStockCode

 Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
 oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
 oXMLHTTP.send

 sJSONResp = oXMLHTTP.responseText

 sJSONResp = Mid(sJSONResp, 4, Len(sJSONResp))

 Set oScript = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
 oScript.Language = "jscript"
 oScript.AddCode "function getProperty(jsonObj, propertyName) { return jsonObj[propertyName]; } "

 Set oJSObj = oScript.eval("(" & sJSONResp & ")")

 Set oProp0 = oScript.Run("getProperty", oJSObj, "0")

 sLCur = oProp0.l_cur
 sLT = oProp0.lt

 MsgBox sLT & " : " & sLCur

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Axel. With MSXML2.XMLHTTP, I successfully get the JSON back to my worksheet. ScriptControl failed to be execute (Error: 429). I think the problem is that my Windows is 64-bits. Any way, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Veck Hsiao: Yes `ScriptControl` is only a 32-bit ActiveX component. Try using one of the available libraries for parsing JSON wit VBA.

Comment: Trying the routine above I get a 404 not found answer. Does anyone knows if this interface still works?

Comment: Addendum: removing the "/info" in the URL (according to another source I found), I get "access denied"...

Comment: This answer from 2015 is outdated. Seems Google finance does not allow that kind of request anymore.