# Youtube API and excel - retrieve username from cell (video URL)

Tags: excel, youtube-api

This is Excel macro homework. The task is to display a YouTube video channel name, based on URL. Let's say we have column A (each cell is separate video URL) and column B in which I want to display names.

I know that by using this code:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=<video_id>&key=<YOUR_API_KEY>&part=snippet
```

I can display basic data which includes `"channelTitle"` variable. But how do I display only channel title?

Comment: Show us what "bunch of data" beholds

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LBVfM6wd example in provided URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#part

I'd say `fields`  = `channelTitle`. Play around with it  little or parse the json in VBA macro: [Parsing JSON in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627652/parsing-json-in-excel-vba)