# Parse a String in Excel Vba

Tags: regex, vba, excel, dictionary

I have a macro that send an XMLHTTP request to a server and it gets as response a **plain text** string, not a JSON format string or other standard formats (at least for what I know).

I would like to parse the output string in order to access the data in an structured approach in the same fashion as the *parseJson* subroutine in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30494373/2165759)

My problem is I am not good with regular expressions and I am not able to modify the routine for my needs.

The string that I need to parse has the following structure:

1. The string is a single line
2. Each single parameter is defined by its parameter name the equal simbol, its value and ending with; **"NID=3;"** or **"SID=Test;"**
3. Parameter can be collected in "structures" starts and end with the symbol | and they are identified with their name followed by ; such as **|STEST;NID=3;SID=Test;|**
4. A structure can contain also other structures

An example of a output string is the following

```
|KC;|AD;PE=5;PF=3;|CD;PE=5;HP=test;|CD;PE=3;HP=abc;|
```

In this case there is a macro structure **KC** which contains a structure **AD**. The structure **AD** is composed by the parameters **PE**, **PF** and 2 structures **CD**. And finaly the structures **CD** have the parameters **PE** and **HP**

So I would like to parse the string to obtain an *Object/Dictionary* that reflects this structure, can you help me?

**Adds after the first answers**

Hi all, thank you for your help, but I think I should make more clear the output that I would like to get.
For the example string that I have, I would like to have an object with the following structure:

```
<KC>
    <AD>
        <PE>5</PE>
        <PF>3</PF>
        <CD>
            <PE>5</PE>
            <HP>test</HP>
        </CD>
        <CD>
            <PE>3</PE>
            <HP>abc</HP>
        </CD>
    </AD>
</KC>
```

So I started to wrote a possible working code base on some hint from @Nvj answer and the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30494373/2165759)

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub Test()

  Dim strContent As String
  Dim strState   As String
  Dim varOutput  As Variant

  strContent = "|KC;|AD;PE=5;PF=3;|CD;PE=5;HP=test;|CD;PE=3;HP=abc;|"
  Call ParseString(strContent, varOutput, strState)

End Sub

Sub ParseString(ByVal strContent As String, varOutput As Variant, strState As String)
' strContent - source string
' varOutput - created object or array to be returned as result
' strState - Object|Array|Error depending on processing to be returned as state
Dim objTokens As Object
Dim lngTokenId As Long
Dim objRegEx As Object
Dim bMatched As Boolean

Set objTokens = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
lngTokenId = 0
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With objRegEx
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "\|[A-Z]{2};"  'Pattern for the name of structures
    Tokenize objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, lngTokenId, bMatched, "str"
    .Pattern = "[A-Z]{2}=[^\|=;]+;" 'Pattern for parameters name and values
    Tokenize objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, lngTokenId, bMatched, "par"
End With

End Sub

Sub Tokenize(objTokens, objRegEx, strContent, lngTokenId, bMatched, strType)
Dim strKey        As String
Dim strKeyPar     As String
Dim strKeyVal     As String

Dim strWork       As String
Dim strPar        As String
Dim strVal        As String
Dim strLevel      As String

Dim strRes        As String

Dim lngCopyIndex  As Long
Dim objMatch      As Object

strRes = ""
lngCopyIndex = 1
With objRegEx
    For Each objMatch In .Execute(strContent)
        If strType = "str" Then
          bMatched = True
          With objMatch
              strWork = Replace(.Value, "|", "")
              strWork = Replace(strWork, ";", "")
              strLevel = get_Level(strWork)
              strKey = "<" & lngTokenId & strLevel & strType & ">"
              objTokens(strKey) = strWork
              strRes = strRes & Mid(strContent, lngCopyIndex, .FirstIndex - lngCopyIndex + 1) & strKey
              lngCopyIndex = .FirstIndex + .Length + 1
          End With
          lngTokenId = lngTokenId + 1
        ElseIf strType = "par" Then

          strKeyPar = "<" & lngTokenId & "par>"
          strKeyVal = "<" & lngTokenId & "val>"
          strKey = strKeyPar & strKeyVal
          bMatched = True
          With objMatch
              strWork = Replace(.Value, ";", "")
              strPar = Split(strWork, "=")(0)
              strVal = Split(strWork, "=")(1)
              objTokens(strKeyPar) = strPar
              objTokens(strKeyVal) = strVal
              strRes = strRes & Mid(strContent, lngCopyIndex, .FirstIndex - lngCopyIndex + 1) & strKey
              lngCopyIndex = .FirstIndex + .Length + 1
          End With
          lngTokenId = lngTokenId + 2

        End If
    Next
    strContent = strRes & Mid(strContent, lngCopyIndex, Len(strContent) - lngCopyIndex + 1)
End With
End Sub

Function get_Level(strInput As String) As String

Select Case strInput
  Case "KC"
  get_Level = "L1"
  Case "AD"
  get_Level = "L2"
  Case "CD"
  get_Level = "L3"
  Case Else
  MsgBox ("Error")
  End
End Select

End Function
```

This function creates a dictionary with an item for each structure name, parameter name and parameter value as shown in the figure
[image]
Thanks to the function `get_Level` the items associated to structures have a level that should help to preserve the original hierarchy of the data.

So what I am missing is a function to create an object that has the original structure of the input string. This is what the `Retrieve` function do in this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30494373/2165759), but I do not know how to adapt it to my case

Comment: Can you show your code? How far have you progressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've started to write a parser in VBA for the string structure specified by you, and it's not complete, but I'll post it anyways. Maybe you can pick up some ideas from it.

```
Sub ParseString()

    Dim str As String
    str = "|KC;|AD;PE=5;PF=3;|CD;PE=5;HP=test;|CD;PE=3;HP=abc;|"

    ' Declare an object dictionary
    ' Make a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime in order for this to work
    Dim dict As New Dictionary

    ' If the bars are present in the first and last character of the string, replace them
    str = Replace(str, "|", "", 1, 1)
    If (Mid(str, Len(str), 1) = "|") Then
        str = Mid(str, 1, Len(str) - 1)
    End If

    ' Split the string by bars
    Dim substring_array() As String
    substring_array = Split(str, "|")

    ' Declare a regex object
    ' Check the reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 in order for this to work
    Dim regex As New RegExp
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
    End With

    ' Object to store the regex matches
    Dim matches As MatchCollection
    Dim param_name_matches As MatchCollection
    Dim parameter_value_matches As MatchCollection

    ' Define some regex patterns
    pattern_for_structure_name = "^[^=;]+;"
    pattern_for_parameters = "[^=;]+=[^=;]+;"
    pattern_for_parameter_name = "[^=;]="
    pattern_for_parameter_val = "[^=;];"

    ' Loop through the elements of the array
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(substring_array) - LBound(substring_array)

        ' Get the array element in a string
        str1 = substring_array(i)

        ' Check if it contains a structure name
        regex.Pattern = pattern_for_structure_name
        Set matches = regex.Execute(str1)

        If matches.Count = 0 Then

            ' This substring does not contain a structure name
            ' Check if it contains parameters
            regex.Pattern = pattern_for_parameter
            Set matches = regex.Execute(matches(0).Value)
            If matches.Count = 0 Then

                ' There are no parameters as well as no structure name
                ' This means the string had || - invalid string
                MsgBox ("Invalid string")

            Else

                ' The string contains parameter names
                ' Add each parameter name to the dictionary
                Dim my_match As match
                For Each my_match In matches

                    ' Get the name of the parameter
                    regex.Pattern = pattern_for_parameter_name
                    Set parameter_name_matches = regex.Execute(my_match.Value)

                    ' Check if the above returned any matches
                    If parameter_name_matches.Count = 1 Then

                        ' Remove = sign from the parameter name
                        parameter_name = Replace(parameter_name_matches(0).Value, "=", "")

                        ' Get the value of the parameter
                        regex.Pattern = pattern_for_parameter_value
                        Set parameter_value_matches = regex.Execute(my_match.Value)

                        ' Check if the above returned any matches
                        If parameter_value_matches.Count = 1 Then

                            ' Get the value
                            parameter_value = Replace(parameter_value_matches(0).Value, ";", "")

                            ' Add the parameter name and value as a key pair to the Dictionary object
                            dict.Item(parameter_name) = parameter_value

                        Else

                            ' Number of matches is either 0 or greater than 1 - in both cases the string is invalid
                            MsgBox ("Invalid string")

                        End If

                    Else

                        ' Parameter name did not match - invalid string
                        MsgBox ("Invalid string")

                    End If

                Next

            End If

        ElseIf matches.Count = 1 Then

            ' This substring contains a single structure name
            ' Check if it has parameter names

        Else

            ' This substring contains more than one structure name - the original string is invalid
            MsgBox ("Invalid string")

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Nvj, in the end I decided to use your approach to solve the problem, thanks

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a simple nested delimited string. A couple of `Split()` functions will do the trick:

```
Option Explicit

Function parseString(str As String) As Collection

    Dim a1() As String, i1 As Long, c1 As Collection
    Dim a2() As String, i2 As Long, c2 As Collection
    Dim a3() As String

    a1 = Split(str, "|")
    Set c1 = New Collection
    For i1 = LBound(a1) To UBound(a1)
        If a1(i1) <> "" Then
            Set c2 = New Collection
            a2 = Split(a1(i1), ";")
            For i2 = LBound(a2) To UBound(a2)
                If a2(i2) <> "" Then
                    a3 = Split(a2(i2), "=")
                    If UBound(a3) > 0 Then
                        c2.Add a3(1), a3(0)
                    ElseIf UBound(a3) = 0 Then
                        c2.Add a3(0)
                    End If
                End If
            Next i2
            c1.Add c2
        End If
    Next i1

    Set parseString = c1

End Function


Sub testParseString()

    Dim c As Collection

    Set c = parseString("|KC;|AD;PE=5;PF=3;|CD;PE=5;HP=test;|CD;PE=3;HP=abc;|")

    Debug.Assert c(1)(1) = "KC"
    Debug.Assert c(2)("PE") = "5"
    Debug.Assert c(3)(1) = "CD"
    Debug.Assert c(4)("HP") = "abc"
    Debug.Assert c(4)(3) = "abc"  

End Sub
```

Note that you can address values by both, index and key (if key existed in the input). If key was not provided you can only access the value by its index. You can also iterate collection recursively to get all the values in a tree structure.

Food for thought: since your structures may have repeated names (in your case "CD" structure happens twice) Collections / Dictionaries would find it problematic to store this elegantly (due to key collisions). Another good way to approach this is to create an XML structure with DOMDocument and use XPath to access its elements. See [Program with DOM in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766564(v=vs.85).aspx)

*UPDATE*: I've added XML example below as well. Have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another take on your string parsing issue using `DOMDocument` XML parser. You need to include Microsoft XML, v.6.0 in your VBA references.

```vb
Function parseStringToDom(str As String) As DOMDocument60

    Dim a1() As String, i1 As Long
    Dim a2() As String, i2 As Long
    Dim a3() As String

    Dim dom As DOMDocument60
    Dim rt As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim nd As IXMLDOMNode

    Set dom = New DOMDocument60
    dom.async = False
    dom.validateOnParse = False
    dom.resolveExternals = False
    dom.preserveWhiteSpace = True

    Set rt = dom.createElement("root")
    dom.appendChild rt

    a1 = Split(str, "|")
    For i1 = LBound(a1) To UBound(a1)
        If a1(i1) <> "" Then
            a2 = Split(a1(i1), ";")
            Set nd = dom.createElement(a2(0))
            For i2 = LBound(a2) To UBound(a2)
                If a2(i2) <> "" Then
                    a3 = Split(a2(i2), "=")
                    If UBound(a3) > 0 Then
                        nd.appendChild dom.createElement(a3(0))
                        nd.LastChild.Text = a3(1)
                    End If
                End If
            Next i2
            rt.appendChild nd
        End If
    Next i1

    Set parseStringToDom = dom

End Function


Sub testParseStringToDom()

    Dim dom As DOMDocument60

    Set dom = parseStringToDom("|KC;|AD;PE=5;PF=3;|CD;PE=5;HP=test;|CD;PE=3;HP=abc;|")

    Debug.Assert Not dom.SelectSingleNode("/root/KC") Is Nothing
    Debug.Assert dom.SelectSingleNode("/root/AD/PE").Text = "5"
    Debug.Assert dom.SelectSingleNode("/root/CD[1]/HP").Text = "test"
    Debug.Assert dom.SelectSingleNode("/root/CD[2]/HP").Text = "abc"

    Debug.Print dom.XML

End Sub
```

As you can see this converts your text into an XML DOM document preserving all the structures and allowing for duplicates in naming. You can then use XPath to access any node or value. This can also be extended to have more nesting levels and further structures.

This is the XML document it creates behind the scenes:

```xml
<root>
    <KC/>
    <AD>
        <PE>5</PE>
        <PF>3</PF>
    </AD>
    <CD>
        <PE>5</PE>
        <HP>test</HP>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <PE>3</PE>
        <HP>abc</HP>
    </CD>
</root>
```