# Extracting value from JSON string in VBA

Tags: json, vba, parsing

I need help on extracting value 102.498295 from JSON string in VBA. Thank you in advance.

```
{"success":true,"terms":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/terms","privacy":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/privacy","historical":true,"date":"2017-05-01","timestamp":1493683199,"source":"USD","quotes":{"USDNPR":102.498295}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON in Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627652/parsing-json-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Also: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON