# Accessing a Variant/Object/JScriptTypeInfo property in VBA

Tags: json, vba, excel, jscript

I have the following code VBA code (for an Excel module)

```
Function getDesc(ByVal pCode As String) As String
    Dim oRequest As Object
    Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    oRequest.Open "GET", "https://my.url.com/?filter=CODE=" & pCode, False
    oRequest.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    oRequest.Send ""

    Set props = jsonDecode(oRequest.ResponseText)

    getDesc = props.row_data
End Function

Function jsonDecode(jsonString As Variant)
    Set sc = CreateObject("ScriptControl"): sc.Language = "JScript"
    Set jsonDecode = sc.Eval("(" + jsonString + ")")
End Function
```

The results of props.row_data is as shown
[image]

I can't figure out how to assign the property `LONG_DESCRIPTION` to `getDesc =`

What's the proper syntax I need? Alternatively, I will accept just about any solution that will allow me to return the String of `LONG_DESCRIPTION`.

Comment: Please post `oRequest.ResponseText` content, at least a relevant part.

Comment: Note that using ScriptControl ActiveX such way you might make the system vulnerable for the a malicious JS code within the response. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30494373/2165759) and [VBA-JSON-parser on GitHub](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser).

Comment: Using this library might help here https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code. **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) module into the VBA project for JSON processing.**

```vb
Option Explicit

Function getDesc(ByVal pCode As String) As String

    Dim oRequest As Object
    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON As Variant
    Dim sState As String

    Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    oRequest.Open "GET", "https://my.url.com/?filter=CODE=" & pCode, False
    oRequest.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    oRequest.Send
    sJSONString = oRequest.ResponseText
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    getDesc = vJSON("row_data")(0)("LONG_DESCRIPTION")

End Function
```

Tested with JSON string `{'row_data':[{'LONG_DESCRIPTION':'desc_string'}]}`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need external libraries to achieve this:

```
Option Explicit

Function getDesc(ByVal pCode As String) As String
    Dim oRequest As Object
    Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    oRequest.Open "GET", "https://my.url.com/?filter=CODE=" & pCode, False
    oRequest.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    oRequest.Send ""

    Set props = jsonDecode(oRequest.ResponseText)

    Set sc = CreateObject("ScriptControl"): sc.Language = "JScript"
    sc.AddCode "function jsGetDesc(obj) { return obj[0]['LONG_DESCRIPTION']; }"
    getDesc = sc.Run("jsGetDesc", props.row_data)
End Function
```