# Harvesting few fields from json response

Tags: json, vba, excel, web-scraping

I've written a script in vba to get some fields from a link which contains json data. As I've never worked with json in combination with vba, I don't have any idea which way I pursue. I heard that power query is an option but that would be difficult for me to cope up. Any alternative solution as to how I can get those fields depicted in the below image.

This is I've tried:

```
Sub CollectInformation()
    Dim ReqHttp As New XMLHTTP60, Ohtml As New HTMLDocument
    weblink = "https://torontolife.com/wp-content/themes/sjm-underscores/inc/neighbourhoods/2015/compiled.json"

    With ReqHttp
        .Open "GET", weblink, False
        .send
        Ohtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        MsgBox .responseText  ''I can see the valid response in the messagebox
   End With
End Sub
```

Fields I'm interested in:
[image]

A piece of scattered chunck:

```
"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"HOOD":"Trinity-Bellwoods","center":"43.65241687364585 -79.41651445205076","streetview":{"lat":43.6452785,"lng":-79.4131849,"heading":-25.74,"pitch":"-1.34"},"rankings":{"Housing":19.7,"Crime":39.4,"Transit":73.9,"Shopping":88,"Health":33.1,"Entertainment":97.9,"Community":61.3,"Diversity":9.9,"Schools":64.8,"Employment":73.2},"irank":42,"urank":42},
```

To be clearer:

The keys are `"HOOD","Housing","Crime","Shopping".` 
I want to get their values.

Comment: You want which fields by name?

Comment: So, there are a bunch of records, and you want to return the values for specific fields, from all records, is that correct? (As opposed to a few single-values?)

Comment: Please see the edit. I've made it clearer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

This will do it

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetInfo()
    '"HOOD","Housing","Crime","Shopping"
    Dim strURL As String, strJSON As String, http As Object, json As Object

    strURL = "https://torontolife.com/wp-content/themes/sjm-underscores/inc/neighbourhoods/2015/compiled.json"

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", strURL, False
    http.send
    strJSON = http.responseText

    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strJSON)("features")

    Dim i As Long, key As Variant
    For i = 1 To json.count
        For Each key In json(i)
            Select Case True
            Case key = "properties"
                Dim a As Object, key2 As Variant
                Set a = json(i)(key)
                For Each key2 In a.Keys
                    Select Case key2
                    Case "HOOD"
                        Debug.Print "Hood" & " " & a(key2)
                    Case "rankings"
                        Dim b As Object
                        Set b = a(key2)
                        Debug.Print "Housing" & " :  " & b("Housing")
                        Debug.Print "Crime" & " :  " & b("Crime")
                        Debug.Print "Shopping" & " :  " & b("Shopping")
                    End Select
                Next key2
            End Select
        Next key
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

**Example output:**

[image: Output]

---

**Notes:**

If you examine the JSON structure you can see it is as follows (sample)

[image: sample]

The information we want in the dictionary returned is within "features" so we can extract that initially with:

```
Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strJSON)("features")
```

This yields a collection (see the `"["` at the start) of dictionaries. Within those dictionaries, we are interested in whenever the key `"properties"` appears, as those hold the items of interest. We can use a `Select Case` statement to filter for that key:

```
Select Case True
Case key = "properties"
```

We then set that to a variable, which is again a dictionary:

```
Set a = json(i)(key)
```

From the JSON image we can see again that we are interested in specific keys:  `HOOD` and `rankings`; in order to get the items of interest (`"HOOD","Housing","Crime","Shopping"`) .

`HOOD` and `rankings` return different [datatypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/data-type-summary).

`HOOD` returns a string:

[image: Hood]

So we can directly access the required value with the associated key:

```
a(key2)
```

I have added  `Debug.Print "Hood" & " " & a(key2)` into the code to make it clear for you but have dropped the "Hood" prefix for my run as looks cleaner, in my opinion, in output.

`rankings` returns a dictionary, see the `"{"`:

[image: Rankings]

So, if we initially set that to a variable:

```
Set b = a(key2)
```

We can avoid looping the keys and directly access via the keys of interest i.e.:

```
Debug.Print "Housing" & " :  " & b("Housing")
Debug.Print "Crime" & " :  " & b("Crime")
Debug.Print "Shopping" & " :  " & b("Shopping")
```

I have added some descriptor text so make the output clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any external converter to play around with json data. There is already a robust method out there. To run the script you don't even add anything to the reference library other than what you did for `xmlhttp` requests. To get the corresponding values you need to use `.` dot operator to call it's keys. However, in some cases you might find some contradictory names like `Status`,`Ranking`,`Properties` which are already available in vba built-in items so you have to handle them using `CallByName` function like I've done below. It's even easier (the usage of it) than pulling any item from `html elements` out of a regular webpage.

This is how you can get your required items:

```
Sub FetchJsonInfo()
    Const URL As String = "https://torontolife.com/wp-content/themes/sjm-underscores/inc/neighbourhoods/2015/compiled.json"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, SC As Object, elem As Object
    Dim resobject As Object, post As Object, R&

    Set SC = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
    SC.Language = "JScript"

    With Http
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        Set resobject = SC.Eval("(" + .responseText + ")")
        .abort

        For Each post In resobject.features
            Set elem = CallByName(post, "properties", VbGet)
            R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = elem.HOOD
            Cells(R, 2) = elem.rankings.Housing
            Cells(R, 3) = elem.rankings.Crime
            Cells(R, 4) = elem.rankings.Shopping
        Next post
   End With
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft XML, v6.0
```

Comment: You should add that `scriptcontrol` is a 32bit component only and will not run inside a 64bit process.

Comment: Also worth noting that evaluating random js outside of a browser script engine sandbox leaves you open to malicious scripting attacks...   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627652/parsing-json-in-excel-vba/30494373#30494373

Comment: Yes, I noticed it and used the same approach around years but never came accross any such issues. However, If anyone thinks crossing a road might endanger his life doesn't mean he is not gonna cross the road. Thanks for the link, by the way.