# How can I parse json in Excel vba without using microsoft scripting runtime?

Tags: json, excel, vba

How can I parse json data in Excel vba **without using "Microsoft scripting runtime"**? My company considers "Microsoft scripting runtime" to be a security risk so I can't use it.

I have been parsing JSON using vba string manipulation functions but that is painful.

Various answers in other questions suggest the VBA-JSON project, or ScriptControl, **but they need "Microsoft scripting runtime".** Sorry for using bold, but this question previously got closed, with a link to another question which recommends using "Microsoft scripting runtime".

Comment: It might be a bit easier to parse using Regular Expressions.  Or perhaps you could use the [MAC dictionary project](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary)  in place of scripting runtime.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thanks, the dictionary project is useful if I will be parsing JSON myself.

Comment: The VBA-JSON author has a drop-in Scripting.Dictionary replacement which also gives you Mac support  https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary.  You don't need Scripting runtime in that case.

Comment: @TimWilliams your comment should be an  answer. thanks -- Rick

Answer (score 1):

The answer by ExcelHero (Daniel Ferry) at

[Parsing JSON in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627652/parsing-json-in-excel-vba) and

https://medium.com/swlh/excel-vba-parse-json-easily-c2213f4d8e7a

is a big win compared to my string manipulation.