# JSON to Excel export failing

Tags: json, excel

I have been trying to export JSON format file to excel, but it has been failing in formatting due to additional square bracket. I see multiple articles providing different solution; but none of them works for me due to my lack of understanding for the language. I have following JSON output that

```
[
  [
    {
        "Port": "Port",
        "dot1x_auth": "Auth",
        "dot1x_auth1": "Auth",
        "dot1x_auth2": "Auth",
        "dot1x_auth3": "Auth",
        "dot1x_auth4": "Dir",
        "dot1x_auth5": "Mode",
        "dot1x_auth6": "VSA",
        "dot1x_auth7": "MBV",
        "dot1x_supp": "Supp"
    },
    {
        "Port": "-----",
        "dot1x_auth": "--------",
        "dot1x_auth1": "--------",
        "dot1x_auth2": "--------",
        "dot1x_auth3": "-----",
        "dot1x_auth4": "-----",
        "dot1x_auth5": "--------",
        "dot1x_auth6": "-----",
        "dot1x_auth7": "---",
        "dot1x_supp": "-------"
    },
    {
        "Port": "1/1",
        "dot1x_auth": "No",
        "dot1x_auth1": "No",
        "dot1x_auth2": "No",
        "dot1x_auth3": "No",
        "dot1x_auth4": "both",
        "dot1x_auth5": "No",
        "dot1x_auth6": "No",
        "dot1x_auth7": "Yes",
        "dot1x_supp": "No"
    }
 ]
```

]

I need an output in excel in following format

```
Port     dot1xauth       dot1xauth1
Port       Auth            Auth
----       -----           -----
1/1        No              No
```

Appreciate any assistance. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tested my VBA JSON Parser on your sample JSON and it worked as expected:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62820310/3566998