# Regular expression VBA

Tags: regex, vba

I think I have everything, but dont know the code for execution.
You see the cells in the picture. I want to delete everything before `"Title":"` and I have the regular expression for that:

```
.+(\Title":")
```

I also want to delete everything after `","URL` and I have the regular expression for that too:

```
\","URL.*
```

How can I implement this in VBA Script to delete this for every cell in this Excel sheet?

[image: Excel_Cells]

Comment: You have JSON in the cells. So [parse it as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6627652/11683).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am in full agreement with GSerg's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65406953/regular-expression-vba#comment115636903_65406953):

> *You have JSON in the cells. So [parse it as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6627652/11683).*

Regular Expressions isn't really a reliable tool for parsing JSON. Does that mean it can't be done? Well, not exactly. But you are risking coming up with unexpected results.

Your use-case looks pretty simple though. So if you were still wanting to proceed with the Regex method anyway, you could probably work with the following function:

```
Function getTitleFromJSON(s As String) As String

    With CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")
        .Pattern = "{""Title"":""(.*)"",""URL"":"""
        getTitleFromJSON = .Execute(s)(0).SubMatches(0)
    End With

End Function
```

You would just use it in a similar fashion to

```
MsgBox getTitleFromJSON(Sheet1.Range("A5").Value)
```

---

`.Execute(s)(0)` is what returns the entire match of the pattern. But you only want the data in the capturing group `(.*)`, which is where `SubMatches(0)` comes in.

[image]

---

Once again, Regex isn't the tool you should be using to parse JSON. Unfortunately, VBA lacks native support for parsing JSON, so I can understand the reasoning behind the desire for wanting to shortcut your way with Regex. But just understand that undesirable results may come out of using the *easy way out*.

Comment: hey thanks. yes I know, its a json file, but at the end I will compare it with a txt-file, so both data should be in the same shape. I will just try it like that to get the goal, maybe it will work.