# Web scraping data displayed inside button with no name

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract values stored inside different buttons on the webpage.
It seems button of each variant has no name, they are just called "variant__box", which are under "variants" div class.
As far as I can tell, values are loaded by javascript on each variant__box.

This is the website to get the data:
https://www.honda.co.uk/motorcycles/range/adventure/crf1100l-africa-twin-adventure-sports/specifications-and-price.html#/

This is the code I've written so far

```vb
Dim ie As Object
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim address, str As String
Dim jobDetailsList As Object
Dim jobitem As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.navigate address 'the one mentioned above
ie.Visible = False

While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4
    DoEvents
Wend

Set html = ie.document
Set jobDetailsList = html.getElementsByClassName("variants")
                  
For Each jobitem In jobDetailsList
    jobitem.Click
    str = jobitem.innerText
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value = str
    i = i + 1
Next jobitem
    
Set html = Nothing
ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
```

It returns nothing.

Comment: the buttons you refer to are `span` elements are they not and they cannot have a name attribute

Comment: as far as i can see, these buttons are inside a div class. values of each variant are stored within a div class "variant__wrapper". When i try to access it using getelementsbyclass, i get nothing

Comment: it's years since I played with VBA - can't even remember how to get the references set to the HTMLDocument object

Comment: looking at the page source directly there is no element directly labelled with class "variants" so it is added by javascript which means your web scrape will not work

Comment: Try this [link](https://motorcycle-api.honda.eu/api/products/v1/en-GB/bikes/crf1100l_atas?status=conLive) to get json response using xmlhttp requests and then use regex or any third party json converter to scrape the content you are after.

Comment: Thank you @SIM! By accessing the link you provided i can at least see the values i was looking for.  The problem is i have 0 experience with regex. Do you think that using the split function with ":" as delimiter will achieve somehow the same result?

Comment: Yeah, sure. You can check out [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627652/parsing-json-in-excel-vba/44596487#44596487) of my answers which is very related to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the IE you can use the following code. But SIM's suggestion is better because IE is then omitted.

```
Sub ScrapeMotorCycleData()
  Dim ie As Object
  Dim address, str As String
  Dim jobDetailsList As Object
  Dim jobitem As Object
  Dim i As Long
  
  i = 2
  address = "https://www.honda.co.uk/motorcycles/range/adventure/crf1100l-africa-twin-adventure-sports/specifications-and-price.html#/"
  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  ie.navigate address 'the one mentioned above
  ie.Visible = False
  'The following line doesn't do what you want
  'While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
  
  'You nee a loop here to wait for loading the dynamic content
  'Ask for the HTML part you want to scrape
  '(No timeout included here, but it can be programmed)
  Do
    Set jobDetailsList = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("variant__wrapper")
  Loop Until jobDetailsList.Length > 0
  
  For Each jobitem In jobDetailsList
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value = jobitem.innerText
    i = i + 1
  Next jobitem
  
  ie.Quit
  Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```