# Use ScriptControl to parse JSON in VBA: transform result to dictionaries and collections

Tags: json, vba

I would like to use Microsoft ScriptControl to parse a JSON string in VBA, and then transform the resulting Object into Dictionary and Collection objects. I already know how to do the parsing with ScriptControl, but cannot figure out how to map the result into the Dictionary and Collection classes. I'm guessing that if I could figure out how to loop through the properties of an Object this would become clear...

```
Dim sc As ScriptControl
Dim obj As Variant

Set sc = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
sc.Language = "JScript"

Set obj = sc.Eval("("+json+")") ' json is a string containing raw JSON

' Now what?
```

By the way, I've used the [vba-json](http://code.google.com/p/vba-json/) library to get the output in terms of Dictionaries and Collections, but I find this library somewhat slow. It does not use ScriptControl.

**EDIT**: I found a discussion of getting object properties in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773683/excel-vba-parsed-json-object-loop) post.

Comment: This has a security risk, see this blog post http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/01/vba-parse-json-safer-with-jsonparse-and.html  The same blog post directs to using Douglas Crockford's parsing library which solves security hole.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript features of parsing JSON, on top of ScriptControl, we can create a parser in VBA which will list each and every data point inside the JSON. No matter how nested or complex the data structure is, as long as we provide a valid JSON, this parser will return a complete tree structure.

JavaScript’s Eval, getKeys and getProperty methods provide building blocks for validating and reading JSON.

Coupled with a recursive function in VBA we can iterate through all the keys (up to nth level) in a JSON string. Then using a Tree control (used in this article) or a dictionary or even on a simple worksheet, we can arrange the JSON data as required.

VBA Code:http://ashuvba.blogspot.in/2014/09/json-parser-in-vba-browsing-through-net.html

Answer (score -1):

loop
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773683/excel-vba-parsed-json-object-loop/19359035#19359035) will help you to loop - add a myitem(n) method in javascript
from there you can map through VB code.