# How do I output a list of dictionaries to an Excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, list, file-io, dictionary

I have a list called 'players' that consists of dictionaries. It looks like this:

```
players = [{'dailyWinners': 3, 'dailyFreePlayed': 2, 'user': 'Player1', 'bank': 0.06},
{'dailyWinners': 3, 'dailyFreePlayed': 2, 'user': 'Player2', 'bank': 4.0},
{'dailyWinners': 1, 'dailyFree': 2, 'user': 'Player3', 'bank': 3.1},
{'dailyWinners': 3, 'dailyFree': 2, 'user': 'Player4', 'bank': 0.32}]
```

It's much longer, but this is an excerpt. How do I output this list of dictionaries to an Excel file so it's neatly organized by key/value?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What is exactly the problem?  Travesing the data structures or generating Excel files?

Comment: Excel can import csv files. Lookup `csv` module. Esp. `DictWriter`.

Comment: Excel can import data in `csv` format and Python just happens to have a [`csv` package](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) with a `DictWriter` that writes dictionaries to `csv`.

Comment: @zch Just beat me to it. I'm leaving my comment for the link.

Comment: Previous similar Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391768/excel-vba-macro-using-itunes-search-api-fastest-way-to-query-parse-json-resu/14393532#comment20343383_14393532

Comment: What would the code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**test.py**

```
from csv import DictWriter

players = [{'dailyWinners': 3, 'dailyFreePlayed': 2, 'user': 'Player1', 'bank': 0.06},
{'dailyWinners': 3, 'dailyFreePlayed': 2, 'user': 'Player2', 'bank': 4.0},
{'dailyWinners': 1, 'dailyFree': 2, 'user': 'Player3', 'bank': 3.1},            
{'dailyWinners': 3, 'dailyFree': 2, 'user': 'Player4', 'bank': 0.32}]

with open('spreadsheet.csv','w') as outfile:
    writer = DictWriter(outfile, ('dailyWinners','dailyFreePlayed','dailyFree','user','bank'))
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(players)
```

Run `python test.py`

Then open the resulting `spreadsheet.csv` file in Excel.

NOTE: I'm running Linux so I wasn't able to test this using Microsoft Excel. This works in LibreOffice Calc and gives a spreadsheet where the keys are the column names and the values are under their appropriate columns.

Comment: hey, thanks so much. I ran this though and a csv. file didn't open. Is it saved somewhere?

Comment: @AlexKlinghoffer There was a typo in `writeheader`. I'd try copying the fixed version over and running it again... the `spreadsheet.csv` should be generated wherever you ran the script from.

Comment: Hey Mike, I really appreciate your help. I tried copying again, but when I run it, it just says: 

Exit status: 0
logout

[Process completed]

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this in Windows? Exit status 0 should mean it completed successfully. Is there a spreadsheet.csv file in the directory you just ran test.py in?

Comment: I'm running it in the terminal on my mac.

Comment: @AlexKlinghoffer The file will be generated in whatever directory your terminal is open to. To find out if the file was generated do `ls` after you run python and look for a file with the name `spreadsheet.csv`. To find out which directory it's in run the command `pwd`.

Comment: @AlexKlinghoffer I'm glad it helped you. If this answer satisfies your question please select it as the correct answer (click the check mark) so that it can be closed out.

Answer (score 21):

**Solution using Pandas**

```
import pandas as pd

players = [{'dailyWinners': 3, 'dailyFreePlayed': 2, 'user': 'Player1', 'bank': 0.06},
{'dailyWinners': 3, 'dailyFreePlayed': 2, 'user': 'Player2', 'bank': 4.0},
{'dailyWinners': 1, 'dailyFreePlayed': 2, 'user': 'Player3', 'bank': 3.1},
{'dailyWinners': 3, 'dailyFreePlayed': 2, 'user': 'Player4', 'bank': 0.32}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(players)

print (df)

df.to_excel('players.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 18):

There is a way to write a list of dictionary to an Excel worksheet. First of all, be sure you have `XlsxWriter package`.

```
from xlsxwriter import Workbook
players = [{'dailyWinners': 3, 'dailyFree': 2, 'user': 'Player1', 'bank': 0.06},
{'dailyWinners': 3, 'dailyFree': 2, 'user': 'Player2', 'bank': 4.0},
{'dailyWinners': 1, 'dailyFree': 2, 'user': 'Player3', 'bank': 3.1},
{'dailyWinners': 3, 'dailyFree': 2, 'user': 'Player4', 'bank': 0.32}]

ordered_list=["user", "dailyWinners", "dailyFree", "bank"] # List object calls by index, but the dict object calls items randomly

wb=Workbook("New File.xlsx")
ws=wb.add_worksheet("New Sheet") # Or leave it blank. The default name is "Sheet 1"

first_row=0
for header in ordered_list:
    col=ordered_list.index(header) # We are keeping order.
    ws.write(first_row,col,header) # We have written first row which is the header of worksheet also.

row=1
for player in players:
    for _key,_value in player.items():
        col=ordered_list.index(_key)
        ws.write(row,col,_value)
    row+=1 #enter the next row
wb.close()
```

I tried the code, and it worked successfully.

Answer (score 4):

The `xlsxwriter` library is great for creating `.xlsx` files (originally mentioned by Fatih1923).

---

The following snippet generates an `.xlsx` file from a list of dicts while stating the **order** and the **displayed names**:

```
import xlsxwriter

# ...

def create_xlsx_file(file_path: str, headers: dict, items: list):
    with xlsxwriter.Workbook(file_path) as workbook:
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        worksheet.write_row(row=0, col=0, data=headers.values())
        header_keys = list(headers.keys())
        for index, item in enumerate(items):
            row = map(lambda field_id: item.get(field_id, ''), header_keys)
            worksheet.write_row(row=index + 1, col=0, data=row)
```

Usage

```
headers = {
    'bank': 'Money in Bank',
    'dailyWinners': 'Daily Winners',
    'dailyFree': 'Daily Free',
    'user': 'User',
}

players = [
    {'dailyWinners': 3, 'dailyFreePlayed': 2, 'user': 'Player1', 'bank': 0.06},
    {'dailyWinners': 3, 'dailyFreePlayed': 2, 'user': 'Player2', 'bank': 4.0},
    {'dailyWinners': 1, 'dailyFree': 2, 'user': 'Player3', 'bank': 3.1},
    {'dailyWinners': 3, 'dailyFree': 2, 'user': 'Player4', 'bank': 0.32}
]

create_xlsx_file("my xslx file.xlsx", headers, players)
```

> Note - The `headers` dict represent both the **order** and the **displayed name**. If you're not using Python3.6+, use `OrderedDict` in `headers`, since the order in `dict` is not preserved

[image]