# VBA: Creating substrings out of JSON and reformatting into columns

Tags: json, vba, excel, substring

I have information from a Facebook FQL Query in the form of JSON and pasted it into Excel. Here's a part of the result:

> "data": [
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "Hilton Head Island - TravelTell", 
>   "location": {
>     "street": "7 Office Way, Suite 215", 
>     "city": "Hilton Head Island", 
>     "state": "SC"
>   }, 
>   "fan_count": 143234, 
>   "talking_about_count": 18234, 
>   "were_here_count": 4196
> }, 
> {
>   "name": "Hilton Hawaiian Village Waikiki Beach Resort", 
>   "location": {
>     "street": "2005 Kalia Road", 
>     "city": "Honolulu", 
>     "state": "HI"
>   }, 
>   "fan_count": 34072, 
>   "talking_about_count": 4877, 
>   "were_here_count": 229999
> }, 
> {
>   "name": "Hilton New York", 
>   "location": {
>     "street": "1335 Avenue of the Americas", 
>     "city": "New York", 
>     "state": "NY"
>   }, 
>   "fan_count": 12885, 
>   "talking_about_count": 969, 
>   "were_here_count": 72206
> },
> ```

I'm trying to use substrings to parse the data and then create columns on another worksheet using "name, street, city, state, fan_count, etc." as the column headers. I'm trying out code to do this for just "name:" right now but there's an error when it hits the line with documentText = myRange.Text . I can't figure out what the error is.

Another problem is that the strings contain quotations. For example, I want the SecondTerm to be ", but I get errors when I try to have it equal "","

> Sub Substring_Test()
>
> ```
> Dim nameFirstTerm As String
> Dim nameSecondTerm As String
> Dim myRange As Range
> Dim documentText As String
>
> Dim startPos As Long 'Stores the starting position of firstTerm
> Dim stopPos As Long 'Stores the starting position of secondTerm based on first term's location
> Dim nextPosition As Long 'The next position to search for the firstTerm
>
> nextPosition = 1
>
> 'First and Second terms as defined by your example.  Obviously, this will have to be more dynamic
> 'if you want to parse more than justpatientFirstname.
> firstTerm = "name"": """
> secondTerm = ""","""
>
> 'Get all the document text and store it in a variable.
> Set myRange = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
> 'Maximum limit of a string is 2 billion characters.
> 'So, hopefully your document is not bigger than that.  However, expect declining performance based on how big doucment is
> documentText = myRange.Text
>
> 'Loop documentText till you can't find any more matching "terms"
> Do Until nextPosition = 0
>     startPos = InStr(nextPosition, documentText, firstTerm, vbTextCompare)
>     stopPos = InStr(startPos, documentText, secondTerm, vbTextCompare)
>     Debug.Print Mid$(documentText, startPos + Len(firstTerm), stopPos - startPos - Len(secondTerm))
>     nextPosition = InStr(stopPos, documentText, firstTerm, vbTextCompare)
> Loop
>
> Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = documentText
> ```
>
> End Sub

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822672/parsing-a-json-object-array-in-excel-vba/14823059#14823059

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130849/convert-json-format-to-csv-format-for-ms-excel It sounds like this answer will free you from having to hand-parse the json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work although you may need to change some of the sheet names

```
Sub Test()
    Dim vData() As Variant
    Dim vHeaders As Variant
    Dim vCell As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    vHeaders = Array("Name", "Street", "City", "State", "Fan Count", "Talking About Count", "Were Here Count")

    i = 1
    Do While i <= ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If InStr(Cells(i, 1).Text, "{") Or _
           InStr(Cells(i, 1).Text, "}") Or _
           Cells(i, 1).Text = """data"": [" Or _
           Cells(i, 1).Text = "" Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        Else
            Cells(i, 1).Value = Replace(Cells(i, 1).Text, """", "")
            Cells(i, 1).Value = Replace(Cells(i, 1).Text, ",", "")
            Cells(i, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(Cells(i, 1).Text)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop

    i = 0
    For Each vCell In Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1))
        If InStr(vCell.Text, "name:") Then
            i = i + 1
            ReDim Preserve vData(1 To 7, 1 To i)
        End If

        If InStr(vCell.Text, "name") Then
            vData(1, i) = Right(vCell.Text, Len(vCell.Text) - InStr(1, vCell.Text, ":"))
        End If

        If InStr(vCell.Text, "street") Then
            vData(2, i) = Right(vCell.Text, Len(vCell.Text) - InStr(1, vCell.Text, ":"))

        End If

        If InStr(vCell.Text, "city") Then
            vData(3, i) = Right(vCell.Text, Len(vCell.Text) - InStr(1, vCell.Text, ":"))

        End If

        If InStr(vCell.Text, "state") Then
            vData(4, i) = Right(vCell.Text, Len(vCell.Text) - InStr(1, vCell.Text, ":"))
        End If

        If InStr(vCell.Text, "fan_count") Then
            vData(5, i) = Right(vCell.Text, Len(vCell.Text) - InStr(1, vCell.Text, ":"))

        End If

        If InStr(vCell.Text, "talking_about_count") Then
            vData(6, i) = Right(vCell.Text, Len(vCell.Text) - InStr(1, vCell.Text, ":"))

        End If

        If InStr(vCell.Text, "were_here_count") Then
            vData(7, i) = Right(vCell.Text, Len(vCell.Text) - InStr(1, vCell.Text, ":"))
        End If
    Next

    'Cells.Delete
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(vData, 2), UBound(vData))).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vData)
    Rows(1).EntireRow.Insert
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, UBound(vHeaders) + 1)).Value = vHeaders

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim json As String
    Dim sc As Object
    Dim o, loc, x, num

    Set sc = CreateObject("scriptcontrol")
    sc.Language = "JScript"

    json = ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Value
    'Debug.Print json

    sc.Eval "var obj=(" & json & ")" 'evaluate the json response

    'Add some accessor functions...
    '  get count of records returned
    sc.AddCode "function getCount(){return obj.data.length;}"

    '  return a specific record (with some properties renamed)
    sc.AddCode "function getItem(i){var o=obj.data[i];" & vbLf & _
                      "return {nm:o.name,loc:o.location," & vbLf & _
                      "f:o.fan_count,ta:o.talking_about_count," & vbLf & _
                      "wh:o.were_here_count};}"

    num = sc.Run("getCount")
    Debug.Print "#Items", num

    For x = 0 To num - 1
        Debug.Print ""
        Set o = sc.Run("getItem", x)
        Debug.Print "Name", o.nm
        Debug.Print "Street", o.loc.street
        Debug.Print "City", o.loc.city
        Debug.Print "Street", o.loc.street
        Debug.Print "Fans", o.f
        Debug.Print "talking_about", o.ta
        Debug.Print "were_here", o.wh
    Next x

End Sub
```

**Note:** the javascript `getItem` function dosn't return a record directly, but wraps the data so that some of the JSON-drived property names are altered (specifically "name" and "location").  VBA seems to have a problem dealing with accessing properties on objects passed from javascript if the property name resembles a "regular" property like `Name` (or `Location`).

Comment: Thanks for the help!I'd give you useful points if I had enough reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue about the 1st part (not familiar with JSON at all), but regarding the 2nd one - try the following lines:

```
firstTerm = Chr(34) & "name: " & Chr(34)
secondTerm = Chr(34) & ","
```

Or simply - use `Chr(34)` for every double quote you want.