# Sort delimited large text file by one field

Tags: excel, text, ms-access-2010, text-mining

I have a Large delimited text file that is like this :

```
{
    "reviewerID": "A1EWN6KZ4HMLT7",
    "asin": "011040047X",
    "reviewerName": "S. Prescott",
    "helpful": [
        2,
        2
    ],
    "reviewText": "The case pictured is a soft violet color, but the case cover I received was a dark purple. While I'm sure the quality of the product is fine, the color is very different.",
    "overall": 1,
    "summary": "Wrong color",
    "unixReviewTime": 1344902400,
    "reviewTime": "08 14, 2012"
}
```

I cant import all of data to excel because of large size and when I imported to access this Error show to me that because of  bad sector and large file cant import youre data.

And now I want to separate records  that are same in one field .
then I want to sort them by that field and then cut them to another file.
now what can I do?

Comment: How large is the file? How did you try to import to Excel?

Comment: That looks like JSON-formatted data, which isn't going to be understood by Excel or Access.  You will need to find some way to parse that before you import it.  If you Google "JSON VBA" you will get some hits which will offer suggestions on how you do that.

Comment: For JSON, you're probably going to want to parse it into something easier for Excel to read.  However, there are some threads that discuss using JSON and VBA.  [Here's one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627652/parsing-json-in-excel-vba), [here's another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360440/how-to-parse-json-with-vba-without-external-libraries) that also has some links that might help. Look at Juan's answer [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/640780-parse-json-excel-visual-basic-applications.html). Also this [gitHub library](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)

Comment: Access does not provide a way to import JSON data directly. However, you could use a third-party tool to convert the JSON data into XML and then use the XML Import feature of Access.

Comment: my data is about 2 GB.

Comment: I open it in excel and excel know my rows and columns but cant import all of them because of being large.

Comment: access dose not import none of them.

Comment: are there any tool to parse my json data to excel without programming? or maybe some one can help me?