# How to directly upload contents from a JSON file

Tags: json, excel, upload, vba

I need to upload data from a text file to Excel. It's JSON data. It's around 50kB. If I regularly upload it into a cell, Excel freezes. Is there a way to upload the contents of the file directly to a VBA variable?

Comment: So you want to read the raw JSON data into a variable?

Comment: Yes there is. Please have a look at the topic [How to ask questions on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide us some code sample we can help you with. You can also have a look at the following links : [Parsing JSON in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360440/how-to-parse-json-with-vba-without-external-libraries) , [Read text file in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528694/read-parse-text-file-line-by-line-in-vba)

Comment: Yeah, exactly..

Comment: I am not asking about parsing. What I need is simply upload the JSON string from a text file and store it to in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Found it, the solution is here and it works:

[http://analystcave.com/](http://analystcave.com/vba-read-file-vba/)

```
Dim fileName As String, textData As String, textRow As String, fileNo As Integer
fileName = "C:\text.txt"
fileNo = FreeFile 'Get first free file number  

Open fileName For Input As #fileNo
Do While Not EOF(fileNo)
   Line Input #fileNo, textRow
   textData = textData & textRow
Loop
Close #fileNo
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to import from text to Excel but from JSON to Excel.
If you have to do it once in a time you'll better use some free on-line tools to convert JSON to CSV. For example [this one](http://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm).
Otherwise, if you want to build a tool to parse the JSON file into Excel I advise you to follow [this tutorial](https://codingislove.com/excel-json/):

```
Public Sub exceljson()
Dim http As Object, JSON As Object, i As Integer
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", False
http.Send
Set JSON = ParseJson(http.responseText)
i = 2
For Each Item In JSON
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("id")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = Item("name")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value = Item("username")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value = Item("email")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value = Item("address")("city")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 6).Value = Item("phone")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 7).Value = Item("website")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 8).Value = Item("company")("name")
i = i + 1
Next
MsgBox ("complete")
End Sub
```