# VBA Parse String Response From API

Tags: json, vba, excel, http

I'm getting below type of responses from an API:

> "{"success":false,"error":"Incorrect apikey"}"
>
> "{"success":true,"error":"Correct apikey"}"

In VBA, how to know if response is true or false ?

My current code is below and am getting response in **hReq.ResponseText** and it is not always fixed (more keys can be added to json). Although the part below is fixed and I have to get only if it returning true or false.

> "{"success":false

Code:

```
Dim hReq As Object
Dim strUrl As String
strUrl = "https://myWebAPI/myMethod?apikey=123456"

Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
With hReq
    .Open "GET", strUrl, False
    .Send
End With

MsgBox hReq.ResponseText
```

I know this is basic question but sorry am new to VBA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON with VBA without external libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19360440/11683)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purely based on what you have shown you can get True/False with

```
Split(Split(hReq.ResponseText, ":")(1), ",")(0)
```