# VBA getting values from a collection?

Tags: json, vba, excel, vb6

I am very new to VBA and I can not figure out how to get values from a Collection.

This is my code:

```
Dim p As Object
Set p = JSON.parse(Response.Content)

Dim links As Object
Set links = p.Item("links")
```

In the debugger for "links" I see:

[image]

I am using this library to parse json : http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html

The part I have in json is:

```
"links":[
    {
        "rel":"next",
        "href":"www.google.com"
    }
]
```

How can I get the value of "rel" here?

Comment: Not familiar, but did you try, e.g. **debug.print links(1)(1)**

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I tried Range("A4").Value = links(1)(1) but content seems to be empty.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that JSON parser either but anyway. Hopefully you don't have `On Error Resume Next` set? Have you just tried `debug.print links(0)` and `debug.print links(1)`

Comment: @MarkJ I tried Debug.Print "Hello World"
Debug.Print links(1)(1)
Debug.Print "Bye" and I am seeing the Hello World and Bye and an empty line in between them. So (1)(1) is evaluated to null I think..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget the bang operator, designed for collection access by key:

```
links(1)!rel
```

or:

```
links(1)![rel] 'When there are spaces or reserved words.
```

Answer (score 3):

I will answer my own question:

```
links(1).Item("rel")
```

worked...

Regards..

Comment: For a shortcut, `Item` is the default property for a `Dictionary`, so you can use `links(1)("rel")`.

Comment: Or even shorter with "bang" operator `links!1!rel`

Comment: what if i only have this [
    {
        "rel":"next",
        "href":"www.google.com"
    }
]

what should i do without the "links"? @TimHall

Comment: In that case you would use the raw parsed response, p, instead of links and use p(1)("rel") (or from wqw's comment, p!1!rel)

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript features of parsing JSON, on top of ScriptControl, we can create a parser in VBA which will list each and every data point inside the JSON. No matter how nested or complex the data structure is, as long as we provide a valid JSON, this parser will return a complete tree structure.

JavaScript’s Eval, getKeys and getProperty methods provide building blocks for validating and reading JSON.

Coupled with a recursive function in VBA we can iterate through all the keys (up to nth level) in a JSON string. Then using a Tree control (used in this article) or a dictionary or even on a simple worksheet, we can arrange the JSON data as required.

You can see the full VBA code [here](http://ashuvba.blogspot.com/2014/09/json-parser-in-vba-browsing-through-net.html)