# Calculate difference in values in two objects

Tags: vba, excel

I have two objects and I want to calculate the difference in values for each value.

The code is now:

```
Function CALBETA(CodeOne As String, CodeTwo As String) As Double
Dim onedata As Object
Dim Twodata As Object

Set onedata = ConnectToBloombergTwo(CodeOne)

Set Twodata = ConnectToBloombergTwo(CodeTwo)

End Function
```

They are based on another function:

```
Public Function ConnectToBloombergOne(Code As String) As Object

    Dim sUrl As String
    Dim rawJson As Dictionary
    Dim dataRequest As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Dim Json As Object
    Dim FetchedData As String

    sUrl = "http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/bulk-time-series/price/" & Code & "?timeFrame=3_YEAR"

    Set dataRequest = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

    With dataRequest
        .Open "GET", sUrl, True
        .Send
        .WaitForResponse
        FetchedData = .ResponseText
    End With

    FetchedData = Right(FetchedData, Len(FetchedData) - 1)
    FetchedData = Left(FetchedData, Len(FetchedData) - 1)

    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(FetchedData)

    Set ConnectToBloombergOne = Json.Item("price")

End Function
```

So, the idea is to compare two different stocks from Bloomberg. Therefore, I need to be able to calculate the difference in the stock price.

How can I do that?

Comment: Which particular properties of those objects do you want to find the difference in?  Also, your `CALBETA` function is invoking the `ConnectToBloombergTwo` function, but you have shown the `ConnectToBloombergOne` function.  What is the difference between the one you are calling and the one you have posted?

Comment: Want to finde the difference in stock price on the difference days: Json.Item("price")

Ahh. It's a mistake. ConnectToBloombergTwo just gets 5 years instead of 3 years.

Comment: What object does `Json.Item("price")` return? This is not a VBA question, but a JSON question, specifically whatever JSON library you are using with Excel.

Comment: Related, or possible duplicate??? [How to parse JSON with VBA without external libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19360440/380384)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA getting values from a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229563/vba-getting-values-from-a-collection)

Comment: You do can as follows: (That is VBA) 
Set pricedata = ConnectToBloomberg(Code)
    
    For Each Item In pricedata
    
    Count = Count + 1
    
    DailyReturn = Item("value") - LastPrice
        
        If LastPrice > 0 Then
        
        DailyReturnPercent = DailyReturn / LastPrice
        
    End If