# Turning API Call into Table in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an API URL that returns the following:

```
{"RESULT_CODE":1000,"RESULT_DATA":{"generic":{"sr_id":"f7376bfd00d6923fefb8c87360adb75fdcda2e99","event_time":"2018-10-22T08:26:48-04:00","event_timestamp":1540211208,"total_ship_count":45178,"total_defense_count":29,"loot_percentage":75,"spy_fail_chance":100,"activity":37,"attacker_name":"Malicious","attacker_planet_name":"Hera","attacker_planet_coordinates":"1:435:8","attacker_planet_type":"3","attacker_alliance_name":"STRYKE","attacker_alliance_tag":"STRYKE","defender_name":"Mao","defender_planet_name":"M2","defender_planet_coordinates":"1:332:5","defender_planet_type":"3","defender_alliance_name":"Noobs United","defender_alliance_tag":"N_U","failed_ships":false,"failed_defense":false,"failed_buildings":false,"failed_research":false},"details":{"resources":{"metal":24547793,"crystal":19830297,"deuterium":47334520},"buildings":[{"building_type":14,"level":6},{"building_type":41,"level":6},{"building_type":42,"level":6},{"building_type":43,"level":1}],"ships":[{"ship_type":202,"count":2018},{"ship_type":203,"count":8682},{"ship_type":204,"count":1204},{"ship_type":205,"count":2},{"ship_type":206,"count":2324},{"ship_type":207,"count":470},{"ship_type":208,"count":2},{"ship_type":209,"count":20051},{"ship_type":210,"count":101},{"ship_type":213,"count":223},{"ship_type":214,"count":80},{"ship_type":215,"count":10021}],"defense":[{"defense_type":401,"count":29}],"research":[{"research_type":106,"level":14},{"research_type":108,"level":16},{"research_type":109,"level":16},{"research_type":110,"level":16},{"research_type":111,"level":16},{"research_type":113,"level":16},{"research_type":114,"level":8},{"research_type":115,"level":14},{"research_type":117,"level":12},{"research_type":118,"level":15},{"research_type":120,"level":12},{"research_type":121,"level":11},{"research_type":122,"level":12},{"research_type":123,"level":5},{"research_type":124,"level":19},{"research_type":199,"level":1}],"repairOrder":[]}}}
```

I'm looking for how I can have the raw URL put into a cell or sheet and have this information pulled and formatted into a row in a table in another sheet using Excel.

Comment: The data you are showing is JSON - this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817545/handle-json-object-in-xmlhttp-response-in-excel-vba-code

Comment: Use this library:  https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON