# HTTP Response (GET) in VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

How to `GET` response using VBA?

This code here does not work. In `Debug.Pring()` or `MsgBox` is empty.

```
TargetURL = snURL + selectedMail
Set HTTPReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
HTTPReq.Open "GET", TargetURL, False
HTTPReq.SetCredentials snUser, snPass, 0
HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"

Debug.Print HTTPReq.responseText
```

I want to get `JSON` data.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16851758/2227085) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Optional libraries (needed, if early binding is used, in general the code will work without them):

[image]

Change the `companyName` variable:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim xmlObject As Object
    Dim companyName As String: companyName = "Google"
    Dim strUrl As String
    strUrl = "http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Lookup/json?input=" & companyName

    Set xmlObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        With xmlObject
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        .Send
    End With

    Dim response As String
    response = "{""data"":" & xmlObject.ResponseText & "}"
    Debug.Print response

End Sub
```