# How do I access a JSON variable in lowercase when VBA keeps changing to uppercase?

Tags: json, vba, excel

How do I access this `key` variable decoded from JSON? I used the example in [Excel VBA: Parsed JSON Object Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773683/excel-vba-parsed-json-object-loop).  VBA editor keeps changing the case to uppercase even when I change it to lowercase. I also tried commenting both out and uncommenting a lowercase `key` but it still changes it. I didn't think the case would matter but it is complaining and I'm not sure why, as the field clearly exists.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: what `Type` of variable is `arr`? I can't see your declarations because of the error message box.

Comment: `Set arr = jsonDecode(jsonString)`

Comment: That's the assignment of the variable. What's the `Dim arr as ...`?

Comment: There is no such line for `arr`.

Comment: VBA has problems dealing with certain properties in js objects when their names correspond to VBA "keywords" which have a different case. Best bet is to keep the decoded JSON object in the script control object, and create an "accessor" function(s) in the script control to which you can pass the property name as a string and get back the property value. There are answers in the thread you cite which address this.

Comment: Check the typename by ?typename(arr)

Answer (score 2):

I had to add `Private sc As ScriptControl` at the top of the module or else it wouldn't work. Even `Dim sc as ScriptControl` within the function wouldn't work. I also created a Javascript `get` function to retrieve values.

```
Private sc As ScriptControl
...
Function jsonDecode(jsonString As Variant)
    Set sc = New ScriptControl
    sc.Language = "JScript"
    sc.AddCode "Object.prototype.get=function( i ) { return this[i]; };"
    Set jsonDecode = sc.Eval("(" + jsonString + ")")
End Function

...

Set arr = jsonDecode(objHTTP.ResponseText)
Debug.Print arr.get("key")
```