# In Excel VBA on Windows, how to loop through a JSON array parsed?

Tags: json, excel, vba

answering my own question here.
I have done some work with JSON in Excel VBA and lots of findings to post which I will do so in Q & A format
https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

So elsewhere on stackoverflow one can see questions about parsing JSON in VBA but they seem to miss a trick or two.

To begin with, I resile from using custom JSON parsing libraries and instead use the ScriptControl's Eval method as the basis of all my JSON code.
And also we express a preference from native Microsoft solutions.

Here is a prior question [In Excel VBA on Windows, how to mitigate issue of dot syntax traversal of parsed JSON broken by IDE's capitalisation behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710995/in-excel-vba-on-windows-how-to-mitigate-issue-of-dot-syntax-traversal-of-parsed) upon which this question builds.  It shows how using VBA.CallByName is more robust
than using the dot syntax to traverse a parsed JSON object.

In this question it is asked how to traverse a parsed JSON array.  Firstly here is a miniscript approach
with a hat tip to ozmike  https://stackoverflow.com/users/334106/ozmike

```
'Tools->References->
'Microsoft Script Control 1.0;  {0E59F1D2-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}; C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msscript.ocx

Private Sub TestJSONParsingArrayWithMiniScript()
    'Hat tip to ozmike  https://stackoverflow.com/users/334106/ozmike
    'Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773683/excel-vba-parsed-json-object-loop#19359035
    Dim oScriptEngine As ScriptControl
    Set oScriptEngine = New ScriptControl
    oScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"
    oScriptEngine.AddCode "Object.prototype.myitem=function( i ) { return this[i] } ; "
    
    Dim sJsonString As String
    sJsonString = "[ 1234, 2345 ]"
    
    Dim objJSON As Object
    Set objJSON = oScriptEngine.Eval("(" + sJsonString + ")")
    
    Debug.Assert objJSON.myitem(0) = 1234
    Debug.Assert objJSON.myitem(1) = 2345
    

End Sub
```

But believe it or not VBA.CallByName can be used natively not just to get an array's length but also access elements.  See answer.

This is Question 2 of series of 5.  Here is the full series

Q1 [In Excel VBA on Windows, how to mitigate issue of dot syntax traversal of parsed JSON broken by IDE's capitalisation behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710995/in-excel-vba-on-windows-how-to-mitigate-issue-of-dot-syntax-traversal-of-parsed)

Q2 [In Excel VBA on Windows, how to loop through a JSON array parsed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711034/in-excel-vba-on-windows-how-to-loop-through-a-json-array-parsed)

Q3 [In Excel VBA on Windows, how to get stringified JSON respresentation instead of “[object Object]” for parsed JSON variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711073/in-excel-vba-on-windows-how-to-get-stringified-json-respresentation-instead-of)

Q4 [In Windows Excel VBA,how to get JSON keys to pre-empt “Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711100/in-windows-excel-vba-how-to-get-json-keys-to-pre-empt-run-time-error-438-obj)

Q5 [In Excel VBA on Windows, for parsed JSON variables what is this JScriptTypeInfo anyway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711112/in-excel-vba-on-windows-for-parsed-json-variables-what-is-this-jscripttypeinfo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So VBA.CallByName also accesses elements in an array as well as find the array's length

```
'Tools->References->
'Microsoft Script Control 1.0;  {0E59F1D2-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}; C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msscript.ocx

Private Sub TestJSONParsingArrayWithCallByName()

    Dim oScriptEngine As ScriptControl
    Set oScriptEngine = New ScriptControl
    oScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"

    Dim sJsonString As String
    sJsonString = "[ 1234, 2345 ]"

    Dim objJSON As Object
    Set objJSON = oScriptEngine.Eval("(" + sJsonString + ")")

    '* Using VBA.CallByName we get the length of the array

    Dim lLength As Long
    lLength = VBA.CallByName(objJSON, "length", VbGet)

    Debug.Assert lLength = 2

    '* Believe or not one uses "0","1",.... with callbyname to get an element
    Debug.Assert VBA.CallByName(objJSON, "0", VbGet) = 1234
    Debug.Assert VBA.CallByName(objJSON, "1", VbGet) = 2345


End Sub
```