# Trouble parsing JSON with vba

Tags: json, vba, excel, parsing

I can get what *appears* to be a valid JSON string from a web query, however, I cannot set items correctly for the life of me.  Need to confirm that I'm not losing my mind...

```
'Call for available reports

Dim URLReporta As String
Dim JSONa As Object
Dim var As Object  
Set myrequesta = CreateObject("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1")
URLReporta = ("https://secure.saashr.com:443/ta/rest/v1/reports?type=Saved&company%3shortname=" & Company)
myrequesta.Open "GET", URLReporta, False
myrequesta.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
myrequesta.setRequestHeader "Authentication", "Bearer " & Token
myrequesta.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
myrequesta.Send
Set JSONa = JsonConverter.ParseJson(myrequesta.responseText)
Set var = JSONa("SavedName")
Debug.Print var.Count
```

I get an error on the line `Set var = JSONa("SavedName")`:

> run-time error '424': object required

`myrequesta.responseText` value is as follows:

> {"reports":[{"SavedName":"This Year","SettingId":18959322},{"SavedName":"Time Off Requests","SettingId":18960210},{"SavedName":"Calc Hours Summary","SettingId":18960209},{"SavedName":"roster","SettingId":18960211},{"SavedName":"E/D/T","SettingId":18823042},{"SavedName":"TestZDR","SettingId":18957188}]}

Comment: *I cannot set items correctly*...set what items? What are your errors? What do you want to parse? What is desired output? In short, what is your question?

Comment: It looks like you're using https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas ?

Comment: updated the code above, I get run-time error '424': object required on line "Set var = JSONa("SavedName")

Comment: If your JSON string could be converted to XML structure, you will be able to use [XPath expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) like `//property[@name = "SavedName"]` to get a collection of all nodes representing `SavedName` properties.

Comment: Did you know ScriptControl.Eval("("+ json + ")" ) will parse object and one can use CallByName to access elements.  See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711034/in-excel-vba-on-windows-how-to-loop-through-a-json-array-parsed?noredirect=1&lq=1#answer-37711035

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure returned by `JsonConverter.ParseJson` function doesn't work such way. For your particular JSON it contains 3 levels:
Root-level object has only one property `reports`, which contains second-level array, which in turn contains 6 third-level objects, having properties `SavedName` and `SettingId`. You are trying to get third-level's object property value from root-level object.

First you need to get second-level array, then loop through it's elements, containing objects, and retrieve the `SavedName` properties' values of that objects. Here is the example:

```
'Call for available reports

Dim URLReporta As String
Dim JSONa As Object
Dim var As Object
Dim rep As Variant
Set myrequesta = CreateObject("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1")
URLReporta = ("https://secure.saashr.com:443/ta/rest/v1/reports?type=Saved&company%3shortname=" & Company)
myrequesta.Open "GET", URLReporta, False
myrequesta.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
myrequesta.setRequestHeader "Authentication", "Bearer " & Token
myrequesta.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
myrequesta.Send
Set JSONa = JsonConverter.ParseJson(myrequesta.responseText) ' root level object
Set var = JSONa("reports") ' second level array
For Each rep In var ' third level objects
    Debug.Print rep("SavedName") ' property "SavedName" value of current third level object
Next
```

Here is the output:

[image: immediate]

If you want just to get the number of reports, then get the array and the number of elements in it:

```
Debug.Print JSONa("reports").Count
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick in unwinding how that parser is intended to work.

Comment: Did you know ScriptControl.Eval("("+ json + ")" ) will parse object and one can use CallByName to access elements.  See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711034/in-excel-vba-on-windows-how-to-loop-through-a-json-array-parsed?noredirect=1&lq=1#answer-37711035

Comment: @SMeaden that approach makes the system vulnerable in some cases (malicious code from the web query may be executed), take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30494373/2165759), especially update part.

Answer (score 1):

JSON objects can be thought of as a collection of dictionaries. So you have to walk through the inner values such as *SavedName* to retrieve whole dictionary objects (all *SavedName* values) or specific string values at indexed locations (one *SavedName* value):

```
Public Sub GetJSONRequest()
    Dim jsonStr As String

    jsonStr = "{" _
         & "     ""reports"": [{" _
         & "         ""SavedName"": ""This Year""," _
         & "         ""SettingId"": 18959322" _
         & "     }, {" _
         & "         ""SavedName"": ""Time Off Requests""," _
         & "         ""SettingId"": 18960210" _
         & "     }, {" _
         & "         ""SavedName"": ""Calc Hours Summary""," _
         & "         ""SettingId"": 18960209" _
         & "     }, {" _
         & "         ""SavedName"": ""roster""," _
         & "         ""SettingId"": 18960211" _
         & "     }, {" _
         & "         ""SavedName"": ""E/D/T""," _
         & "         ""SettingId"": 18823042" _
         & "     }, {" _
         & "         ""SavedName"": ""TestZDR""," _
         & "         ""SettingId"": 18957188" _
         & "  }]" _
         & "  }"

    Dim JSONa As Object, element As Object, e As Variant, i As Variant, var As Variant

    Set JSONa = ParseJson(jsonStr)

    ' DICTIONARY OBJECT
    Set element = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set element = JSONa("reports")

    ' OUTER DICTIONARY
    For Each e In element
        ' INNER COLLECTION OF DICTIONARIES
        For Each i In e
            Debug.Print i & " " & e(i)
        Next i
    Next e            

    ' STRING VALUE OF FIRST SAVEDNAME VALUE
    var = JSONa("reports")(1)("SavedName")
    Debug.Print var

    Set element = Nothing
    Set JSONa = Nothing
End Sub
```

Output

```
SavedName This Year
SettingId 18959322
SavedName Time Off Requests
SettingId 18960210
SavedName Calc Hours Summary
SettingId 18960209
SavedName roster
SettingId 18960211
SavedName E/D/T
SettingId 18823042
SavedName TestZDR
SettingId 18957188
This Year
```