# Error when parse JSON through VBA-JSON library

Tags: json, excel, vba, runtime-error, type-mismatch

I'm receiving a

> runtime error 13 Type mismatch

at the line `Cells(i,1).value=item("fp")`.

Dont know why the item can't be selected. As you can observe the json file it has "fp" value as "042018"

```
Sub Jsonread()
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim JsonTS As TextStream
Dim jsonText As String
Dim jsonObject As Object
Dim item As variant

Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Abd\retoffline_others.json", ForReading)
jsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
JsonTS.Close

Dim i As Long

Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)

i = 3

For Each item In jsonObject
    Cells(i, 1) = item("fp")
    Cells(i, 2) = item("sply_ty")
    i = i + 1
Next

End Sub
```

An extract of the json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "Flip",
  "fp": "042018",
  "filing_typ": "M",
  "gt": 0,
  "cur_gt": 0,
  "b2cs": [
    {
      "csamt": 0,
      "sply_ty": "INTRA"
    },
```

Comment: Probably `jsonObject` is `Nothing` check before using it in the loop: `If jsonObject Is Nothing Then MsgBox "It is Nothing":Exit Sub` • If it is nothing that means your parsing went wrong or your file wasn't read proberly. Check the value of `jsonText` too.

Comment: PEH, I have checked the values of both JsonObject and JsonText. Both of them contains value

Comment: Try to  declare `item As Variant` instead of an `Object`. But actually I think it should work.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I am getting type mismatch error. I have edited the question accordingly. Please help

Comment: what do you get with TypeName(item)     ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble parsing JSON with vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902688/trouble-parsing-json-with-vba)

Comment: @QHarr I get String

Comment: yeah... and your syntax is expecting a dictionary.....looks like @peh may have resolved so try running that....

Answer (score 0):

First of all the JSON that you showed is not valid. It ends with a `,` but instead of the comma it must be a `]}` to make it a valid JSON example:

```
{
    "name": "Flip",
    "fp": "042018",
    "filing_typ": "M",
    "gt": 0,
    "cur_gt": 0,
    "b2cs": [{
        "csamt": 0,
        "sply_ty": "INTRA"
    }]
}
```

*<sup>Code 1: Valid JSON example that can be used with the code below.</sup>*

Make sure you put only valid JSON data into the parser. If you give invalid data the parser will hang up or in best case throw an error.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Jsonread()
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim JsonTS As TextStream
    Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Abd\retoffline_others.json", ForReading)

    Dim jsonText As String
    jsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
    JsonTS.Close

    Dim jsonObject As Object
    Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)

    Debug.Print jsonObject("fp")
    Debug.Print jsonObject("b2cs")(1)("sply_ty")
End Sub
```

*<sup>Code 2: VBA code to parse the JSON from code 1.</sup>*

**Explanation:**

`jsonObject("b2cs")` represents the following:

```
"b2cs": [{
    "csamt": 0,
    "sply_ty": "INTRA"
}]
```

then `jsonObject("b2cs")(1)` will get the first item in the `[]` brackets which represents the following:

```
{
    "csamt": 0,
    "sply_ty": "INTRA"
}
```

and finally `jsonObject("b2cs")(1)("sply_ty")` is the item you were looking for, and it will result in:

```
042018
INTRA
```