# Converting json with arrays to an excel macro

Tags: json, excel, vba, parsing

I am new to Macro creation. I have a json like below with one master key and multiple sub values..

```
{"uuid":"9BFD4668B3EE5F09E053512C48A5B19E","code":"PROCDHD","name":"PROD Holdings","customerSegment":"BC","marketGroup":"BC","corporatePartnerType":"USUAL CUST","divisions":[{"uuid":"9BFD4669D5B45F09E053512C48A5B19E","code":"PRADNTCRP","name":"Kim International","shortName":"PRAD International","remarks":"A Luxury Pearls & Jewelry Company","businessPartners":[{"uuid":"9BFD466743A85F09E053512C48A5B19E","AT1Code":"CTOII011","name":"TIMI INTERNATIONAL CORPORATION","address":{"uuid":"9BFD4659FC7A5F09E053512C48A5B19E","addressLine1":"11000 MONARCHI ST","city":"GARDEN CLOVE","zip":"94221","countryCode":"IN"}}]},{"uuid":"9BFD4669AF8F5F09E053512C48A5B19E","code":"VRISHKA","name":"Vrisksha Holdings","shortName":"Vrshco Holdings","remarks":"Sells Packaging, jewells For jewellery Industry","businessPartners":[{"uuid":"9EE6E38AE8125405E053512C48A5498C","AT1Code":"CSKUS008","name":"Vriskha HOLDINGS","address":{"uuid":"9ED8CA9DC4D670AAE053522C48A559BF","addressLine1":"11958 MONARCHI STREET","city":"GARDEN CLOVE","zip":"94221","countryCode":"IN"}}]}]}
```

`9BFD4668B3EE5F09E053512C48A5B19E` - Master key,

`9BFD4669D5B45F09E053512C48A5B19E, 9BFD4669AF8F5F09E053512C48A5B19E` - sub key rows (should be displayed as 2 rows in excel for one key)

I managed to get the first sub key alone, but second key is not being displayed,

my code:

```
Public Sub exceljson_Type1()
    Dim https As Object, Json As Object, i As Integer
    Dim Item As Variant
    Set https = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    https.Open "GET", "file:///C:/Users/Desktop/Tasks/JSON/sample.json", False
    https.Send
    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(https.responseText)
    i = 3
    For Each Item In Json
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("uuid")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = Item("code")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value = Item("customerSegment")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value = Item("marketGroup")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value = Item("corporatePartnerType")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 6).Value = Item("divisions")("uuid")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 7).Value = Item("divisions")("name")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 8).Value = Item("divisions")("name")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 9).Value = Item("divisions")("shortName")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 10).Value = Item("divisions")("remarks")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 11).Value = Item("divisions")("businessPartners")("uuid")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 12).Value = Item("divisions")("businessPartners")("cw1Code")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 13).Value = Item("divisions")("businessPartners")("name")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 14).Value = Item("divisions")("businessPartners")("address")("uuid")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 15).Value = Item("divisions")("businessPartners")("address")("addressLine1")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 16).Value = Item("divisions")("businessPartners")("address")("city")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 17).Value = Item("divisions")("businessPartners")("address")("zip")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 18).Value = Item("divisions")("businessPartners")("address")("countryCode")
    i = i + 1
    Next
    MsgBox ("complete")
End Sub
```

Requsting your help to change the code such that i will get all the entries associated with the main key into different sub rows.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37902688/2398630)

Comment: You want to loop json("divisions") collection to get both levels. Bear in mind they both are nested.

Comment: @QHarr: I am still waiting for your  help..

Comment: Have you tried using a json viewer to inspect the structure and re-write your initial loop to be over json("divisions")