# Extracting data in json format using vba

Tags: json, vba, extract

I am currently using below mentioned code for data extraction from web,code is extracting data from web without any issue,now i want extract same data in json format.My code is given below.My page usrl is given below
https://www.amazon.com/s?crid=AQO8JFH64H82&i=merchant-items&k=socks&me=A29M0OOY4LPNOT&qid=1635324852&ref=glow_cls&refresh=1&sprefix=socks%2Caps%2C315&low-price=0.1&high-price=5

```
Set Ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Ie.Visible = True
Ie.navigate "https://www.amazon.com/s?crid=AQO8JFH64H82&i=merchant-items&k=socks&me=A29M0OOY4LPNOT&qid=1635324852&ref=glow_cls&refresh=1&sprefix=socks%2Caps%2C315&low-price=0.1&high-price=5"
Set html = Ie.Document
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim Fileout As Object
Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Data\test" & Format(Now(), "_yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm") & ".txt", True, True)
If html1 Like "*a-section a-spacing-small a-spacing-top-small*" Then
If html1 Like "*a-pagination*" Then
pagen = html.getElementsByClassName("a-section a-spacing-small a-spacing-top-small")(0).innerText
pagen = Replace(pagen, "'", "")
endpage = html.getElementsByClassName("a-pagination")(0).innerText
fileout.write endpage
```

Answer (score 0):

First, welcome to SO.

You have to decide if you want to parse json for yourself, or want to use one of several available libraries:

1. For use libraries, I recommend first, go to [THE SOURCE](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) of Json parsers.

After, please go to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2782393/2752308); it is a must, and it is as easy as that:

```
Dim p As Object
Set p = JSON.parse(strFormattedJSON)
```

But, for parse it, you will need to understand inner structure, as most JSON libraries parse JSON objects to Arrays or Dictionaries, nested inside each other; maybe you have to access them like that:

```
Debug.Print p.Item("a-pagination")(0)
```

2. For parse youself, [here is a very good implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21664962/2752308).
   [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38304247/2752308) also is good and leads [to this one, the better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711073/in-excel-vba-on-windows-how-to-get-stringified-json-respresentation-instead-of).

PS: Our search engine is very good ;)

Comment: why you are using p.Item(a-pagination")(0) as i am using class name in code?

Comment: @Satti22, in this solution, after you parse an object to JSON, it will get into Arrays or Dictionaries, using names of properties/elements as keys. I did not implemented it because I'm out of VBA editor in a tablet; that is why I wrote _maybe you have_

Comment: Still facing following error,by reference argument type mismatch on following line.Set p = JSON.parse(strFormattedJSON).If possible please update complete solution.

Comment: @Satti22 My answer was only to provide clues and tell that there are two basic ways. In next 24h I'll have access to a VBA editor and will try one of these solutions, and will edit it