# Retrieving one value from JSON works, but identical approach on the other value fails

Tags: json, vba, autocorrect

The source .json file is as simple as this:

```
{
  "rates": {
    "EURUSD": {
      "rate": 1.112656,
      "timestamp": 1559200864
    }
  },
  "code": 200
}
```

I can return the `"timestamp"` value, but using the identical approach I cannot return the `"rate"` value.

This runs with no problems:

```
Sub current_eur_usd()

  Dim scriptControl As Object
  Set scriptControl = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
  scriptControl.Language = "JScript"
  Dim oJSON As Object

  With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=EURUSD", False
    .send
    Set oJSON = scriptControl.Eval("(" + .responsetext + ")")
    .abort
  End With
  MsgBox oJSON.rates.EURUSD.timestamp   '<<< 'timestamp' works, 'rate' fails

  Set oJSON = Nothing
  Set scriptControl = Nothing
End Sub
```

But when I try to replace `timestamp` with `rate`, I get the error message highlighting the `MsgBox` line.

> Run-time error '438':
>   Object doesn't support this property or method

I think the problem lies in VBA automatically capitalizing `rate`.

```
MsgBox oJSON.rates.EURUSD.rate
```

auto-transforms into

```
MsgBox oJSON.rates.EURUSD.Rate
```

How can I return the `"rate"` value?

Comment: Check out [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710995/in-excel-vba-on-windows-how-to-mitigate-issue-of-dot-syntax-traversal-of-parsed]

Comment: @Gareth - huge thanks! I have explored all the options mentioned and referenced in this question and was able to find the best suiting solution, i.e. `CallByName` function.

Comment: Afterall, the [solution by Slai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56374289/#56378643) looks better to my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround could be evaluating it :

```
MsgBox scriptControl.Eval("(" + .responsetext + ").rates.EURUSD.rate")
```

The object can also be assigned to JS variable (not tested) :

```
Set EURUSD = scriptControl.Eval("EURUSD = (" + .responsetext + ").rates.EURUSD")
Debug.Print scriptControl.Eval("EURUSD.rate")
Debug.Print EURUSD.timestamp
```

Comment: In order for this to work, I had to put it inside the `With` block, but I do like the readability of this solution. As [QHarr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6241235/qharr) explained, `scriptControl` will only work on 32 bit Office, but this is not an issue for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I use [this](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) tool to parse the JSON response like this:

```
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=EURUSD", False
    .send
    Set oJSON = ParseJson(.responseText)
    .abort
End With
```

Try that way, you can loop later to check all the items inside the `oJSON` like this:
`For Each Item in oJSON.Items` and see if rates are there.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I think on a bigger project this would be the way to go. However, if possible, I tend to avoid external tools and references.

Answer (score 1):

Script control will work for 32 bit rather than 64 bit.

The following have the advantage is will work on 32 and 64 bit machines

---

**Using json parser:**

I would also use jsonconverter.bas (add then add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime) and as it returns a dictionary inside you can test for the `rate` key

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetRate()
    Dim json As Object, pairs As String
    pairs = "EURUSD"
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=" & pairs, False
        .send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
        If json("rates")(pairs).Exists("rate") Then
            Debug.Print json("rates")(pairs)("rate")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Using regex:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetQuoteValue()
    Dim json As Object, pairs As String, s As String, re As Object
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    pairs = "EURUSD"
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=" & pairs, False
        .send
        s = .responseText
        Debug.Print GetValue(re, s, """rate"":(\d+\.\d+)")
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetValue(ByVal re As Object, inputString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As String
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .pattern = pattern
        If .Test(inputString) Then
            GetValue = .Execute(inputString)(0).SubMatches(0)
        Else
            GetValue = "Not found"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

---

**Using string splitting:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetQuoteValue()
    Dim json As Object, pairs As String, s As String, p As String

    pairs = "EURUSD"
    p = """rate"":"
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=" & pairs, False
        .send
        s = .responseText
        If InStr(s, p) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print Split(Split(s, p)(1), ",")(0)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I think on a bigger project this would be the way to go. However, if possible, I tend to avoid external tools and references.

Comment: Added a regex answer.

Answer (score 0):

A great solution for smaller projects is employing [`CallByName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/callbyname-function) function. Not a pretty one, but can do the job in a single line, and it's not requiring to import external files to the project or add references.

```
Sub current_eur_usd()

  Dim scriptControl As Object
  Set scriptControl = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
  scriptControl.Language = "JScript"
  Dim oJSON As Object

  With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=EURUSD", False
    .send
    Set oJSON = scriptControl.Eval("(" + .responsetext + ")")
    .abort
  End With
  MsgBox VBA.CallByName(VBA.CallByName(VBA.CallByName(oJSON, "rates", VbGet), "EURUSD", VbGet), "rate", VbGet)

  Set oJSON = Nothing
  Set scriptControl = Nothing
End Sub
```