# Using API Parsing JSON object in Excel VBA

Tags: json, vba, excel

I have an issue with understanding [Excel VBA: Parsed JSON Object Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773683/excel-vba-parsed-json-object-loop).

I need a solution on the below code:

```
Sub getPricesOnReport()

 Dim url As String: url = "http://statistics.mla.com.au/ReportApi/RunReport?ReportGuid=70587516-e17a-4065-a8aa-e3fe4c512159&FromDate=13%2F03%2F2017&ToDate=18%2F03%2F2017"
 Dim httpRequest As Object: Set httpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHttp")
 Dim httpResponse As Object
 Dim scriptControl As Object: Set scriptControl = createObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
 Dim XDOM As ListObject

scriptControl.Language = "JScript"

httpRequest.Open "GET", url, False
httpRequest.send

Set httpResponse = scriptControl.eval("(" + httpRequest.responseText + ")")

With Sheets("MLA")

If httpResponse.ResponseStatus <> "OK" Then
    MsgBox "Error in Response"
Else
Cells(3, 2).Value = httpResponse.ResponseDate
Cells(3, 3).Value = httpResponse.ResponseHeader
Cells(3, 4).Value = httpResponse.ResponseStatus
Cells(3, 5).Value = httpResponse.ResponseDisclaimer
'Cells(4, 2).Value = httpResponse.returnValue ' 
End If  
End With
End Sub
```

I am getting an error for the code

```
Cells(4, 2).Value = httpResponse.returnValue
```

though the object is available.

PFB image:

[image: Json object]

How do i modify the code to access the data?

Comment: What is the error description?

Comment: Capital `R` in `ReturnValue`?

Comment: The Excel in my computer is behaving irrationally it is converting the Capital R into small r, what could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

## **In this case, Capitalization matters!**

**ReturnValue** needs to be capitalized properly.

It may be defaulting to a "small r" when you type `ReturnValue` if there are other references to `returnValue`.  (VBA is trying to be helpful by correcting the word to how you typed it before!)

### In the VBA Editor:

- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
- Enter `ReturnValue` for *both* `Find What` and `Replace With`.
- Make sure `Current Project` is selected, and that **`Match Case` is unchecked**.
- Click `Replace All`

Every occurrence of the word will be changed to the correct capitalization.

[image]