# Loop through child objects in json in VBA Macro

Tags: json, excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through each item in the json file and get only few property values and put them in excel cells. 
Json file example-

```
{
  "123": {
     "fname":"Testing",
     "lname":"Lname",
     "age":"21",
     "email":"testing.lname@yopmail.com"
     },
  "234": {
     "fname":"...",
     "lname":"....",..........
```

it goes on like that.

I tried JsonConvertor.ParseJSon(content) and tried using MSScriptControl as well. With JsonConvert i was able to get only the first item value which is "123","234",.. but not their child. With MSScriptControl i was able to get the 123 as one object and 234 as another object and so on.. But using For Each item as in items statement throws error.

I also tried the code from the below thread,
[Excel VBA: Parsed JSON Object Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773683/excel-vba-parsed-json-object-loop/7300963)

Still its showing "Object doesn't support this property or method" when i try to loop through the object which has the key and value.

```
Sub ImportJSON()
Dim Movie As Object
Dim scriptControl As Object
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
    .Title = " Select a json file"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False

    If .Show() Then
        Filename = .SelectedItems(1)

        Dim content As String
        Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile
        Open Filename For Input As #iFile
        content = Input(LOF(iFile), iFile)

'            Set scriptControl = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
'            scriptControl.Language = "JScript"
'            Set Movie = scriptControl.Eval("(" + content + ")")
'
'            For Each mov In Movie.Keys
'                For Each item In mov
'                Debug.Print mov("email")
'                Next
'            Next
'
'            MsgBox Movie.Email
'            'Debug.Print Movie.Email


        'Parse JSON String
        Dim items As Object
        Set items = JsonConverter.ParseJson(content)
        i = 1
        For Each item In items
            For Each Child In item
                Cells(i, 1) = item("email")
            Next Child
        Next item
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

I'm expecting to loop through each set of items (123,234,...) and get only few common fields like fname, lname and email. But i get error "object doesn't support this property or method"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
    Dim items As Object, itm, child
    Set items = JsonConverter.ParseJson(content)
    i = 1
    'loop over the "items" dictionary keys
    For Each itm In items
        Set child = items(itm) '<< get a reference to the nested dictionary
        Cells(i, 1) = itm
        Cells(i, 2) = child("email")
        Cells(i, 3) = child("age")
        'etc
    Next ite
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you Tim. And i really forgot it is a object and i need to assign it to a object variable using Set. How dumb i'm.. Thanks anyways :)