# JSON import to Excel

Tags: json, excel, api, google-docs

Is it possible to script JSON calls in a macro?

I want to get a JSON string through an API connection. It looks like the problem is Excel expects the parameters to be passed in the HTML-string, but JSON passes parameters in the HTML body. Any ideas?

Comment: Options for consuming json in VB/VBA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782076/is-there-a-json-parser-for-vb6-vba. How are you calling the API in your VBA? xmlHTTP?

Comment: JSON is just a plain-text markup for variable arrays.  There isn't anything special about JSON.  It sounds like Excel is passing the information through a _GET request (.com?variable=anwser).  You could look at modifying the HTML server code to read the variables from a GET request (in PHP, simply $variable = $_GET['variable'];).

Answer (score 42):

Since this is VBA, I'd use COM to call `xmlhttprequest` but use it in synchronous manner as not to upset VBA’s single threaded execution environment, A sample class that illustrates a `post` and `get` request in this manner follows:

```vb
'BEGIN CLASS syncWebRequest

Private Const REQUEST_COMPLETE = 4

Private m_xmlhttp As Object
Private m_response As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_xmlhttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_xmlhttp = Nothing
End Sub


Property Get Response() As String
    Response = m_response
End Property

Property Get Status() As Long
    Status = m_xmlhttp.Status
End Property

Public Sub AjaxPost(Url As String, Optional postData As String = "")
    m_xmlhttp.Open "POST", Url, False
    m_xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    m_xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-length", Len(postData)
    m_xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Connection", "close"
    m_xmlhttp.send (postData)
    If m_xmlhttp.readyState = REQUEST_COMPLETE Then
        m_response = m_xmlhttp.responseText
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub AjaxGet(Url As String)
    m_xmlhttp.Open "GET", Url, False
    m_xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Connection", "close"
    m_xmlhttp.send
    If m_xmlhttp.readyState = REQUEST_COMPLETE Then
        m_response = m_xmlhttp.responseText
    End If
End Sub

'END CLASS syncWebRequest
```

So now you can call the above to return you the server's response:

```
Dim request As New syncWebRequest
request.ajaxGet "http://localhost/ClientDB/AllClients?format=json" 
Dim json as string 
json = request.Response
```

The problem here is we want to be able to read the data returned from the server in some way, more so than manipulating the JSON string directly. What's worked for me is using the [VBA-JSON](http://code.google.com/p/vba-json/) (google code export [here](https://github.com/orialmog/vba-json/)) COM type `Collection` to handle JSON arrays and `Dictionary` to handle members and their declarations, with a parser factory method `Parse` that basically makes creating these collections of dictionaries much simpler.

So now we can parse the JSON:

```
[{"Name":"test name","Surname":"test surname","Address":{"Street":"test street","Suburb":"test suburb","City":"test city"}}]
```

into something like the following:

```
Set clients = parser.parse(request.Response)
For Each client In clients
    name = client("Name")
    surname = client("Surname")
    street = client("Address")("Street")
    suburb = client("Address")("Suburb")
    city = client("Address")("City")
Next
```

That's nice but what about stuff like being able to edit and post back the data? Well there's also a method `toString` to create a JSON string from the above [Collection/Dictionary] JSON data, assuming the server accepts JSON back.

Comment: I can't believe this hasn't been accepted / voted before now.  You solved my problem perfectly - thank you!

Comment: using `theData("Name")` isn't working for me - any idea why? :c I added JSONLib as a class, used `Dim parser As New JSONLib` (not in your code originally). Then I used `Dim theData` and `Set theData = parser.parse(request.Response)`. Are you dimming clients as a collection?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot! Got confused between `client` and `clients`. To help anyone else out in the future - copy the library code into a Class Module (right click - Insert -> Class Module). Name it JSONLib - copy the code from the jsonlib module in OP's code in there. `Dim parser As New JSONLib` Then `Set theData = parser.parse(request.Response)` Make sure you are using `For Each key in theData key("Name")` - I was trying to pull the values from `theData("Name")` and was super confused.

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a .NET Excel-Addin for this. It's a generic Excel JSON client that streams any JSON object straight into Excel via http.

Docs and installation instructions can be found here:
http://excel-requests.pathio.com/en/master/

And here's the GitHub link:
https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/excel-requests

Comment: the example times out and there are no installation instructions.

Comment: it does work though. Note if you get error and excel opens with funny chars all over you probably installed 64-bit when you meant 32-bit.

Comment: ah ok - the whole thing is not in the best state though; when I get some time, I'll clean it up (and include a powershell script that automatically picks 32/64 bit depending on your Excel) - feel free to drop me an email bjoern.stiel (at) pathio (dot) com and I'll keep you posted

Comment: It's taken a bit longer but here's the new Addin (under the new name Excel Requests): http://excel-requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. Download the powershell script and execute to install the correct version.