# Put a VBA Class into Action

Tags: vba, excel

My question relates to the question: [JSON import to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044423/json-import-to-excel?answertab=oldest)

I understand most of what this post is saying, but I don't understand how to put it together in an excel module or class module. Would someone please help me to understand how I can assemble this beast to achieve my purpose?

EDIT 29-5-14 @ 7.44AM -

Here is the try which I have done so far:

**Installed as ClassModule syncWebRequest**

```
'BEGIN CLASS syncWebRequest

Private Const REQUEST_COMPLETE = 4

Private m_xmlhttp As Object
Private m_response As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_xmlhttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_xmlhttp = Nothing
End Sub


Property Get Response() As String
    Response = m_response
End Property

Property Get Status() As Long
    Status = m_xmlhttp.Status
End Property

Public Sub AjaxPost(Url As String, Optional postData As String = "")
    m_xmlhttp.Open "POST", Url, False
    m_xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    m_xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-length", Len(postData)
    m_xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Connection", "close"
    m_xmlhttp.send (postData)
    If m_xmlhttp.readyState = REQUEST_COMPLETE Then
        m_response = m_xmlhttp.responseText
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub AjaxGet(Url As String)
    m_xmlhttp.Open "GET", Url, False
    m_xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Connection", "close"
    m_xmlhttp.send
    If m_xmlhttp.readyState = REQUEST_COMPLETE Then
        m_response = m_xmlhttp.responseText
    End If
End Sub

'END CLASS syncWebRequest
```

**Installed as Module Test**

```
Sub Test()
    Dim request As New syncWebRequest
    request.AjaxGet "http://crimson/php/SiteEnquiryAjax.php?action=aisFeed&brandCode=s&siteID=0625?format=json"
    Dim json As String
    json = request.Response
End Sub
```

I'm used to working with normal modules, but have not had to work with a class module before. I am therefore trying to understand this and translate it to meet my requirements, but forgive me if I am making it a chunkier job than one would expect.

I'm trying to query data from a local webservice that returns JSON. The webservice returns data based on an ID (e.g. 0656) in the form of:

```
{"total":"1","results":[{"brandName":"ABC","brandingName":"Cat","siteCategory":"Production","siteName":"Scrubbed","streetAddress":"ABC RD, SUBURB, VIC 3000","siteState":"VIC","phoneNumber":"03 0909 0909","mobileNumber":"0409 090 909","faxNumber":"03 9090 9090","applicationServer":"CAT0656ABC001","dateOpened":"1979-08-21","siteNotice":"","lastContact":"2014-05-19 04:36:31",}]}
```

My objective is to put this in a spreadsheet where the user can enter the sites ID (e.g. 0656) and the spreadsheet will then be able to pull and respond with data as exampled above.

EDIT 29-5-14 @ 8.42AM -

**Updated Module Test** - my intention here was to test the parser exampled in the linked question, however when I now run the macro I receive an error. My understanding is that this may be the missing piece of what I'm trying to achieve. I have now commented out the added items to stop error occurring.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim request As New syncWebRequest
    request.AjaxGet "http://crimson/php/SiteEnquiryAjax.php?action=aisFeed&brandCode=s&siteID=0625"
    Dim json As String
    json = request.Response

    'Set clients = parser.Parse(request.Response)
    'For Each client In clients
    'Name = client("Name")
    'State = client("siteState")
    'street = client("Address")("Street")
    'suburb = client("Address")("Suburb")
    'city = client("Address")("City")
    'Next
End Sub
```

EDIT 29-5-14 @ 9.40AM -

To put it another way... I want to turn this: **HTTP Result of "url/SiteEnquiryAjax.php?action=aisFeed&brandCode=s&siteID=0656"**

```
{"total":"1","results":[{"brandName":"ABC","brandingName":"Cat","siteCategory":"Production","siteName":"Scrubbed","streetAddress":"ABC RD, SUBURB, VIC 3000","siteState":"VIC","phoneNumber":"03 0909 0909","mobileNumber":"0409 090 909","faxNumber":"03 9090 9090","applicationServer":"CAT0656ABC001","dateOpened":"1979-08-21","siteNotice":"","lastContact":"2014-05-19 04:36:31",}]}
```

Into this: **Excel Output**

[image: Excel Output]

Comment: Please post your tries with question

Comment: What are you trying to do specifically? Are you trying to consume a webservice? Do you have a local JSON file you are trying to import? The way this question reads now it sounds like "How do I copy and paste other people's code?"

Comment: I have added my objectives in the above.

Comment: OK, your updates look good.  Now, what is not working for you, or, what parts don't you understand?

Comment: What part I don't understand is how to convert all of this to output. I think I have the code set up as it should be, but now I don't know how I:

a) return JSON for site ID specific to user input
b) print the JSON in the spreadsheet

Comment: Nobody has the help for me?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact details of the error you are receiving, I've used vba-json before and I think you're not instantiating the parser before using it:

```
Dim parser As New JSONLib
Set clients = parser.parse(Request.Response)
```

As far as the design of the project goes, I think you've done well to separate the `Request` as a Class and then making the request from a Module. I ran into many similar problems accessing Salesforce from Excel and created a library that I think may help: [Excel-REST](https://github.com/timhall/excel-rest). It follows a similar idea, but separates it into three classes: Client, Request, and Response. Here's an example:

```
Sub RetrieveJSONSimple
  Dim Client As New RestClient
  Dim Response As RestResponse
  Set Response = Client.GetJSON("url...")

  If Response.Status = Ok Then
    ' Response.Data is parsed json
    For Each Client in Response.Data
      Name = Client("Name")
      State = Client("siteState")
      Street = Client("Address")("Street")
      Suburb = Client("Address")("Suburb")
      City = Client("Address")("City")
    Next Client
  End If
End Sub

Sub RetrieveJSONAdvanced
  Dim Client As New RestClient
  Client.BaseUrl = "http://crimson/php/"
  ' Can also setup authentication with HTTP Basic, OAuth, and others

  Dim Request As New RestRequest
  Request.Resource = "SiteEnquiryAjax.php?action=aisFeed&brandCode=s&siteID={SiteId}"
  Request.AddUrlSegment "SiteId", "0625"

  ' GET and json are default, but can be set
  Request.Method = httpGET
  Request.Format = json

  Dim Response As RestResponse
  Set Response = Client.Execute(Request)

  ' Process as before
End Sub
```