# How to create excel report in cucumber project

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I know how to create HTML reports, but I don't know how to create excel report. Does anyone know how to create the excel report.

Comment: Why do you need excel report?

Comment: You can output to json then import to excel. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044423/json-import-to-excel

Comment: I had generated the HTML report but my team leader told me to generate the excel sheet report, so that is the reason.( Priyanshu Shekhar)

Comment: Hi  Dave McNulla, Is there any other way to generate the excel report. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output array to CSV in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822422/output-array-to-csv-in-ruby)

Comment: Write to CSV and then import to Excel. See the link above.

Comment: Hi JeffC, But how to convert the CSV to excel.

Comment: I have created csv and able to output the array into CSV.        Here is my code      require 'csv'
class Csv_Excel

  def initialize(browser)
    @browser = browser
  end

  def loading_to_csv
    CSV.open("c:/AJAY/report.csv", "wb") do |csv|
      csv << ["time", "url", "elec_disc", "check_box", "full_disc", "report" ]
    end
  end
end
 But here my question is how to convert csv into excel .

Comment: How do you expect this report to look like? I mean an excel report only makes sense if you have results of multiple runs and you want to fit them all in an excel sheet.

Comment: Hi Eugene, Do you know how to create excel sheet report, it does't matter how it looks but I need to generate the excel report.