# Best way of 'automating data' from Statistics Sweden to Excel?

Tags: excel, sdmx

This question hopefully serves as a purpose for other general questions of using SDMX/JSON or other request types of achieving data requests into excel.

I am new to this sort of data request, but was wondering how data could be pulled in a semi-automated way into excel for various data fields from Statistics Sweden's website.

Their API details are given here: http://www.scb.se/en_/About-us/Open-data-API/API-for-the-Statistical-Database-/

I'm looking to understand how certain fields can be pulled into Excel.

Comment: it is possible, do you have programming background, if yes which language do you use and what you have tried so far, if no use this https://konklone.io/json/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON import to Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8044423/11683)

Answer (score 1):

For SDMX XML format you may use some existing libraries (search github for sdmx).

Example of data: http://share.scb.se/AA0102/data/ECOFIN_NAG_08_Q_SE1.xml

Once you have the data you can transform it to CSV format (also look for libs), which can be imported into Excel.
If you are lucky you may even find some CSV export on that swedish site.