# Open Local JSON file in VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba

I have a number of local JSON files which I am trying to open as a string using VBA in order to extract specific information from them into Excel.

I have seen a similar exercise work when the files are accessed by HTTP (using New.WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest), however when I've tried to adapt this using a FILE:/// prefix it won't work.

Is there a different Excel method I can use to access the string content of the JSON file?

Cheers

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading from disk is not really something you would adapt code that reads from a url to do.

You can load it into memory with;

```
dim hf As integer: hf = freefile
dim data as string

open "c:\bla\bla.bla" for input as #hf
    data = input$(LOF(hf), #hf)
close #hf

debug.? data
```

There are many results for [JSON parsing in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782076/is-there-a-json-parser-for-vb6-vba).