# How to parse json string in vb6

Tags: json, parsing, vb6

I'm calling a web service in VB6 which returns a json string as response. I'm able to hold the response in a string. now I want to show the each parameter separately how can I extract the values from the string ?. a sample string is here :

```
{
    "id": "22144",
    "t" : "AAPL",
    "e" : "NASDAQ",
    "l" : "108.00",
    "l_fix" : "108.00",
    "l_cur" : "108.00",
    "s": "2",
    "ltt":"4:00PM EDT",
    "lt" : "Aug 10, 4:00PM EDT",
    "lt_dts" : "2016-08-10T16:00:01Z",
    "c" : "-0.81",
    "c_fix" : "-0.81",
    "cp" : "-0.74",
    "cp_fix" : "-0.74",
    "ccol" : "chr",
    "pcls_fix" : "108.81",
    "el": "107.98",
    "el_fix": "107.98",
    "el_cur": "107.98",
    "elt" : "Aug 10, 5:16PM EDT",
    "ec" : "-0.02",
    "ec_fix" : "-0.02",
    "ecp" : "-0.02",
    "ecp_fix" : "-0.02",
    "eccol" : "chr",
    "div" : "0.57",
    "yld" : "2.11"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is There a JSON Parser for VB6 / VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782076/is-there-a-json-parser-for-vb6-vba)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing JSON in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627652/parsing-json-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found <kbd>VB-JSON</kbd> works really well for parsing json in VB6.

You can download it from here.

#### [VB-JSON: A Visual Basic 6 (VB6) JSON Parser Class Library](http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html)

The `.zip` file that you download will contain a sample project and the library, which is called `JSON.bas`.

The main parser function is `JSON.parse` and you pass it the json string as parameter.

So in your project, you only need to include / add the `JSON.bas` file.

#### Sample Usage (from the sample project) :

```
Private Sub cmdObjToJSON_Click()

   Dim p As Object

   Dim sInputJson As String
   sInputJson = "{ width: '200', frame: false, height: 130, bodyStyle:'background-color: #ffffcc;',buttonAlign:'right', items: [{ xtype: 'form',  url: '/content.asp'},{ xtype: 'form2',  url: '/content2.asp'}] }"

   MsgBox "Input JSON string: " & sInputJson

   ' sets p
   Set p = JSON.parse(sInputJson)

   MsgBox "Parsed object output: " & JSON.toString(p)

   MsgBox "Get Bodystyle data: " & p.Item("bodyStyle")

   MsgBox "Get Form Url data: " & p.Item("items").Item(1).Item("url")


   p.Item("items").Item(1).Add "ExtraItem", "Extra Data Value"

   MsgBox "Parsed object output with added item: " & JSON.toString(p)


End Sub
```

As it applies to your case. Something like the following might work (with some tweaks if needed).

```
Dim parsedJsonObject As Object
Set parsedJsonObject = JSON.parse(yourJsonStringVariable)

'Print the ticker ( t in your json )
Debug.Print parsedJsonObject.Item("t")
```

Comment: is there any way to get the length of the jsonarry here

Answer (score 1):

There is a JSON parser library for Visual Basic that you can find in http://json.org/.
You can either use VB-JSON or PW.JSON.