# Parsing Json string vb6

Tags: json, vb6

My code to retrieve STRINGA:

```
Private Sub RestExample()

    Dim APICall As String
    Dim Query As String
    Dim strKey As String, STRINGA AS STRING
    Dim myXML As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim nodes As IXMLDOMSelection

    APICall = "https://oauth.openapi.it/counters/total"
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", APICall, False
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & PASSWORD
        .send
        STRINGA = .responseText
    End With

End Sub
```

to the end i have in STRINGA:

```
{"data":{"GET:oauth.openapi.it\/counters":{"counter":22,"paid":0,"limit":false},"GET:oauth.openapi.it\/scopes":{"counter":6,"paid":0,"limit":false},"POST:oauth.openapi.it\/token":{"counter":1,"paid":0,"limit":false},"GET:imprese.openapi.it\/advance":{"counter":14,"paid":0,"limit":false},"GET:imprese.openapi.it\/base":{"counter":2,"paid":0,"limit":false}},"success":true,"message":"","error":null}
```

How to get all values from Json node?

Comment: Title says VB6 but your question is also tagged with VBA?  Which is it?  For VBA, you can use https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43464001/5162073).

Comment: I have no words to thank you, SAVED ME!

Answer (score 1):

Download [VB-JSON: A Visual Basic 6 (VB6) JSON Parser Class Library](http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html) and add the necessary items to your project.  Once added you parse the JSON string like this:

```
Dim p As Object
Set p = JSON.parse(STRINGA)
```

And you can retrieve values like this

```
Debug.Print p.Item("data").Item("GET:oauth.openapi.it\/counters").Item("counter")
Debug.Print p.Item("success")
Debug.Print p.Item("message")
Debug.Print p.Item("error")
```

Or if you want to iterate over the items do something like this:

```
Dim Data As Variant
Dim Item As Variant
   
For Each Data In p.Item("data").Items
   For Each Item In Data.Items
      Debug.Print Item
   Next
Next
```

Comment: I have no words to thank you, SAVED ME!