# From C# API Datatable to ADOB recordset for VBA

Tags: c#, excel, vba, rest

I have an REST API, written in C#. The API queries the data from a Database and returns a message with POST. The API is called from an Excel Macro.
The issue that I am facing is with the results of the query.

If I try to return a ADODB.Recordset then the message cannot be serialized (xmlSerializer.Serialize method fails).

If I return a datatable then - it is not recognized in VBA code.

*(For i = 0 To dataTable.Columns.Count - 1)* returns the error "Object does not support this property or method."

Can you please advise me about the best way approach this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have plenty of options to serialize the data: csv/tab-delimited, xml, json etc.   Do you really want to send a binary object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating I successfully used the following method to solve this problem:

[Return ADODB.RecordSet from ReST Call as ADODB.Recordset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819238/return-adodb-recordset-from-rest-call-as-adodb-recordset)

Server Code -

```
ADODB.Stream stream = new ADODB.Stream();
rs.Save(stream, PersistFormatEnum.adPersistXML);
rs.Close();
rsString = stream.ReadText();
return Ok(rsString);
```

Client Code
_

```
Recordset ret = null;
string strResponse = string.Empty;
Does things to call out to the ReST web service...
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strResponse))
{
    strResponse = Replace(Replace(Replace(strResponse, "\\t", "    "), "\\r\\n", " "), "\", "");
    ret = new Recordset();
    Dim s As Object
    Set s = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    stream.Open();
    stream.WriteText(strResponse);
    stream.Position = 0;
    ret.Open(stream);
}

return ret;
```