# accesing web service in VB6 with json

Tags: json, vb6

I'm calling a web service in VB6 which returns a json string as response. I'm able to hold the response in a string. now I want to show the each parameter separately how can I extract the values from the string ?. a sample string is here :

```
"aaa": {"bbb": 900,"ccc": "oke"},"result": {"count": 3,"data": [["x1, x2","x3"],["y1, y2","y3"],["z1, z2","z3"]]}}
```

Comment: Please post the code you already tried, so we can review it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is There a JSON Parser for VB6 / VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782076/is-there-a-json-parser-for-vb6-vba)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options
1. Write your own Json parser in VB6
2. Create a COM wrapper for Json.Net and use it in your code.

The first one is going to be quite complex, but your code will not have any runtime dependeny

The second approach is fairly easier but will require the .Net Framework to be installed in the machines where your VB6 code is running.

Comment: Is there no preexisting 3rd-party VB6 JSON library?

Comment: The last code I wrote in VB6 was in 2005 and Json didn't exist then. I'm not sure if anyone has written a Json parser in VB6. If it doesn't contain arrays or child elements, then you can quickly put up a simple parser with Split() and Substring () functions.

Comment: Turns out there are some options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782076/is-there-a-json-parser-for-vb6-vba  and  http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html is mentioned often.

Comment: That really great to hear that VB6 is alive and kicking. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: It is indeed! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've used two different solutions for this in the past and although they are not very user friendly, they get the job done well enough. I apologize for not having links to the original code and author.

This is the best one in my opinion:

```
Option Explicit
DefObj A-Z
Private Const MODULE_NAME As String = "mdJson"

'=========================================================================
' API
'=========================================================================

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

Private Type JsonContext
    Text()              As Integer
    pos                 As Long
    Error               As String
    LastChar            As Integer
End Type

'=========================================================================
' Error management
'=========================================================================

Private Sub RaiseError(sFunction As String)
'    PushError
'    PopRaiseError sFunction, MODULE_NAME
    Err.Raise Err.Number, MODULE_NAME & "." & sFunction & vbCrLf & Err.Source, Err.Description
End Sub

Private Sub PrintError(sFunction As String)
'    PushError
'    PopPrintError sFunction, MODULE_NAME
    Debug.Print MODULE_NAME & "." & sFunction & ": " & Err.Description, Timer
End Sub

'=========================================================================
' Functions
'=========================================================================

Public Function JsonParse(sText As String, vResult As Variant, Optional Error As String) As Boolean
    Const FUNC_NAME     As String = "JsonParse"
    Dim uCtx            As JsonContext
    Dim oResult         As Object

    On Error GoTo EH
    With uCtx
        ReDim .Text(0 To Len(sText)) As Integer
        Call CopyMemory(.Text(0), ByVal StrPtr(sText), LenB(sText))
        JsonParse = pvJsonParse(uCtx, vResult, oResult)
        If Not oResult Is Nothing Then
            Set vResult = oResult
        End If
        Error = .Error
    End With
    Exit Function
EH:
    PrintError FUNC_NAME
    Resume Next
End Function

Private Function pvJsonMissing(Optional vMissing As Variant) As Variant
    pvJsonMissing = vMissing
End Function

Private Function pvJsonParse(uCtx As JsonContext, vResult As Variant, oResult As Object) As Boolean
    '--- note: when using collections change type of parameter oResult to Collection
    #Const USE_RICHCLIENT = False
    #Const USE_COLLECTION = False
    Const FUNC_NAME     As String = "pvJsonParse"
    Dim lIdx            As Long
    Dim vKey            As Variant
    Dim vValue          As Variant
    Dim oValue          As Object
    Dim sText           As String

    On Error GoTo EH
    vValue = pvJsonMissing
    With uCtx
        Select Case pvJsonGetChar(uCtx)
        Case 34 ' "
            vResult = pvJsonGetString(uCtx)
        Case 91 ' [
            #If USE_RICHCLIENT Then
                #If USE_COLLECTION Then
                    Set oResult = New cCollection
                #Else
                    Set oResult = New cSortedDictionary
                #End If
            #Else
                #If USE_COLLECTION Then
                    Set oResult = New Collection
                #Else
                    Set oResult = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                #End If
            #End If
            Do
                Select Case pvJsonGetChar(uCtx)
                Case 0, 44, 93 ' , ]
                    If Not oValue Is Nothing Then
                        #If USE_COLLECTION Then
                            oResult.Add oValue
                        #Else
                            oResult.Add lIdx, oValue
                        #End If
                    ElseIf Not IsMissing(vValue) Then
                        #If USE_COLLECTION Then
                            oResult.Add vValue
                        #Else
                            oResult.Add lIdx, vValue
                        #End If
                    End If
                    If .LastChar <> 44 Then ' ,
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                    lIdx = lIdx + 1
                    vValue = pvJsonMissing
                    Set oValue = Nothing
                Case Else
                    .pos = .pos - 1
                    If Not pvJsonParse(uCtx, vValue, oValue) Then
                        GoTo QH
                    End If
                End Select
            Loop
        Case 123 ' {
            #If USE_RICHCLIENT Then
                #If USE_COLLECTION Then
                    Set oResult = New cCollection
                #Else
                    Set oResult = New cSortedDictionary
                    oResult.StringCompareMode = 1 ' TextCompare
                #End If
            #Else
                #If USE_COLLECTION Then
                    Set oResult = New Collection
                #Else
                    Set oResult = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                    oResult.CompareMode = 1 ' TextCompare
                #End If
            #End If
            Do
                Select Case pvJsonGetChar(uCtx)
                Case 34 ' "
                    vKey = pvJsonGetString(uCtx)
                Case 58 ' :
                    If Not oValue Is Nothing Then
                        .Error = "Value already specified at position " & .pos
                        GoTo QH
                    ElseIf Not IsMissing(vValue) Then
                        vKey = vValue
                        vValue = pvJsonMissing
                    End If
                    lIdx = .pos
                    If Not pvJsonParse(uCtx, vValue, oValue) Then
                        .pos = lIdx
                        vValue = Empty
                        Set oValue = Nothing
                    End If
                Case 0, 44, 125 ' , }
                    If IsMissing(vValue) And oValue Is Nothing Then
                        If IsEmpty(vKey) Then
                            GoTo NoProp
                        End If
                        vValue = vKey
                        vKey = vbNullString
                    End If
                    If IsEmpty(vKey) Then
                        vKey = vbNullString
                    ElseIf IsNull(vKey) Then
                        vKey = "null"
                    End If
                    If Not oValue Is Nothing Then
                        #If USE_COLLECTION Then
                            oResult.Add oValue, vKey & ""
                        #Else
                            oResult.Add vKey & "", oValue
                        #End If
                    Else
                        #If USE_COLLECTION Then
                            oResult.Add vValue, vKey & ""
                        #Else
                            oResult.Add vKey & "", vValue
                        #End If
                    End If
NoProp:
                    If .LastChar = 0 Then
                        GoTo QH
                    ElseIf .LastChar <> 44 Then ' ,
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                    vKey = Empty
                    vValue = pvJsonMissing
                    Set oValue = Nothing
                Case Else
                    .pos = .pos - 1
                    If Not pvJsonParse(uCtx, vValue, oValue) Then
                        GoTo QH
                    End If
                End Select
            Loop
        Case 116, 84  ' "t", "T"
            If Not ((.Text(.pos + 0) Or &H20) = 114 And (.Text(.pos + 1) Or &H20) = 117 And (.Text(.pos + 2) Or &H20) = 101) Then
                GoTo UnexpectedSymbol
            End If
            .pos = .pos + 3
            vResult = True
        Case 102, 70 ' "f", "F"
            If Not ((.Text(.pos + 0) Or &H20) = 97 And (.Text(.pos + 1) Or &H20) = 108 And (.Text(.pos + 2) Or &H20) = 115 And (.Text(.pos + 3) Or &H20) = 101) Then
                GoTo UnexpectedSymbol
            End If
            .pos = .pos + 4
            vResult = False
        Case 110, 78 ' "n", "N"
            If Not ((.Text(.pos + 0) Or &H20) = 117 And (.Text(.pos + 1) Or &H20) = 108 And (.Text(.pos + 2) Or &H20) = 108) Then
                GoTo UnexpectedSymbol
            End If
            .pos = .pos + 3
            vResult = Null
        Case 48 To 57, 43, 45, 46 ' 0-9 + - .
            For lIdx = 0 To 1000
                Select Case .Text(.pos + lIdx)
                Case 48 To 57, 43, 45, 46, 101, 69, 120, 88, 97 To 102, 65 To 70 ' 0-9 + - . e E x X a-f A-F
                Case Else
                    Exit For
                End Select
            Next
            sText = Space$(lIdx + 1)
            Call CopyMemory(ByVal StrPtr(sText), .Text(.pos - 1), LenB(sText))
            If LCase$(Left$(sText, 2)) = "0x" Then
                sText = "&H" & Mid$(sText, 3)
            End If
            On Error GoTo ErrorConvert
            vResult = CDbl(sText)
            On Error GoTo 0
            .pos = .pos + lIdx
        Case 0
            If LenB(.Error) <> 0 Then
                GoTo QH
            End If
        Case Else
            GoTo UnexpectedSymbol
        End Select
        pvJsonParse = True
QH:
        Exit Function
UnexpectedSymbol:
        .Error = "Unexpected symbol '" & ChrW$(.LastChar) & "' at position " & .pos
        Exit Function
ErrorConvert:
        .Error = Err.Description & " at position " & .pos
    End With
    Exit Function
EH:
    RaiseError FUNC_NAME
End Function

Private Function pvJsonGetChar(uCtx As JsonContext) As Integer
    Const FUNC_NAME     As String = "pvJsonGetChar"
    Dim lIdx            As Long

    On Error GoTo EH
    With uCtx
        Do While .pos <= UBound(.Text)
            .LastChar = .Text(.pos)
            .pos = .pos + 1
            Select Case .LastChar
            Case 0
                Exit Function
            Case 9, 10, 13, 32 ' vbTab, vbCr, vbLf, " "
                '--- do nothing
            Case 47 ' /
                Select Case .Text(.pos)
                Case 47 ' //
                    .pos = .pos + 1
                    Do
                        .LastChar = .Text(.pos)
                        .pos = .pos + 1
                        If .LastChar = 0 Then
                            Exit Function
                        End If
                    Loop While Not (.LastChar = 10 Or .LastChar = 13)  ' vbLf or vbCr
                Case 42 ' /*
                    lIdx = .pos + 1
                    Do
                        .LastChar = .Text(lIdx)
                        lIdx = lIdx + 1
                        If .LastChar = 0 Then
                            .Error = "Unterminated comment at position " & .pos
                            Exit Function
                        End If
                    Loop While Not (.LastChar = 42 And .Text(lIdx) = 47) ' */
                    .LastChar = .Text(lIdx)
                    .pos = lIdx + 1
                Case Else
                    pvJsonGetChar = .LastChar
                    Exit Do
                End Select
            Case Else
                pvJsonGetChar = .LastChar
                Exit Do
            End Select
        Loop
    End With
    Exit Function
EH:
    RaiseError FUNC_NAME
End Function

Private Function pvJsonGetString(uCtx As JsonContext) As String
    Const FUNC_NAME     As String = "pvJsonGetString"
    Dim lIdx            As Long
    Dim nChar           As Integer
    Dim sText           As String

    On Error GoTo EH
    With uCtx
        For lIdx = 0 To &H7FFFFFFF
            nChar = .Text(.pos + lIdx)
            Select Case nChar
            Case 0, 34, 92 ' " \
                sText = Space$(lIdx)
                Call CopyMemory(ByVal StrPtr(sText), .Text(.pos), LenB(sText))
                pvJsonGetString = pvJsonGetString & sText
                If nChar <> 92 Then ' \
                    .pos = .pos + lIdx + 1
                    Exit For
                End If
                lIdx = lIdx + 1
                nChar = .Text(.pos + lIdx)
                Select Case nChar
                Case 0
                    Exit For
                Case 98  ' b
                    pvJsonGetString = pvJsonGetString & Chr$(8)
                Case 102 ' f
                    pvJsonGetString = pvJsonGetString & Chr$(12)
                Case 110 ' n
                    pvJsonGetString = pvJsonGetString & vbLf
                Case 114 ' r
                    pvJsonGetString = pvJsonGetString & vbCr
                Case 116 ' t
                    pvJsonGetString = pvJsonGetString & vbTab
                Case 117 ' u
                    pvJsonGetString = pvJsonGetString & ChrW$(CLng("&H" & ChrW$(.Text(.pos + lIdx + 1)) & ChrW$(.Text(.pos + lIdx + 2)) & ChrW$(.Text(.pos + lIdx + 3)) & ChrW$(.Text(.pos + lIdx + 4))))
                    lIdx = lIdx + 4
                Case 120 ' x
                    pvJsonGetString = pvJsonGetString & ChrW$(CLng("&H" & ChrW$(.Text(.pos + lIdx + 1)) & ChrW$(.Text(.pos + lIdx + 2))))
                    lIdx = lIdx + 2
                Case Else
                    pvJsonGetString = pvJsonGetString & ChrW$(nChar)
                End Select
                .pos = .pos + lIdx + 1
                lIdx = -1
            End Select
        Next
    End With
    Exit Function
EH:
    RaiseError FUNC_NAME
End Function

Public Function JsonDump(vJson As Variant, Optional ByVal Level As Long, Optional ByVal Minimize As Boolean) As String
    Const FUNC_NAME     As String = "JsonDump"
    Const STR_CODES     As String = "\u0000|\u0001|\u0002|\u0003|\u0004|\u0005|\u0006|\u0007|\b|\t|\n|\u000B|\f|\r|\u000E|\u000F|\u0010|\u0011|\u0012|\u0013|\u0014|\u0015|\u0016|\u0017|\u0018|\u0019|\u001A|\u001B|\u001C|\u001D|\u001E|\u001F"
    Const INDENT        As Long = 4
    Static vTranscode   As Variant
    Dim vKeys           As Variant
    Dim vItems          As Variant
    Dim lIdx            As Long
    Dim lSize           As Long
    Dim sCompound       As String
    Dim sSpace          As String
    Dim lAsc            As Long

    On Error GoTo EH
    Select Case VarType(vJson)
    Case vbObject
        sCompound = IIf(vJson.CompareMode = 0, "[]", "{}")
        sSpace = IIf(Minimize, vbNullString, " ")
        If vJson.Count = 0 Then
            JsonDump = sCompound
        Else
            vKeys = vJson.Keys
            vItems = vJson.Items
            For lIdx = 0 To vJson.Count - 1
                vItems(lIdx) = JsonDump(vItems(lIdx), Level + 1, Minimize)
                If vJson.CompareMode = 1 Then
                    vItems(lIdx) = JsonDump(vKeys(lIdx)) & ":" & sSpace & vItems(lIdx)
                End If
                lSize = lSize + Len(vItems(lIdx))
            Next
            If lSize > 100 And Not Minimize Then
                JsonDump = Left$(sCompound, 1) & vbCrLf & _
                    Space$((Level + 1) * INDENT) & Join(vItems, "," & vbCrLf & Space$((Level + 1) * INDENT)) & vbCrLf & _
                    Space$(Level * INDENT) & Right$(sCompound, 1)
            Else
                JsonDump = Left$(sCompound, 1) & sSpace & Join(vItems, "," & sSpace) & sSpace & Right$(sCompound, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Case vbNull
        JsonDump = "Null"
    Case vbEmpty
        JsonDump = "Empty"
    Case vbString
        '--- one-time initialization of transcoding array
        If IsEmpty(vTranscode) Then
            vTranscode = Split(STR_CODES, "|")
        End If
        For lIdx = 1 To Len(vJson)
            lAsc = AscW(Mid$(vJson, lIdx, 1))
            If lAsc = 92 Or lAsc = 34 Then '--- \ and "
                JsonDump = JsonDump & "\" & Chr$(lAsc)
            ElseIf lAsc >= 32 And lAsc < 256 Then
                JsonDump = JsonDump & Chr$(lAsc)
            ElseIf lAsc >= 0 And lAsc < 32 Then
                JsonDump = JsonDump & vTranscode(lAsc)
            ElseIf Asc(Mid$(vJson, lIdx, 1)) <> 63 Then '--- ?
                JsonDump = JsonDump & Chr$(Asc(Mid$(vJson, lIdx, 1)))
            Else
                JsonDump = JsonDump & "\u" & Right$("0000" & Hex(lAsc), 4)
            End If
        Next
        JsonDump = """" & JsonDump & """"
    Case Else
        JsonDump = vJson & ""
    End Select
    Exit Function
EH:
    PrintError FUNC_NAME
    Resume Next
End Function
```

You use it by providing a Variant to the JsonParse function:

```
Dim objJSON As Variant
Dim sJSON as String
Dim fParseSuccess As Boolean

fParseSuccess = JsonParse(sJSON, objJSON)
```

You can then navigate through the Collection and Dictionary objects it creates. This part is not very user-friendly but you'll get the hang of it. Here's an example:

```
For iCounter = 0 To objJSON.Item("dates").Count - 1
    Dim tmp as Variant

    tmp = objJSON.Item("dates").Item(iCounter).Item("date")

    For iIndex = 0 To objJSON.Item("dates").Item(iCounter).Item("games").Count - 1

        With objJSON.Item("dates").Item(iCounter).Item("games")
            iVisID = .Item(iIndex).Item("teams").Item("away").Item("team").Item("id")
            iHomeID = .Item(iIndex).Item("teams").Item("home").Item("team").Item("id")
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution I found. This one was less performant parsing a large amount of data but is a little more user friendly. This is a Class:

```
Option Explicit

'Not a real (fractional) number, but Major.Minor integers:
Private Const CLASS_VERSION As String = "1.6"

'Character constants.
Private Const LBRACE As String = "{"
Private Const RBRACE As String = "}"
Private Const LBRACKET As String = "["
Private Const RBRACKET As String = "]"
Private Const COLON As String = ":"
Private Const COMMA As String = ","
Private Const QUOTE As String = """"
Private Const PLUS As String = "+"
Private Const MINUS As String = "-"
Private Const RADIXPOINT As String = "." 'Always a period since we're locale-blind.
Private Const ZERO As String = "0"
Private Const NINE As String = "9"
Private Const REVSOLIDUS As String = "\"

Private Const WHITE_SPACE As String = vbTab & vbLf & vbCr & " "

Private Const S_OK As Long = 0
Private Const VARIANT_ALPHABOOL As Long = &H2&
Private Const LOCALE_INVARIANT As Long = 127& 'Used to do VT conversions with the invariant locale.

Private Declare Function HashData Lib "shlwapi" ( _
    ByVal pbData As Long, _
    ByVal cbData As Long, _
    ByVal pbHash As Long, _
    ByVal cbHash As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function StrSpn Lib "shlwapi" Alias "StrSpnW" ( _
    ByVal psz As Long, _
    ByVal pszSet As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function VariantChangeTypeEx Lib "oleaut32" ( _
    ByRef vargDest As Variant, _
    ByRef varSrc As Variant, _
    ByVal lcid As Long, _
    ByVal wFlags As Integer, _
    ByVal vt As VbVarType) As Long

Private TypeNameOfMe As String 'Used in raising exceptions.
Private Names As Collection
Private Values As Collection
Private CursorIn As Long 'Scan position within JSON input string.
Private LengthIn As Long 'Length of JSON input string.
Private TextOut As String 'Buffer to build JSON output string in.
Private CursorOut As Long 'Append position within JSON output string.
Private NumberType As VbVarType

Private vbUS As String 'Pseudo-const ChrW$(&H1F&).

Private mIsArray As Boolean
Private mDecimalMode As Boolean

'=== Public Properties =================================================================

Public Whitespace As Boolean 'True to use indenting and newlines on JSON Get.

Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = Values.Count
End Property

Public Property Get DecimalMode() As Boolean
    DecimalMode = mDecimalMode
End Property

Public Property Let DecimalMode(ByVal RHS As Boolean)
    mDecimalMode = RHS
    If mDecimalMode Then
        NumberType = vbDecimal
    Else
        NumberType = vbDouble
    End If
End Property

Public Property Let IsArray(ByVal RHS As Boolean)
    If Values.Count > 0 Then
        Err.Raise 5, TypeNameOfMe, "Cannot change IsArray setting after items have been added"
    Else
        mIsArray = RHS
        If mIsArray Then Set Names = Nothing
    End If
End Property

Public Property Get IsArray() As Boolean
    IsArray = mIsArray
End Property

'Default property.
Public Property Get Item(ByVal Key As Variant) As Variant
    'Retrieval works either by key or index for "objects" but only
    'by index for "arrays."

    Dim PrefixedKey As String

    If IsNull(Key) Then Err.Raise 94, TypeNameOfMe, "Key must be String or an index)"
    If VarType(Key) = vbString Then
        If mIsArray Then
            Err.Raise 5, TypeNameOfMe, "Array values can only be acessed by index"
        End If

        PrefixedKey = PrefixHash(Key)
        If IsObject(Values.Item(PrefixedKey)) Then
            Set Item = Values.Item(PrefixedKey)
        Else
            Item = Values.Item(PrefixedKey)
        End If
    Else
        If IsObject(Values.Item(Key)) Then
            Set Item = Values.Item(Key)
        Else
            Item = Values.Item(Key)
        End If
    End If
End Property

Public Property Let Item(Optional ByVal Key As Variant = Null, ByVal RHS As Variant)
    'Add new Item or change existing Item's value.
    '
    'When IsArray = True:
    '
    '   Pass a Null as Key to add a new item at the end of the "array."
    '
    '   Pass an index (Long) as Key to assign a new value to an
    '   existing Item.  However if the index is greater than .Count
    '   the value is added as a new entry at the end of the "array."
    '
    'When IsArray = False:
    '
    '   Pass a name (String) as Key.  If the named Item exists its
    '   value is updated.  If it does not exist a new Item is added.
    '
    'Item reassignment for existing items (assign new value) is
    'implemented as remove and re-add.  This means changing the value
    'of an "object's" Item moves it to the end of the list.

    Dim PrefixedKey As String

    With Values
        If mIsArray Then
            If VarType(Key) = vbString Then
                Err.Raise 5, TypeNameOfMe, "Array values can only be changed by index or added via Null"
            End If

            If IsNull(Key) Then
                .Add RHS            'Add at end.
            Else
                If Key > .Count Then
                    .Add RHS        'Add at end.
                Else
                    .Remove Key
                    .Add RHS, , Key 'Insert into position.
                End If
            End If
        Else
            If VarType(Key) <> vbString Then
                Err.Raise 5, TypeNameOfMe, "Object values can only be changed or added by key not by index"
            End If

            PrefixedKey = PrefixHash(Key)
            On Error Resume Next
            .Add RHS, PrefixedKey
            If Err Then
                On Error GoTo 0
                'Add failed, Key must already exist.  Remove/re-add.  Remove Name.
                .Remove PrefixedKey
                .Add RHS, PrefixedKey
                Names.Remove PrefixedKey
            Else
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
            'Add Name.
            Names.Add Key, PrefixedKey
        End If
    End With
End Property

Public Property Set Item(ByVal Key As Variant, ByVal RHS As Variant)
    'This is just an alias for Let since we don't have to do anything
    'different.
    '
    'This allows either Let or Set to be used by client logic.

    Item(Key) = RHS
End Property

Public Property Get JSON() As String
    CursorOut = 1
    SerializeItem vbNullString, Me
    JSON = Left$(TextOut, CursorOut - 1)

    'Clear for next reuse.  Do it here to reclaim space.
    TextOut = ""
End Property

Public Property Let JSON(ByRef RHS As String)
    Clear

    CursorIn = 1
    LengthIn = Len(RHS)

    SkipWhitespace RHS

    Select Case Mid$(RHS, CursorIn, 1)
        Case LBRACE
            CursorIn = CursorIn + 1
            ParseObject RHS, CursorIn, Len(RHS)
        Case LBRACKET
            CursorIn = CursorIn + 1
            ParseArray RHS, CursorIn, Len(RHS)
        Case Else
            Error13A "either " & LBRACE & " or " & LBRACKET, CursorIn
    End Select
End Property

Public Property Get Name(ByVal Index As Long) As String
    If mIsArray Then Err.Raise 5, TypeNameOfMe, "Array items do not have names"

    Name = Names.Item(Index)
End Property

Public Property Get Version() As String()
    Version = Split(CLASS_VERSION)
End Property

'=== Public Methods ====================================================================

Public Function AddNewArray(Optional ByVal Key As Variant = Null) As clsJSONBag
    Dim NewArray As clsJSONBag

    Set NewArray = New clsJSONBag
    NewArray.IsArray = True
    Set Item(Key) = NewArray
    Set AddNewArray = NewArray

End Function

Public Function AddNewObject(Optional ByVal Key As Variant = Null) As clsJSONBag
    Dim NewObject As clsJSONBag

    Set NewObject = New clsJSONBag
    Set Item(Key) = NewObject
    Set AddNewObject = NewObject

End Function

Public Sub Clear()
    Set Names = New Collection
    Set Values = New Collection
    mIsArray = False
End Sub

Public Function Exists(ByVal Key As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim Name As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Name = Names.Item(Key)
    Exists = Err.Number = 0
    Err.Clear

End Function

'Marked as hidden and ProcedureID = -4
Public Function NewEnum() As IUnknown
    If mIsArray Then Err.Raise 5, TypeNameOfMe, "Arrays must be iterated using index values"

    Set NewEnum = Names.[_NewEnum]
End Function

Public Sub Remove(ByVal Key As Variant)
    'Allow remove by Key or Index (only by Index for arrays).  If the item
    'does not exist return silently.

    Dim PrefixedKey As String

    If VarType(Key) = vbString Then
        If mIsArray Then Err.Raise 5, TypeNameOfMe, "Must remove by index for arrays"

        PrefixedKey = PrefixHash(Key)
        On Error Resume Next
        Names.Remove PrefixedKey
        If Err Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        Values.Remove PrefixedKey
    Else
        If Key < Values.Count Then
            Values.Remove Key
            If Not IsArray Then Names.Remove Key
        End If
    End If
End Sub

'=== Friend Methods (do not call from client logic) ====================================

Friend Sub ParseArray(ByRef Text As String, ByRef StartCursor As Long, ByVal TextLength As Long)
    'This call is made within the context of the instance at hand.
    Dim ArrayValue As Variant

    CursorIn = StartCursor
    LengthIn = TextLength

    mIsArray = True
    Do
        SkipWhitespace Text
        Select Case Mid$(Text, CursorIn, 1)
            Case COMMA
                CursorIn = CursorIn + 1
            Case RBRACKET
                CursorIn = CursorIn + 1
                Exit Do
            Case Else
                ParseValue Text, ArrayValue
                Values.Add ArrayValue
        End Select
    Loop
    StartCursor = CursorIn

End Sub

Friend Sub ParseObject(ByRef Text As String, ByRef StartCursor As Long, ByVal TextLength As Long)
    'This call is made within the context of the instance at hand.

    Dim Char As String
    Dim ItemName As String
    Dim Value As Variant
    Dim FoundFirstItem As Boolean

    CursorIn = StartCursor
    LengthIn = TextLength

    Do
        SkipWhitespace Text
        Char = Mid$(Text, CursorIn, 1)
        CursorIn = CursorIn + 1
        Select Case Char
            Case QUOTE
                ItemName = ParseName(Text)
                ParseValue Text, Value
                Item(ItemName) = Value
                FoundFirstItem = True
            Case COMMA
                If Not FoundFirstItem Then
                    Err.Raise 13, TypeNameOfMe, "Found "","" before first item at character " & CStr(CursorIn - 1)
                End If
            Case RBRACE
                Exit Do
            Case Else
                Error13A ", or }", CursorIn - 1
        End Select
    Loop
    StartCursor = CursorIn
End Sub

'=== Private Methods ===================================================================

Private Sub Cat(ByRef NewText As String)
    Const TEXT_CHUNK As Long = 512 'Allocation size for destination buffer Text.
    Dim LenNew As Long

    LenNew = Len(NewText)
    If LenNew > 0 Then
        If CursorOut + LenNew - 1 > Len(TextOut) Then
            If LenNew > TEXT_CHUNK Then
                TextOut = TextOut & Space$(LenNew + TEXT_CHUNK)
            Else
                TextOut = TextOut & Space$(TEXT_CHUNK)
            End If
        End If
        Mid$(TextOut, CursorOut, LenNew) = NewText
        CursorOut = CursorOut + LenNew
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Error13A(ByVal Symbol As String, ByVal Position As Long)
    Err.Raise 13, TypeNameOfMe, "Expected " & Symbol & " at character " & CStr(Position)
End Sub

Private Sub Error13B(ByVal Position As Long)
    Err.Raise 13, TypeNameOfMe, "Bad string character escape at character " & CStr(Position)
End Sub

Private Function ParseName(ByRef Text As String) As String
    ParseName = ParseString(Text)

    SkipWhitespace Text
    If Mid$(Text, CursorIn, 1) <> COLON Then
        Error13A COLON, CursorIn
    End If
    CursorIn = CursorIn + 1
End Function

Private Function ParseNumber(ByRef Text As String) As Variant
    Dim SaveCursor As Long
    Dim BuildString As String
    Dim BuildCursor As Long
    Dim Char As String
    Dim GotDecPoint As Boolean
    Dim GotExpSign As Boolean

    SaveCursor = CursorIn 'Saved for "bad number format" error.
    BuildString = Space$(LengthIn - CursorIn + 1)

    'We know 1st char has been validated by the caller.
    BuildCursor = 1
    Mid$(BuildString, 1, 1) = Mid$(Text, CursorIn, 1)

    For CursorIn = CursorIn + 1 To LengthIn
        Char = LCase$(Mid$(Text, CursorIn, 1))
        Select Case Char
            Case RADIXPOINT
                If GotDecPoint Then
                    Err.Raise 13, TypeNameOfMe, "Second decimal point at character " & CStr(CursorIn)
                End If
                If Mid$(BuildString, BuildCursor, 1) = MINUS Then
                    Err.Raise 13, TypeNameOfMe, "Digit expected at character " & CStr(CursorIn)
                End If
                GotDecPoint = True
            Case ZERO To NINE
                'Do nothing.
            Case "e"
                CursorIn = CursorIn + 1
                Exit For
            Case Else
                Exit For
        End Select
        BuildCursor = BuildCursor + 1
        Mid$(BuildString, BuildCursor, 1) = Char
    Next

    If Char = "e" Then
        BuildCursor = BuildCursor + 1
        Mid$(BuildString, BuildCursor, 1) = Char

        For CursorIn = CursorIn To LengthIn
            Char = Mid$(Text, CursorIn, 1)
            Select Case Char
                Case PLUS, MINUS
                    If GotExpSign Then
                        Err.Raise 13, TypeNameOfMe, "Second exponent sign at character " & CStr(CursorIn)
                    End If
                    GotExpSign = True
                Case ZERO To NINE
                    'Do nothing.
                Case Else
                    Exit For
            End Select
            BuildCursor = BuildCursor + 1
            Mid$(BuildString, BuildCursor, 1) = Char
        Next
    End If

    If CursorIn > LengthIn Then
        Err.Raise 13, TypeNameOfMe, "Ran off end of string while parsing a number"
    End If

    ParseNumber = Left$(BuildString, BuildCursor)
    If VariantChangeTypeEx(ParseNumber, ParseNumber, LOCALE_INVARIANT, 0, NumberType) <> S_OK Then
        Err.Raise 6, TypeNameOfMe, "Number overflow or parse error at character " & CStr(SaveCursor)
    End If
End Function

Private Function ParseString(ByRef Text As String) As String
    Dim BuildCursor As Long
    Dim Char As String

    ParseString = Space$(LengthIn - CursorIn + 1)

    For CursorIn = CursorIn To LengthIn
        Char = Mid$(Text, CursorIn, 1)
        Select Case Char
            Case vbNullChar To vbUS
                Err.Raise 13, TypeNameOfMe, "Invalid string character at " & CStr(CursorIn)
            Case REVSOLIDUS
                CursorIn = CursorIn + 1
                If CursorIn > LengthIn Then
                    Error13B CursorIn
                End If
                Char = LCase$(Mid$(Text, CursorIn, 1)) 'Accept uppercased escape symbols.
                Select Case Char
                    Case QUOTE, REVSOLIDUS, "/"
                        'Do nothing.
                    Case "b"
                        Char = vbBack
                    Case "f"
                        Char = vbFormFeed
                    Case "n"
                        Char = vbLf
                    Case "r"
                        Char = vbCr
                    Case "t"
                        Char = vbTab
                    Case "u"
                        CursorIn = CursorIn + 1
                        If LengthIn - CursorIn < 3 Then
                            Error13B CursorIn
                        End If
                        On Error Resume Next
                        Char = ChrW$(CLng("&H0" & Mid$(Text, CursorIn, 4)))
                        If Err Then
                            On Error GoTo 0
                            Error13B CursorIn
                        End If
                        On Error GoTo 0
                        CursorIn = CursorIn + 3 'Not + 4 because For loop will increment again.
                    Case Else
                        Error13B CursorIn
                End Select
            Case QUOTE
                CursorIn = CursorIn + 1
                Exit For
            'Case Else
                'Do Nothing, i.e. pass Char unchanged.
        End Select
        BuildCursor = BuildCursor + 1
        Mid$(ParseString, BuildCursor, 1) = Char
    Next

    If CursorIn > LengthIn Then
        Error13A QUOTE, LengthIn + 1
    End If
    ParseString = Left$(ParseString, BuildCursor)
End Function

Private Sub ParseValue(ByRef Text As String, ByRef Value As Variant)
    Dim SubBag As clsJSONBag
    Dim Token As String

    SkipWhitespace Text
    Select Case Mid$(Text, CursorIn, 1)
        Case QUOTE
            CursorIn = CursorIn + 1
            Value = ParseString(Text)
        Case LBRACE
            CursorIn = CursorIn + 1
            Set SubBag = New clsJSONBag
            SubBag.DecimalMode = DecimalMode
            SubBag.ParseObject Text, CursorIn, LengthIn
            Set Value = SubBag
        Case LBRACKET
            CursorIn = CursorIn + 1
            Set SubBag = New clsJSONBag
            SubBag.DecimalMode = DecimalMode
            SubBag.ParseArray Text, CursorIn, LengthIn
            Set Value = SubBag
        Case MINUS, ZERO To NINE
            Value = ParseNumber(Text)
        Case Else
            'Special value tokens.
            Token = LCase$(Mid$(Text, CursorIn, 4))
            If Token = "null" Then
                Value = Null
                CursorIn = CursorIn + 4
            ElseIf Token = "true" Then
                Value = True
                CursorIn = CursorIn + 4
            Else
                Token = LCase$(Mid$(Text, CursorIn, 5))
                If Token = "false" Then
                    Value = False
                    CursorIn = CursorIn + 5
                Else
                    Err.Raise 13, TypeNameOfMe, "Bad value at character " & CStr(CursorIn)
                End If
            End If
    End Select
End Sub

Private Function PrefixHash(ByVal KeyString As String) As String
    'This is used to make Collection access by key case-sensitive.

    Dim Hash As Long

    HashData StrPtr(KeyString), 2 * Len(KeyString), VarPtr(Hash), 4
    PrefixHash = Right$("0000000" & Hex$(Hash), 8) & KeyString
End Function

Private Sub SerializeItem( _
    ByVal ItemName As String, _
    ByRef Item As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal Level As Integer)
    'For outer level call set CursorOut = 1 before calling.  For outer level call
    'or array calls pass vbNullString as ItemName for "anonymity."

    Const TEXT_CHUNK As Long = 64
    Dim INDENT As String
    Dim Anonymous As Boolean
    Dim Name As Variant
    Dim ItemIndex As Long
    Dim TempItem As Variant
    Dim ItemBag As clsJSONBag
    Dim SubBag As clsJSONBag
    Dim ItemText As String
    Dim ArrayItem As Variant

    If Whitespace Then
        INDENT = Space$(4 * Level)
    End If

    Anonymous = StrPtr(ItemName) = 0 'Check for vbNullString.
    If Not Anonymous Then
        'Not vbNullString so we have a named Item.
        If Whitespace Then Cat INDENT
        Cat SerializeString(ItemName) & COLON
    End If

    Select Case VarType(Item)
        Case vbEmpty, vbNull 'vbEmpty case should actually never occur.
            If Whitespace And Anonymous Then Cat INDENT
            Cat "null"
        Case vbInteger, vbLong, vbSingle, vbDouble, vbCurrency, vbDecimal, vbByte, vbBoolean
            If Whitespace And Anonymous Then Cat INDENT
            If VariantChangeTypeEx(TempItem, _
                                   Item, _
                                   LOCALE_INVARIANT, _
                                   VARIANT_ALPHABOOL, _
                                   vbString) <> S_OK Then
                Err.Raise 51, TypeNameOfMe, ItemName & ", value " & CStr(Item) & " failed to serialize"
            End If
            Cat LCase$(TempItem) 'Convert to lowercase "true" and "false" and "1.234e34" and such.
        Case vbString
            If Whitespace And Anonymous Then Cat INDENT
            Cat SerializeString(Item)
        Case vbObject
            Set ItemBag = Item
            If ItemBag.IsArray Then
                If Whitespace And Anonymous Then Cat INDENT
                Cat LBRACKET
                If ItemBag.Count < 1 Then
                    Cat RBRACKET
                Else
                    If Whitespace Then Cat vbNewLine
                    With ItemBag
                        For ItemIndex = 1 To .Count
                            If IsObject(.Item(ItemIndex)) Then
                                Set TempItem = .Item(ItemIndex)
                            Else
                                TempItem = .Item(ItemIndex)
                            End If
                            SerializeItem vbNullString, TempItem, Level + 1
                            Cat COMMA
                            If Whitespace Then Cat vbNewLine
                        Next
                    End With
                    If Whitespace Then
                        CursorOut = CursorOut - 3
                        Cat vbNewLine & INDENT & RBRACKET
                    Else
                        Mid$(TextOut, CursorOut - 1) = RBRACKET
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                If Whitespace And Anonymous Then Cat INDENT
                Cat LBRACE
                If ItemBag.Count < 1 Then
                    Cat RBRACE
                Else
                    If Whitespace Then Cat vbNewLine
                    For Each Name In ItemBag
                        If IsObject(ItemBag.Item(Name)) Then
                            Set TempItem = ItemBag.Item(Name)
                        Else
                            TempItem = ItemBag.Item(Name)
                        End If
                        SerializeItem Name, TempItem, Level + 1
                        Cat COMMA
                        If Whitespace Then Cat vbNewLine
                    Next
                    If Whitespace Then
                        CursorOut = CursorOut - 3
                        Cat vbNewLine & INDENT & RBRACE
                    Else
                        Mid$(TextOut, CursorOut - 1) = RBRACE
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Case Else
            Err.Raise 51, TypeNameOfMe, ItemName & ", unknown/unsupported type = " & CStr(VarType(Item))
    End Select
End Sub

Private Function SerializeString(ByVal Text As String) As String
    Dim BuildString As String
    Dim BuildCursor As Long
    Dim TextCursor As Long
    Dim Char As String
    Dim intChar As Integer

    BuildString = Space$(3 * Len(Text) \ 2)
    BuildCursor = 1
    StringCat BuildString, BuildCursor, QUOTE
    For TextCursor = 1 To Len(Text)
        Char = Mid$(Text, TextCursor, 1)
        Select Case Char
            Case QUOTE, REVSOLIDUS
                StringCat BuildString, BuildCursor, REVSOLIDUS & Char
            Case vbBack
                StringCat BuildString, BuildCursor, REVSOLIDUS & "b"
            Case vbFormFeed
                StringCat BuildString, BuildCursor, REVSOLIDUS & "f"
            Case vbLf
                StringCat BuildString, BuildCursor, REVSOLIDUS & "n"
            Case vbCr
                StringCat BuildString, BuildCursor, REVSOLIDUS & "r"
            Case vbTab
                StringCat BuildString, BuildCursor, REVSOLIDUS & "t"
            Case " " To "!", "#" To LBRACKET, RBRACKET To "~"
                StringCat BuildString, BuildCursor, Char
            Case Else
                intChar = AscW(Char)
                Select Case intChar
                    Case 0 To &H1F, &H7F To &H9F, &H34F, &H200B To &H200F, _
                         &H2028 To &H202E, &H2060, &HFE01 To &HFE0F, _
                         &HFEFF, &HFFFD, &HD800 To &HDFFF
                        StringCat BuildString, BuildCursor, _
                               REVSOLIDUS & "u" & Right$("000" & Hex$(intChar), 4)
                    Case Else
                        StringCat BuildString, BuildCursor, Char
                End Select
        End Select
    Next
    StringCat BuildString, BuildCursor, QUOTE
    SerializeString = Left$(BuildString, BuildCursor - 1)
End Function

Private Sub SkipWhitespace(ByRef Text As String)
    CursorIn = CursorIn + StrSpn(StrPtr(Text) + 2 * (CursorIn - 1), StrPtr(WHITE_SPACE))
End Sub

Private Sub StringCat(ByRef TextOut As String, ByRef CursorOut, ByRef NewText As String)
    Const TEXT_CHUNK As Long = 64 'Allocation size for destination buffer Text.
    Dim LenNew As Long

    LenNew = Len(NewText)
    If LenNew > 0 Then
        If CursorOut + LenNew - 1 > Len(TextOut) Then
            If LenNew > TEXT_CHUNK Then
                TextOut = TextOut & Space$(LenNew + TEXT_CHUNK)
            Else
                TextOut = TextOut & Space$(TEXT_CHUNK)
            End If
        End If
        Mid$(TextOut, CursorOut, LenNew) = NewText
        CursorOut = CursorOut + LenNew
    End If
End Sub

'=== Private Events ====================================================================

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    TypeNameOfMe = TypeName(Me)
    vbUS = ChrW$(&H1F&)
    DecimalMode = False

    Clear
End Sub
```

I apologize once again for not having a link to the original code and author.

There's a post on VBForums about this class, perhaps a newer version:
[Another-JSON-Parser-Generator](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?738845-VB6-JsonBag-Another-JSON-Parser-Generator)